# Is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes

I am guilty of this, and I suspect most users have been at some point.

You arrive at a question, either because you're just browsing or you think you could answer it. You realise that either the question is beyond your expertise, or someone has already answered and it looks like a reasonable answer.

You think, I'll do some voting while I'm here, and upvote the answer or answers that look reasonable **and you don't see why they won't work**. Perhaps two or more answers are basically or functionally the same, so that's why you upvote them. Or perhaps you do actually know the answer is correct, but you haven't spotted the typo that will make it fail.

The problem is, you're guessing if they actually solve the question or not because, as I said, the question itself is not one you can answer with any confidence - or perhaps the method they've used is not one you're familiar with. In this or any similar situation, is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works or not, because you think it probably will?

Comment: Generally, you can use your votes however you want. You can upvote bad content and downvote good content - no one can do anything about your votes. However, voting up only correct contents and vote down incorrect content is the way to contribute to the site, and doing the reverse is doing a disservice to whoever that reach the question later and promote wrong information.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting anyone should purposely upvote bad content or downvote good content, more voting on a feeling or maybe even a guess!

Comment: My comment still applies. The idea is that no one can control how you vote, and the quality of the site ultimately depends on whether people check the answers carefully before voting.

Comment: "voting on a feeling or maybe even a guess" how does that make sense? You aren't certain about things when you take action, especially when it may affect others?

Comment: @codeMagic Since this is an abstract question, why are you taking things so literally?

Comment: @worldofjr because I am interested in the integrity of the site and I thought you were looking for a reasonable answer. If you see my history, I can have as much fun as anyone.  Just thought you were looking for an honest answer. Carry on....

Comment: I'm sure there is a bit of herd instinct going on. So answers that are upvoted already tend to attract even more upvotes even if the voters cannot know if the answer is really good, they just trust the others that already upvoted in the hope that one of them actually knew what he is doing. In the end: take the votes with a grain of salt.

Comment: [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810205/1820501) an example of upvoted and accepted non working answer. This is a shame, because it's one of the first results for googling of "css Calibri". Fortunately, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810362/1820501) (which is the correct one) is upvoted a lot more. So, don't upvote an answer if you don't know if it works, because that can mislead other peoples googling the same problem.

Comment: Well...if it's on one of _my_ answers, I guess I wouldn't mind it being upvoted.

Comment: Vote lock-in is a big reason not to upvote too early. I've had several occasions where I've upvoted an answer because it addressed exactly my problem and it was so simple. Twenty minutes later I find out it actually doesn't work for me, and I can't rescind the upvote until the post is edited.

Comment: I spotted a grossly wrong example of this kind of upvoting a while ago (it still has 2 upvotes, and was downvoted when I pointed out its errors): http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555455/541686

Comment: There are legitimate cases where you think an answer is _probably_ right, and certainly useful even if it isn't, but can't be _sure_ it's right. If you're just saying "I don't get it, but looks smart", that doesn't deserve an upvote. If you're saying "It solves a definite problem in the original code, and I could see how that problem would be the cause of the behavior the OP was asking about, but I'm not positive it wasn't something else", sure, upvote.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would personally say it is not reasonable to upvote an answer when you are uncertain of its correctness. Whenever possible, try to ensure that the answer would indeed solve the OP's issue. However, the problem of incorrect answers getting upvotes is fairly common and in certain scenarios, excusable.

The other day, I answered an SQL question where the user asked for a query. I was the first to give an answer and got an upvote within the next few minutes. Shortly afterwards, another user posted an answer which was practically identical, but with an added SQLFiddle link. (It came 17 minutes after my answer, but as it came with a SQLFiddle link, I would kindly rule out plagiarism.) When I checked the link, I realized that in my answer, I missed a technicality which made my answer grossly incorrect. I subsequently edited my answer and provided a working solution. (The answer was accepted, but no more subsequent upvotes.) At one glance, my initial answer seemed to provide the working solution, and someone viewing the question and the answer would naturally not think too deeply about the solution. With an answer already provided, it would be forgivable if he interpreted it the way I did initially. So he simply gave his upvote for an answer that looked correct and moved on to other questions.

Such behaviour would not generally constitute irresponsible voting although wherever possible, it would be best to choose not to vote when you aren't quite certain that the solution provided is actually a working one.

Comment: Yes I agree, unfortunately the first 10-15 minutes are crucial for people to decide where to put their votes. After that it's very hard to either get a downvote retracted after editing your question or having other upvotes. I believe it's more or less as with google: you hardly navigate to the second page of the results.. why bothering with lower-score answers?

Answer (score 28):

> is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works or not?

No!

> This answer is useful

How is it useful if you don't know that it's...useful?

Whether you know the answer or not, if you don't understand the answer then you surely shouldn't vote on it (unless it's outrageously incorrect without trying).

- I will upvote answers that I **know** to be correct, assuming certain
  criteria.
- If I know a different way but not the proposed way and am curious if
  it works then I will try it.

  1. If it works and is reasonable....upvote.
  2. If it doesn't work and is unhelpful...downvote and/or comment.
  3. If it doesn't work but is helpful in some way...upvote and or comment
  4. If it works but is unreasonable...downvote and/or comment.

Of course, you always have the option to do nothing at all if you are unsure.

The main point is that upvoting simply because others have or there's a chance it may work seems silly and wrong. If you are going to upvote then it should be helpful in some way and you should have some level of certainty that it will/should work.

Comment: Interesting. By that logic I shouldn't upvote an answer that wasn't completely right, but did lead me in the right direction ... and was therefore useful. Perhaps I should downvote this answer, because it works but it's unreasonable! :D

Comment: You are free to vote how you wish.. If it's incorrect then it shouldn't get an upvote. Being correct/incorrect and useful/not useful are mutually exclusive

Comment: How do you define "correct"?

Comment: @Roland gets you where you want to go. If it works then it is a correct way. That's why I added "reasonable/unreasonable" in my answer. There are plenty of ways you can decipher it

Comment: @codeMagic An answer that would be completely correct except for a simple single-character typo is a trivial example of an answer that is both incorrect and useful. An answer that correctly answers a different question is a trivial example of an answer that is both correct and useless.

Comment: @hvd I agree. That's what my first comment was meant to point out. But I forgot **not** in front of mutually exclusive...it was late

Comment: I routinely upvote answers that I expect to work without running them through the interpreter/compiler. I don't care about typos that can be fixed easily if one understands the answer.

Comment: @Roland I have done that also if I have some level of certainty that they will work. But that's not what we are talking about here.

Comment: I get the gist of this answer, but I would personally phrase things a little differently, because on occasion there is an answer that "doesn't work", yet it is still useful because it reveals a fruitful *approach* to a problem, or is otherwise elucidating, and ultimately puts the reader on the path to a good solution. Sometimes such an answer is so helpful, I *still* believe it deserves an upvote. And even if you can't bring yourself to upvote a "nonworking" answer, I feel strongly that this type of answer at least does *not* deserve a downvote. (So comment without voting at all.)

Comment: Also, you are looking for the word *orthogonal*.  (Mutually exclusive doesn't make too much sense.  I mean, sure tall/short and female/male are "not mutually exclusive"... but what would it even mean if they *were*?  If you have height you cannot have gender?)

Comment: @JohnY point taken and I have made some changes that hopefully explain my point better. By not mutually exclusive I mean that just because it is, say, incorrect does not mean that it isn't useful. It doesn't have to be absolutely correct to be useful. I think the usage there is fine but I learned a new word today so...thanks. Though, I'm not sure that's the correct word in this case even though it is helpful :)

Comment: I know for a fact that I've up-voted one of Jon Skeet's answers without verifying the answer...

Comment: @Rohan that's different because...Jon Skeet

Comment: I agree, the principle "*I don't know how this works.. lemme upvote it*" should just be applied for questions, not answers

Comment: I like your point of view, I'll try it from now on. I will upvote you when I see it works.

Answer (score 11):

An answer can be useful without being correct, if by correct you mean "completely solves the OP's problem".

A well formatted and easy to read answer that describes an approach that could work can be useful, **even if** the approach doesn't work.

To quote @hvd, an answer that would solve the problem, but for a one-character typo, is not correct.  It is still useful.  Now, such an answer can be edited and made correct, but I don't think that edit is required to make it worthy of an upvote or two.

I wouldn't upvote something that already had a bunch of upvotes, nor would I bump an answer over a different one that be more correct, but separating a more reasonably written, more plausible solution from others seems like a useful thing.

Comment: "an approach that could work" The kind of answer that immediately comes to my mind's eye when I read this are those that answerers write without understanding what the problem actually is. The OP's problem falls under a general kind of problem that can be caused by situations A, B, C, or D. A, B, C are more frequent so the OP gets answers for A, B, C. However, someone reading the question carefully would know that A, B and C cannot be the case *here*. Yet those answers that depend on A, B, C present "approach[es] that *could* work", if the problem was a *different* one.

Comment: @Louis You should not upvote answers that appear to simply provide a working solution, without knowing if that solution actually works.  But many answers don't simply provide a working solution.  Many answers make some effort to identify some steps that can be taken to better identify the cause of the problem, in addition to providing a plausible solution.  And for answers like these, even if one is only vaguely familiar with the subject, you should be able to make a pretty good guess if that answer will be helpful or not.

Comment: @user3334690 I said "However, someone reading the question carefully would know that A, B and C **cannot be the case here**"? [Emphasis added.] My problem is not with hypotheses that are compatible with the circumstances described in the question. My problem is with answers that depend on circumstances *at odds* with what the OP described, even if in *other circumstances* they could be useful. I evaluate "usefulness" in light of the question.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it would be right - I would prefer to keep my votes for when I have a reasonably good idea of what I'm voting on.

There are too many sheep around here to just trust that the highest voted answer is correct.

Check out this recent thread for some interesting discussions around the problem that is caused by this type of behaviour:

- [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-answers)