# How can we deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, old-answers

I was prompted to ask this after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441429/156755) (scored +749/-3)

> Note: The answer has been edited and is now correct. [Previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/441429/15)

The answer wasn't bad when it was added, but the information is woefully out of date.

[jquerylatest.com](http://jquerylatest.com) is no longer updated/maintained and is only preserved to prevent old websites which use it from breaking. It was [never intended](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/) to be linked to directly from production pages)

One other user has posted comments saying not to use the answer but they're lost in the noise.

It doesn't *feel* like flagging is the right approach for a well formed answer, however...

- Since the answer appears to work (you get a functional but outdated version of jQuery), many people won't realise it's a bad answer until they try to use newer functionality.
- Those who do realise it's a bad answer after trying it are unlikely to re-find the answer and downvote it (as evidenced by the score).
- Being an old question, it's unlikely to get enough passers-by who can spot the problem to move it down the list in any reasonable timescale (and at a glance it looks like a good answer).

So... How do we fix this answer (and others like it)?

Comment: You downvote, comment, provide a better answer, and sit back and let time and the community do the rest.

Comment: @MartijnPieters with that score it could take a while.

Comment: @Stijn: yup, but that's how it is. Score changes slowly. Flagging is not an option here, moderators are not going to judge the correctness of the post.

Comment: The OP is aware that this is no longer supported (they commented on this answer), so they could quite simply unaccept it and go for a different answer

Comment: I don't have an answer to the problem but I do feel that it's a real, important problem. Two weeks ago I've flagged an answer again with  this comment: *"I know about the policy of moderators not deleting wrong answers, but please delete this one. It's 100% wrong, it's currently at +444/-109 and it's still gathering upvotes every few days. The user is gaining privileges and on first sight appears to be very knowledgeable in [javascript] while he isn't."* I have very little hope for the answer to be deleted, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case with answers that look good at first glance. Most users don't take the time to dig into details before voting. @Joe Good point. I've given the OP a link to this question.

Comment: @Stijn: bring the answer to the attention of the JS chatroom? Discuss it here? Is there a suitable better answer to upvote?

Comment: @Basic, add a comment below the answer with a big "READ THIS BEFORE USING THIS ANSWER" at the start. The meta effect might get your comment some upvotes to prop it to the top of the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what could we, as users, possibly do with an answer that has such a high score? Are you suggesting organised downvoting? The top voted comment on the answer, with 125 votes, says *"Not working at all. Do not vote for this before a try."* but it doesn't help. The answer has gained another 9 upvotes and 2 downvotes in the last 10 days.

Comment: @Stijn: Is there a better answer, linked in those comments? How many upvotes did that answer gain in the meantime? Another option might be to edit that answer, if it is so popular, perhaps. Not sure about what the edit would look like and if it'll stick though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There isn't, although the accepted answer is 100% correct and is on +280/-40.

Comment: @Stijn: so there is an already accepted answer that is correct? That's pinned to the top then, and your problem lies with the stupidity of the interwebs and people upvoting something popular without understanding. Not sure what the moderators are going to do about *that*.

Comment: Anyway the question is (would be) offtopic by now. My impression is that questions asking for resources are more often outdated than other questions.

Comment: related: [What's the policy on down voting previously correct but now outdated answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265749/1048572)

Comment: _"Being an old question, it's unlikely to get enough passers-by..."_  so what's the problem then?

Comment: Wouldn't it be OK for someone to just edit the answer as a matter of updating it? I don't see any harm on doing so, is there any?

Comment: This is an ongoing problem. Just yesterday I took a significant amount of time to clearly and correctly answer a question.  By the time I had the complete answer up the TC had accepted an answer that was flat out wrong.  I posted a friendly comment explaining to the TC what was wrong with the accepted answer and NADA.  Already the accepted answer has gathered up votes as well even though it provides the wrong results!  This is really frustrating as less experienced individuals show up on a question from google and just do whatever has the checkmark and/or most upvotes; even when it is wrong.

Comment: @SamIam Enough passers-by _to get it downvoted enough_ is the key.  There are multitude more who get here from Google and don't have an account, or can't downvote due to not having enough rep, or don't downvote often due to loss of rep, or don't downvote because it just doesn't cross their minds.

Comment: And what about [questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272663/2333214) ..?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255527/question-with-horrible-answers

Comment: Flag as low quality then organize a mob in chat to go select 'Recommend Deletion' in the review. Is that allowed? Would that work?

Comment: The Best Solution is for the experts out there to have a vote and close the answers that are outdated. Then inform the person who raised the question either to raise it as new or delete the question all together. If the person doesn't respond in some length of time then the question should be deleted by the Admin team. I'm sure that same question will be raised again by someone else. I also believe that answers should have a cap on voting to about 10. In theory i can have one answer that scored 1000+ votes and another 20 answers that scored -20 votes. Steady flow of 10's is better for rep :)

Comment: Downvoting isn't the answer because it unfairly punishes the original answerer "for not having the temerity to maintain a vigil over his answers and update them once the data changes". The rep was justly earned and so should not be lost.  Instead, the moderators should have the power to administratively mark another answer as correct, which may reward the owner of the new answer while not punishing the owner of the original answer.  Everyone wins.

Comment: @Jon Interesting point, I hadn't considered the lost rep. In this case, it doesn't apply as the answer in question is community wiki but definitely relevant to other similar situations

Comment: In this specific case, wouldn't it make sense to close the question because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" and then delete it? The question itself has no place here and the answers aren't really useful enough to be worth preserving (at least no more useful than Googling "jquery cdn") so why not bin the whole thing?

Comment: @Basic ***The question was edited and is correct***. It was changed over 12 hours ago. You need to edit your question to reflex that, otherwise people may think the question is still wrong/out-of-date.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks. Fixed

Comment: This question about hugely upvoted answers that are not correct now has a hugely upvoted answer recommending a flag that does not exist. It's like raiiiin...

Comment: Isn't the simplest thing to do to just *edit the answer* and add a 'This answer is obsolete' line at the top? Obviously not everyone has the rep to do this but those who do should feel no hesitation at fixing a wrong answer. Unless of course that it's more about points scoring than correct answers...

Comment: @ClaraOnager Without citation/context, that sort of edit verges on vandalism. On the other hand, users tend to react poorly to major edits being made to their non-CW answers. It's a sticky wicket.

Comment: @Jon, I believe downvoting an answer removes 2 points, while upvoting that same answer adds 10 points. In other words, even if an out-of-date answer comes back down to zero, its original author will keep 80% of his/her reputation that was garnered through that question.

Comment: Why should any be lost?  That's like saying your painter did an awesome job when he or she completed, but 4 years later, you downgrade your opinion to just an okay job, owing to normal wear and tear making it look less than stellar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think outdated answers is challenge for stack overflow. Also for people who provided it - when I give answers I want to contribute to SO. If my answers gets outdated - I don't want to mislead users. What solutions did SO think about in this regard?

Comment: Referenced in meta post *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302)* (2021-02-18).

Comment: Related: [Good question, old version-dependent answer - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Firstly, I agree something needs to be done about this.

*Now*, in *this* situation, since the post is a community wiki (CW), more flexibility and less ownership is implied in the post.

Even so, this post is *so* out of whack, and by making the changes I want to make to it, I practically re-wrote the post. Here's what I think it should say:

> **Up until jQuery 1.11.1**, you could use the following URLs to get the latest version of jQuery:
>
> - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js - jQuery hosted (minified)
> - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js - jQuery hosted (uncompressed)
> - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js - Google hosted (minified)
> - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js - Google hosted (uncompressed)
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
>         type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> However, since jQuery 1.11.1, both jQuery and Google stopped updating
> these URL's; they will *forever* be fixed at 1.11.1. There is no
> supported alternative URL to use. For an explanation of why this is the case, see this blog post; [Don't use
> jquery-latest.js](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/).
>
> Both hosts support `https` as well as `http`, so change the protocol
> as you see fit (or use a [protocol relative
> URI](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/))
>
> See also: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Why?

1. The two URLs I removed (linking to jQuery 1.9.1) are *wrong*. 1.9.1 is a version, not a family; those URLs are/ were never *latest*; they were, and always will be, fixed at 1.9.1.
2. http://jquerylatest.com was added by an anonymous user. It adds no value to the post, as the two links it contains are both included in the answer anyway.
3. http://scriptsrc.net/ hasn't been updated since jQuery 1.10.*, so I've removed that
4. jQuery's own CDN now supports https, as well as Google's; updated that sentence (and made it easier to read).

Comment: Nice solution and agreed, CW makes it less likely someone will be precious about the answer. I'll pop back this evening and assuming you've made the edit/nobody has a better idea, I'll accept.

Comment: I don't find this new version clearer. You don't usually take the time to read the whole post when you just want an url. My reflex would be copy/paste the code sample. (Particulary for an answer with so many upvotes)

Comment: @gzou: I'd welcome any improvements, but the bold **Up until 1.11.1** *right* at the start of the post is clear enough in my opinion. I guess we could also bold the **However** directly below the `<script />`, at another attempt at getting people's attention,  but... meh.

Comment: it's definitively an improvement, but I think it would need a flag as suggested in Krumia answer.

Comment: Excellent edit Matt, and I agree you can't guard against those who don't read. I am all for making things clearer, but anyone who blindly copies links from the internet and updates production code without applying some reading comprehension is bound to screw things up. If they shoot themselves in the foot it is their own doing. Even the question states "(Obviously not necessarily a great plan to link your code to potentially changing libraries but useful in development)" so there's lots of warning flags for those who actually care enough about the work they are doing to read before they act.

Comment: *You don't usually take the time to read the whole post when you just want an url.* In that case you have only yourself to blame...

Answer (score 293):

### How do we fix this answer (and others like it)?

As [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) have already said, you can downvote, comment, and provide a better answer, of course.

### But...

If the obsolete answer is really old, it is most probable that your comment/answer will be drowned for a long time. I think this is where we have to take a leaf out of Wikipedia's book.

When an article in Wikipedia has obsolete facts, and if Wikipedians notice this, they can let others know it by adding [`{{Update|inaccurate=y}}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Articles_with_obsolete_information) to the page. The result is this:

[image: Screenshot from Wikipedia]

This is essentially equivalent to ***"This answer is obsolete"*** comment on Stack Overflow. But note that, unlike in Stack Overflow, Wikipedia does not naturally drown that flag. It is displayed on the very top of the page. This has several advantages:

1. Wikipedia users know up-front that the information in the article *might* be obsolete. They do not have to *use* that information in order to realize that it is obsolete.
2. If they visit the article, without *any* inspection, Wikipedia editors immediately know that the article should be fixed. So the correction process is faster.

I think we should have something similar on Stack Overflow. **A flag for obsolescence:** a flag not for moderators, but for the community. And enough flags (3? 5?) should display a message about the answer:

> > <sub>This answer may contain out-of-date information. Please validate this answer and consider providing an answer with recent information.</sub>
>
> Answer Text.

Comment: Just keep in mind that obsolete does not imply useless or incorrect in all situations. Though with JavaScript and similar web technologies, that's quite likely to coincide. (This note is for the general case, the specific example is undisputed.)

Comment: I think this is an excellent suggestion. @Deduplicator raises a very good point, but I think we can work around that if we're careful. Perhaps something that conveys `The information in this answer is no longer accurate for [versions after x/the latest version]`. In any case, it's a feature request I'd support if you care to propose it

Comment: Of course obsolete does not imply useless. There would always be legacy systems. Hence the use of word "may" :) And "please validate" means inspect it, and downvote if necessary. And of course I think if someone flags something as _obsolete/out-of-date_, that person should explain the reasons very well (and system should provide means to do that). Requirement of multiple flags to display the message ensures the consensus.

Comment: I don't like it that much. I'm fully occupied by voting and flagging for other issues. By editing the answer and indicating the part that is outdated you can get much more accurate and helpful hints than a general Don't-trust-this-answer note.

Comment: @Basic: Thanks, if it gets momentum here, I will propose it as a feature request.

Comment: @Trilarion: My suggestion was _not_ to improve the process of updating obsolete answers. It is about _identifying_ obsolete answers. Yes, you are right, a general note is not that helpful. But this would increase the probability of someone spotting the answer. And when that person updates it, he can clear the obsolete flag.

Comment: @Trilarion: On second thoughts, people don't like to edit other's answers. So a flag would be an encouragement to edit an obsolete answer.

Comment: This flag idea is the best one I have seen for this problem.  However I would only allow certain editors to mark the answer obsolete.  Over a certain number of points might be one way, or a certain number of upvotes in answers with the same tag might be another.  that way you are getting input from users that the community has given kudos to on a particular tag.  So if a user has gotten say a total of eg:50 upvotes for various answers in say the jquery tag, that user can mark an answer in the jquery tag obsolete.  I have no idea how practical this idea may be from a SO resources point of view.

Comment: @Krumia : One more things, if you put the wikipedia box on an article, then the page is automatically added in this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:All_Wikipedia_articles_in_need_of_updating "Category:All Wikipedia articles in need of updating"). Just look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Categories#Why_might_a_category_list_not_be_up_to_date?) for more information.

Comment: Posts marked like this could be appear in a review queue (created for this purpose). That could give the posts the needed visibility, so the necesssary actions are taken.

Comment: Converted to a feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/1461424

Comment: It should be a vote, not a flag. Or maybe a "nominate for obsolete consideration flag". But the mechanics better not be screwed up like with closevotes.

Comment: In *extreme* cases where the answer can be misleading and there are already more comments than will display, I think it may be justified (or at least preferable to a drastic 3rd party content edit) to edit a very brief, neutral "Note: this answer pertains to an older version" or similar at the top of such an answer.  That leaves the historic information there for the cases where it is useful, but cautions first-time readers to not just grab & go, but look at the comments and other answers.

Comment: @Krumia. Amen. Thank you for referencing an institution that has dealt with community-curated authority for a couple of internet-life-spans longer than SO. I'm not saying what Wikipedia has is optimal for SO, rather, it'd be silly not to consider what evolved there.

Comment: "No longer useful" is part of the definition of "obsolete".  We need another word.

Comment: Note that the Wikipidedia notice is alerting possible factual inaccuracy, not possible uselessness.

Comment: I like this idea but I wonder how to avoid over-use. For example, someone asked a question about C five years ago. The answer used C99. Someone slaps this flag on the answer simply because there's a better way to do it in C11, (which btw many and probably most C programmers don't use). Whether this flag is correct depends whether you take the question to be about "the latest version of C at time of asking" or "the latest version of C at time of reading", an arguable point. It's far better to tag the question C99 than to flag the answer out of date, but I don't see that happening reliably.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Visitors coming for answers will not really look at tags. Nobody Googles "foo the bar in C99". Everyone wants to know hot to "foo the bar in **C**". Part of the philosophy of SO is to have a wiki of canonical answers. And canonical answers are incomplete if they don't have updates on later developments in the industry.

Comment: @Krumia: The problem I'm trying to highlight is that "in C" is itself a contentious term and doesn't mean the same to all audiences. The most recent version of the standard has in point of fact not replaced the previous version in use. For that matter, C99 never really replaced C89 either. I agree that people might ignore tags, but adding the tag at least clarifies the question for those who are aware of the difference. I'm not sure the philosophy of SO really tells me what is the canonical answer to a question whose meaning becomes increasingly ambiguous over time.

Comment: "adding the tag at least clarifies the question for those who are aware of the difference". Yes, but for those who are like me, sigh! :D

Comment: ... but anyway, if an acceptable response to the flag is to edit the answer to say "in C99..." and remove the flag then I'd have no concerns. If the effect of the flag is to remove information about C99 from the site and replace it with C11-only answers then that's a nasty side-effect IMO. I suppose the ideal is that the answer should separately address both, but if the original C99 answerer isn't using C11 it's not realistic for them to do that.

Comment: " if an acceptable response to the flag is to edit the answer to say "in C99..." and remove the flag" YES! [yes, of course](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/1461424).

Answer (score 14):

It is not the upvoting / downvoting that is the problem. That's SO's natural and quite fair rating system. Instead of changing the mechanics, it is better to change the user's behavior by changing the way the information is presented, and influence his behavior in this regard.

Instead of simply showing the aggregated score over time, it would be better to display a small time-graph that indicates the highs and lows, and the time the answer is live. I think if the graph shows decay over time, the user might get the notion that the answer is out of date, or atleast that there are comments that are more critical to the answer today than they were earlier.

As an extension, alternative answers might get indicated on the graph so that they can be linked to the critical downvotes, and can contain information such as versioning, deprecation or new alternative methods.

Comment: That could be a feature request. I also thought about this. My idea was basically to weigh votes with time past and overweigh more recent and underweigh older votes. This would accelerate the whole process of getting once popular but now outdated answers back in line.

Comment: Answer decaying might be a bad idea. There are answers that are correct for eternity. Those gems will drown if we implement this.

Comment: Replacing simple numbers with a complicated mini-graph seems like a problematic UI to me. You'd be making it harder to parse every answer on the site to handle a relatively rare case.

Comment: My suggestion is to display the downvoting activity more visually, not so much decay the score itself. There is no logical reason why decay would work on something people have elected to be important.

Comment: One could also just show the trend of the last X answers as an upward, neutral, downward pointing arrow. That could also give people an indication about recent evaluations of the answer.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the score AND having another aid alongside (perhaps directly underneath?), such as StarShine's idea. That way, the answer poster can keep their score and be rewarded for their work at the time, but readers can understand that the answer is likely outdated. @DavidRobinson said it's a relatively rare case, but I think this will be more and more a problem the older stackoverflow gets.

Comment: @David Robinson: Yes, the graph should be clear, readable and sober by design, such that it attracts attention to the voting trend rather than precise numbers or exact duration. Nothing complicated. A single trend line scaled over max-min score, and a tooltip hover that says something like: "The question gained / lost # votes in the last # days. See latest answers to find out why."

Answer (score 12):

Regarding the score I think that editing (answer is community wiki) is the method of choice.

Answer (score 8):

> ### How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?

Martijn was right in his answer/comment, which has 34 comment upvotes:

> 34 - You downvote, comment, provide a better answer, and sit back and let time and the community do the rest. – Martijn Pieters♦ [Oct 1 '14 at 9:04](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers#comment100084_272570)

So that's:

- Comment
- Downvote
- Provide a better answer
- And wait...

So I'm going to expand on that in a full answer here - in a way, I hope, that addresses Stijn's concern, with 101 upvotes,

> 101 - @MartijnPieters with that score it could take a while. – Stijn [Oct 1 '14 at 9:05](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers#comment100085_272570)

The problem is that some answers are *hugely* upvoted, *bad*, and *outdated*!

Sometimes, the reason they're at the top is because they're accepted.
In 2008, the site was new, and many low-effort, unsophisticated answers were easily accepted - and the questions became the canonical Q&A.

Sometimes the answer might not even be accepted, but it is just an over-confident or overly marked-up effort that seems clever but really isn't - and to recognize it requires a bit of sophisticated expertise.

What can we do about these kinds of answers within the pre-existing structure and guidelines?

I'll address some issues and provide some ideas to handle them.

#### Issue: Too Much Visual Noise

Sometimes people say, "Brilliant! Plus one! Love getting an answer!" Sometimes they follow up with "How does X work?" And other people respond in the comments. And some respond incorrectly. And some may even write brilliant short answers in a single comment. And someone else may even write a criticism, but the criticism is lost in all the noise - and the critical message doesn't get through.

Sometimes, after scrubbing away the chaff, what's left are some legitimate criticisms. Maybe there are already upvoted critical comments, but they're candy-coated and take careful reading to realize they actually mean the answer is wrong, instead of affirming the answer.

Ideas to resolve:

- Write a better, clearer, more direct criticism.
- Flag poorly written, but critical, comments that do not directly address the actual issues with it.
- Flag any other uncritical comments. If there is information in comments not already in an answer, put them in your better answer or append their substance to the answer current answer, and flag them as no-longer-needed.

#### Issue: Trivially obsolete code

Stack Overflow is about a decade old, and getting older. So is much of its most popular content. This means that new solutions sit at the bottom, while old solutions may be pinned at the top.

For example, Python 2 is reaching end-of-life soon, and most companies are transitioning to Python 3 now. Old code may not even run.

Idea to resolve:

- Update the code with a trivial edit (minimize lines changed please!)
- write a critique if the trivial edit is not accepted.
- write a better answer.

What is the rule for changing code? Usually don't, because it can change the meaning of the answer - and we don't do that.

However, the [help page on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) says:

> When should I edit posts? [...] To [...] add updates as the post ages

So, this would be the uncommon use-case. So, especially if you see opportunities in *my* answers, for example:

```
xrange(...)
```

to new code:

```
range(...) # xrange in Python 2
```

Note that this doesn't change the meaning, to my view, because `xrange` becomes `range` in Python 3. I for one would be happy to see those kinds of edits on my posts by people who really know what they're doing.

If the answerer or another user objects, fine, let them roll it back and be wrong.

Then flag poorly executed comments, comment yourself, downvote, write your better answer, and walk away.

Note that this suggestion requires careful judgment and domain knowledge, and the recognition that even though you may be "right" you may be going out on a limb. If you're wrong a lot (and even *I* am sometimes wrong about what I think an author will accept as an edit) then rethink this part of the strategy.

This issue for Python 2 & 3 is addressed in more detail with different opinions here, and I think the top several answers all have good points and all have points I'd quibble with: [When is it permissible to update other people's answers for Python 3?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348295/541136)

#### Issue: other meta issues

Sometimes a poor answer seems to be an answer, but it's [not *actually an answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/541136). Maybe the question asks for an apple, but it provides an orange. Maybe it's actually a convoluted link-only answer.

And maybe we just haven't to this point in time actually identified the fact that on close inspection, it's not actually an answer.

Idea to resolve:

- Flag it on those grounds. Maybe we can side-step the entire thorny issue of its "badness" with a technicality - it's nice when that happens.
- If you're confused, ask about it on meta. Nothing like sunshine to wash away badness.

### Will these suggestions get results?

I know they can. I have seen an accepted answer go from ~100 net upvotes to 0 (at one point losing about 2 points per day), whereupon the answerer asked a mod to [delete the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627022/541136).

I have seen accepted answers be updated with small snippets of code from others, and as the answerer did not roll them back, the edits were accepted. I try to work with any editor of my own answers as well. But if the community objects, don't get involved in a rollback war.

I have seen cluttering Not-An-Answers eventually get deleted when intelligent people finally realize they're not actually answers.

### Prescriptive Conclusion

So...

> How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?

Do this.

Do a good analysis of the issues with the whole Q&A - then, in this approximate order, do the following if apropos:

1. If the issue is trivially obsolete code, offer minimalist edits if you think the answerer will be accepting of them - if accepted, the problem may be solved! Give them 24 hours to a week. Otherwise, next...
2. Downvote it yourself.
3. Write your own critical comment, be clear, write plainly, and don't sugar-coat it. If the answer is still getting upvotes after your comment, either your assessment is wrong or your comment wasn't clear.
4. Flag all comments that don't clearly request improvement.
5. Write a much better answer (maybe don't publish it immediately - really polish it first, and who knows, the asker might unaccept the old and accept your new one. This has happened to me on several occasions - and why I'm taking my time with this answer now.).
6. Address the content from the comments you wish to flag in your answer.
7. For other meta problems with the answers, flag for a moderator or ask on meta if you're confused.

Note that while writing a much better answer is *optional*, not doing so may inhibit your ability to legitimately flag outdated comments, and hurts the overall strategy.

Comment: One option I don't see here which might be worth including is, create a new canonical "how do I solve this in 2018" and maybe eventually mark the old question as a duplicate of the new one. This is probably not something which should be taken on by a lone ranger, though; coordinate with the community (the Python chat room, for example, in the case of a Python question).

Comment: @tripleee: but never use year numbers. Use Python (/ pandas/ whatever) version numbers. Or "How to do X in Python 2.x" vs "... in Python 3.x"? or in limited cases, more specifics e.g. "in Python 3.1 - 3.4" or "3.5+"? (As an aside, SO search can not intelligently translate "3.5+" into [tag:python-3.5] [tag:python-3.6] [tag:python-3.7] ). So neither tags nor plaintext work particularly well. (Oh and Google won't intelligently handle them either, it'll mangle them in a different way)

Comment: Yeah, I'm paraphrasing what a proper "new improved canonical" might look like but perhaps simplifying too much for my own good.

Answer (score 7):

##### Usability issue may contribute to the problem.

If there are 800 users who upvoted the answer because it looks like it did just what they want, and 700 of them found out it didn't work but never withdrew their upvote, there could be several reasons.

- A few hundred of them might just not have bothered to find the page again and never tried to withdraw their vote.
- Some of them might have made that effort and *attempted* to
  withdraw their upvote.

After increasing a value by pressing an
up-arrow, what's the most obvious way to decrease it?  Pressing the
down-arrow, right?  New users trying that will get an error message
about not having enough reputation to be allowed to down-vote an
answer.  Some of them will tell themselves, "Oh, well, I tried, but I
guess I'm not allowed to change my vote".  (Others will discover that
the up-arrow is a toggle and pressing it a second time decreases the
number and are not counted among those 700+).  That confusion could
be another reason that those with down-voting privileges never catch
up with the unwithdrawn upvotes.

Comment: Not to mention that votes become locked - so if they take a day to find out that it doesn't work, they can't do anything about it without editing the answer anyway (and many won't have the rep or confidence to do that)

Answer (score 2):

- Cast your downvote.
- Comment to explain why you think it's bad (as long as you do it in a constructive manner (see /help/privileges/comment- it should be clear enough from your comment how the answer could be improved / where it could use improvement)). If such a comment has already been written, upvote it.

  If you're afraid of backlash / retaliation from commenting and downvoting at the same time, just put a few days or weeks between those two actions.
- Write a better answer.

Concerning outdatedness, if you are confident in your understanding of the facts to clearly delineate under what conditions the answer is *not* outdated, then say so. Ex. "This information only applies from version 1.2.0 to 1.2.7 of the Foo software", or "This information applies to software conforming to Foo spec version 42.0 and onward, but new features in version 68.0 have enabled different approaches which may be more attractive if you don't need to support usage with older versions". I feel like it should be okay to edit the post to say this, but I'm not 100% sure. If you don't feel comfortable making such an edit, you can comment. And then in your answer post, you can make similar statements qualifying information / approaches / solutions for different "eras". Linking to relevant sources of information is always nice with things like this. Ex. release notes / changelogs / version-pinned spec documents / issue tracker tickets, etc.

Over time, the votes will start rolling in, and if your answer post is useful, it will rise. I've seen my fair share of comments like "why is this all the way down here?" / "I'm so glad I kept scrolling" / "why is this not the top answer?" on answers that had then reached the top / close to the top by the time of my reading.

I agree that there are pain points in the system. Downvoting is a much higher privilege than upvoting, and statistically speaking, the vast majority of users of the system cannot cast "real" downvotes (take a look at the "Total Reputation" side bar in [the reputation leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)). Combine that with answers that point to things that are not very immutable (I gave examples earlier about software / spec versions, which don't really suffer from that by definition of being versioned and archivable and whatnot), such as a service that can be free one day, and then a paid product the next day, and then gone the next (there's a particular email-related answer post I've seen a couple times, but don't have a link handy), and it makes for a pretty non-ideal scenario. But in scenarios like that, what I've seen is that people will pipe up in the comments, and those comments eventually accrue upvote weight, which *kind* of soothes the pain.

Comment: I mean, this clearly doesn't work. [This incorrect answer was noted as being incorrect back in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2865546/400654), however it still managed to be the second and third scored answer and many times repeated on the question 12 years later.

Comment: @KevinB well, it's second by a pretty large margin, which is kind of my point.

Answer (score 0):

I  believe that the core problem with questions like this is the way they are worded.

The question requests the "latest" link to a resource. This information could change with each single version.

Users need to be encouraged to request for help with a particular version software/framework etc.

In cases where this cannot be done, the best way is to edit the answer. This way,

- The edits will get approved quickly as long as the update is correct
- The upvotes will be maintained
- Version history of the answer will be maintained

Comment: I read the question differently. To me, it seems the OP wants a static link that always points at the latest version of jQuery. Eg we expose an Api at `/Api/V1.0.1/`, `/Api/V1.1.3/`, etc... But they're only used for backwards compatability with legacy systems. All maintained servers simply point at `/Api/Current/` which redirects to the latest version.

Comment: I see what you are saying. However for similar questions requesting the 'latest' links, this may not always be possible right?

Comment: Yep, it depends entirely on the service in question

Answer (score 0):

**Decay the weight of older votes** - applied at a relatively long time-scale so as to not impact voting on current questions.  When users flip their vote it will have double impact with added weighting still.

An alternative approach is expire older votes, as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256174/1156245) by @andy-lorenz.

Comment: It is now possible to sort the answers by "Trending", which is exactly this. However, users can't "flip their vote" unless the answer was edited, and most of the people who upvoted these old answers are probably not monitoring them closely, nor especially interested in the cleanup process.

Comment: Sure they can flip their vote - they can unlike an out of date answer and like a new one.

Comment: No, they really cannot. Past a certain grace period, the system will not allow you to change votes on something that hasn't been edited in the interim. I've tried it many times.

Comment: That's current rules - we're talking about an alternative possible implementation.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that moderators aren't there to correct wrong answers, even if they're only wrong because of the passage of time. Therefore a flag isn't appropriate because there's nothing here for a moderator to do.

As Matt observes, in this case the answer is CW. That is to say, the community is invited to edit the answer. Do so.

In a more typical case, you don't normally edit someone else's answer in a way that substantially changes what it's saying. So:

1. Post a correct answer
2. Post a comment that this answer is out of date referring to your answer. Hopefully, the author of the answer will respond by editing the incorrect answer or (ideally, but perhaps unlikely given the huge amounts of rep involved) deleting it. Optionally also post a comment pinging the asker of the question, they might revise their choice of accepted answer.
3. If the author doesn't respond then either they disagree with you so strongly they don't think you're even worth talking to, or else they're not currently active on SO. I'd leave it a week or so and then:
4. Edit the answer to say that while it was correct at the time of answering, it is not correct any longer.
5. If the author reverts your change then that's it. There's nothing more to do to their answer other than raise awareness of it with people who might downvote it (in chat, for example). The author of the question has a right to disagree with you what their answer should say, and the upvotes all count (even if the upvoters would change their vote now if they realised the situation).

**The process is designed to display the accepted and most-upvoted answers first, not the correct ones**. It has a great advantage of simplicity. If you don't like that process (and it does have its unfortunate edge cases), you could maybe argue for something like a "tag moderator". That is to say, a mod-like being with high scores in a particular tag, who unlike normal mods *is* mandated to moderate answers for correctness.

I would also say *don't go through this just because the answer is only correct for an older version*. Your example deserves attention because it's specifically about "the latest version" at any time, not just the latest version at the time it was asked. But for example if someone asks a question about how to use jQuery, and it's answered 2 years ago with the best way at the time, and a better way has since been introduced in a more recent jQuery, then *don't* have a panic attack that the answer is now incorrect.

I'm not sure quite what the best procedure is in that case. I'd tentatively go for "tag the old question with a version-specific tag if available, and ask a new question specifically about the latest version of jQuery, which therefore is not a dupe, and answer it yourself". But that might get marked dupe anyway. In which case the "this answer is wrong" situation *does* now apply, in the sense that the community has decided that the question in point of fact *has* changed to be about 2.something instead of 1.something. Personally I'd disagree with that assessment of the questions being duplicates, but if they are then it follows that the old answer is now wrong :-)

Comment: The "tag moderator" you describe sounds a lot like a gold tag badge holder.

Comment: @Stijn: that would perhaps be a necessary condition for the post but I'd say not sufficient. I have 3 gold tag badges, but I wouldn't be particularly interested in receiving tag-mod-requests to review the correctness of answers in those tags.

Answer (score -2):

The most upvoted comment is in response to this comment,

> You downvote, comment, provide a better answer, and **sit back and let time and the community do the rest.** – Martijn Pieters

Which is,

> @MartijnPieters **with that score it could take a while.** – user247702

I think it's fine to have the system correct itself with time. I would also like to see this process move faster and so I'd like to introduce a concept out of economics,

## Inflation

I know it sounds bizarre and it's unpopular when it happens to your money, and I'm not saying it should happen to the awarded reputation. But it should happen to upvotes as they're used to rank answers. Hear me out, this [idea was actually suggested by Jeff Atwood and is *ALREADY* employed in Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/157251), just apply this same logic to answers. The reason for this is simple, we should prioritize those that vote on answers **TODAY**. It's silly to say a vote 10 years ago has the same worth as a vote today because **people that are looking for the content are best represented as `t` approaches now, and moves away from 0.** Further, it provides no value to have a historical record of the best answer *in the past*, the vote count need only serve the present.

That is all.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps SO should put a small banner on answers that are old (1 year?  2 years?) AND where there are much newer answers.  It would be a totally non-judgemental banner "This answer is over 18 months old.  More recent answers exist that you might consider."  Then let the normal upvoting/downvoting process work to get the newer answers rated higher.  The only problem I see is that downvoting the obsolete answer would hurt the reputation of the person who posted it, even though it was correct at the time.  I like Krumia's idea, too.  The two are compatible.