# Should I edit a question to better fit a good answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353529/git-diff-how-to-ignore-filemode-of-piped-input/28354568) and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354568/511387) that solves my problem, but doesn't really answer the question.

For posterity, is it better to rephrase the question and accept the answer, or just upvote the answer and wait for an answer to the original question?

Comment: Closely related: [How to deal with questions whose title, description, and accepted answer don't match?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272663)

Comment: *"is it better to rephrase the question...or just upvote the question"* I assume you mean "upvote the answer."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Sometimes, just editing is better.

Comment: As there are no answers addressing the question as-is, you are free to edit it to the question you actually tried to ask there. Thereafter, this question becomes academic.

Comment: _@Neil_ Does the edited Q&A in whole provide any benefit for fututre research?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem then there wasn't anything wrong with the answer and there is of course no point in waiting for another one.  Only the question was lacking, the answerer knew to ignore the parts of it that were not relevant.  Pretty common.  Yes, you can fix that.  But keep in mind that programmers only ever for search for questions and might be similarly be astray.