# What to do with answers that teach bad practice?

Tags: discussion, answers

The question's title already says everything but I will try to elaborate.

Disclaimer: I don't want to unleash the meta effect but I needed an example.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504004/how-can-i-replace-all-elements-in-an-array-with-a-prefix-string-in-mongodb)  with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504086/3100115) that solved the problem but is very inefficient as I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504004/how-can-i-replace-all-elements-in-an-array-with-a-prefix-string-in-mongodb#comment56756081_34504086).

Is writing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506328/3100115) to show the best way to solve the problem and leaving a comment on the existing answer as I did enough or what is the best way to handle such situation?

I am asking this because I don't feel that the answer deserves a downvote.

I can't find any possible duplicate so please if this question has been asked provide a link in the comment.

Comment: Related ? - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293524/what-to-do-with-a-highly-upvoted-yet-bad-answer-when-author-is-unconvinced?rq=1

Comment: Nothing drastically wrong with an answer that uses a documented api and warns that it *can* have unpleasant side-effects.  Posting a comment is pretty pointless, the author already knows it is slow.  Post a better answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel  that you can provide an answer that is better than any existing answer do so and let the community decide.

By all means comment *in your answer* as to why your solution is better than others if you feel it is warranted.

---

Comments on other answers *might* be appropriate but remember that comments are intended to be temporary.

Downvoting other answers is entirely a personal thing...the only guidance you'll get is the fact that the tooltip on a DV arrow is "This answer is not useful"...if it's correct, I'd argue it **is** useful.

How "correct/efficient" is entirely subjective...and so, arguably, not something to be voted on.

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D on this , but would like to add that StackOverflow, and the rest of the StackExchange family, is a place to ask/answer questions so that everyone can learn from it. In my opinion, this also includes situations like you pointed to. As long as you handle it professionally and inform the others why you think your answer is "better", everyone learns and improves.  As for the actual down voting of other answers, I personally save that for "obviously wrong" answers. Somethings the optimal way, is not as clear as the "slower" way where it's all spelled out.

Comment: Its depressing that so many people equate  "factually correct" with "useful".  Something being factually correct in no way makes it useful.  There are *all sorts* of things that can make a factually correct answer be not useful.  Being full of very bad practices is absolutely one of those possibilities.  Of course, not *all* bad practices can make the entire answer not useful/harmful, but there are plenty that can.