# A flagged answer that does not provide an answer to OP was kept. What's next?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

What happens when there's [a great comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python/30696682#30696682) written as an answer, so long it explains a lot about the technical background of the question but **does not** answer OP's question? (Explicitly states "go use some of the other answers").

Flagged it and got declined (maybe because of the sound explanation, can't blame them) so I might wanna know how far does this "not an answer" goes in this case. Also, what else could be done in such case?

Comment: It's a nice post with an explanation why not use a particular function. The author also mentions the next "_don't use `strptime`. Use one of the many other approaches described in answers here instead._ ". It is not an answer but adds _value_ to the other answers.

Comment: Also, answers aren't *only* for the OP...they are for other, future, users with the same or similar issues. Related - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313580/what-to-do-with-answers-that-teach-bad-practice/313581#313581

Comment: @Paulie_D that's a good comment with the link. More like I'm trying to understand about SO.

Comment: @KarelG indeed, as you can see I'm saying myself that it IS a great comment explaining all the background of the problem. As you say, it is not an answer but... it's really good insight.

Comment: [Is "Don't do it" a valid answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/179419). **tl;dr**: "yes"

Comment: @Ben please add it as an answer to check it as accepted. :)

Comment: I don't have time, but [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296764/458741) is a MSO answer based on my comment, based on a MSE answer, based on a MSE comment, based on a MSF answer, based on a MSF comment, that tells you what do do... METACEPTION!

Comment: @Ben how cooool is that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Flagged it

Why?

As opposed to all the code dump and "use library X" answers there, this answer actually explains the underlying problem.

> [flag] got declined

And rightfully so. That's [not what the "Not an answer" flag is for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag).

> what else could be done in such case?

Nothing. Upvote it.

Comment: Why? My question states that `it does not answer OP's question. (Explicitly states "go use some of the other answers")`. Thanks for the link.

Comment: So? That is _an_ answer. There are many good, existing answers that they refer to, they're just explaining why OP's approach cannot work. Would you rather see they add the content of existing answers to theirs?

Comment: Let's ignore for a moment the great and careful explaination in that answer. He's saying "use other answers but be careful about a common problem". Would that be accepted?

Comment: You have to look at everything in context. When adding a late answer to a question that has already many upvoted answers containing solutions, you do not have to repeat the solutions in said answer. If the post we're talking about was posted before any other answer, it'd better contain some example code.