# Improve quality of old questions/answers

Tags: discussion, support

Answers for very old questions posted some years back are becoming out of date with emerging technologies.
[Interface Vs Abstract class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class/1913185#1913185)

Earlier interface does not have any implementation. But with launch of JDK 1.8, interface can provide default implementation for methods declared in interface.

Some of the content is getting irrelevant.

***EDIT:***

I propose below actions to improve the quality of old questions/answers.

1. Community should re-open protected questions with a good score (eg, score > 5) in a phased manner. Once this question is active, people will update the content with new technical advances.
2. One new badge has to be introduced. People scoring positively for X number of answers on protected questions with age > 2 years etc, should receive a badge ( name has to be decided).

Comment: Provide a new answer! If it is good and correct, it will eventually get voted to the top.

Comment: that question is not specifically about Java, so Java 8 most definitely does not make it irrelevant. Bad example.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Not so much to put a sour tone on things, but I really don't think that will actually happen just from a probability standpoint. It seems far more likely that even the newest and most relevant answer to a most dated question will stay towards the bottom, if only because people will rarely ever scroll down to it while continually bubbling up the previously-popular answers and questions of the past. There is an inadvertent bias here to favor the oldest and most popular posts -- easily seen by visiting any "frequent" section of a mature tag. We don't find new mass-up-voted things there.

Comment: @Ike I [used to believe the same thing,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73858/show-most-recent-answers-first-in-old-questions) but I haven't been able to find a lot of examples where a superior new answer doesn't eventually make it to the top. (If you know some, I'd be interested in the list.) Don't forget that those users who use the "active" sort order see the newest post first.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Really? You have a lot more experience than me to be able to make projections based on trends. I must admit I'm seeing more narrow slices of time. But what if we turn the spotlight not to answers, but to questions? Is there a single mature wiki tag where a great new question (within the past year) could likely trump, say, this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: @Pekka웃 For answers I think there's a greater likelihood of a good one bubbling up to the top, especially if the accepted one isn't so good anymore. But questions seem to have a hard time against the increasingly higher and higher volume of question traffic to receive the same exposure as those highest-voted questions of the past. It doesn't feel like an even competitive field at least -- there's definitely a massive hurdle to overcome there, and sometimes I worry that the greatest newest questions will never catch up with those of the past.

Comment: @Ike it's certainly true that questions have it a *lot* tougher now - but then, ideally, there should be no need for the same question to be asked again, no? That doesn't change the fact that askers (and answerers) had it much easier in the olden days in many ways, but it shouldn't hurt the visibility of questions and their correct answers, at least in theory.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah yes, the past questions that are relevant are wonderful ways to eliminate duplicates. But I see my fair share of gems today, on par with those of the old, but rather fleeting.. they might get a dozen up-votes, and then kind of get lost in shuffle. It's where I kind of wish, like you did (but more on the Q side), that the site could kind of bias newer questions bustling with activity and shine the spotlight on them, promote more exposure, and a little less on the old. But probably the biggest downside of that is a higher chance for duplicates to be overlooked.

Comment: @Ike that's a fair point. There is a certain bias because upvotes play a role in curating the content that exists. I think SO are aware of this, though - the "most relevant" sort orders when searching questions and such don't seem to discriminate by upvotes much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a new answer explaining the change is welcome. It can however take a long time for that answer to rise to the top.

Therefore it may be useful to edit the existing, highest-voted answer with a sidenote sentence like *"Per JDK 1.8, interfaces can contain implementations, see [this answer] for details"*. Or rather, find a decent Q&A that already explain the changes to interfaces in JDK 1.8 and link to that, I'm sure it already exists.

The OP of that existing, highly-upvoted answer can then decide whether they want to incorporate the gist of the existing answer(s) into theirs.

Of course this touches the delicate subject of post ownership. I wrote the above considering that we're a community, and that you don't "own" answers per se: you write answers to improve the site as a whole, hence every (relevant, correctly written) improvement to an answer is good.

See also [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers).

Comment: "wrote the above considering that we're a community, and that you don't "own" answers per se" ... yes, but the community as a whole, and even moderators reviewing edits don't take this approach.  Blantant errors exist with no way to fix them but leave comments dangling and making a reader check the question (badly written), the answer (wrong), the comments of that answer to assemble the list of deltas that were never applied, and some things you can't just write in a comment due to limited formatting, and writing a completely duplicate answer with a small change is silly.  It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea of a flag in the link CodeCaster cited about flagging for obsolescence like so:

> *This answer may contain out-of-date information. Please validate this
>   answer and consider providing an answer with recent information.*

... though I think it would be okay to just flag the entire question this way. To me there's a point well beyond where a question still has a life line to bubble up answers, at least given the structure of the site.

Imagine if SO was around during Kernighan and Ritchie's days when C was the brand new thing, and being able to see the discussions between the language authors, experts, and even the intermediates and novices of that period, including what they voted as useful at that time period. I would have loved to have seen that, even though probably the majority of the information would no longer be applicable.

"Inapplicable" and "junk" to me aren't the same thing in a historical context, otherwise we might have shut down even some of Dijkstra or Knuth's posts in this hypothetical scenario as now being no longer relevant, and that would be a tragedy.

The problem to me is that this information is put on a *flat level* with new questions. It kind of leads to an uneven playing field. Imagine if the site grew to have 10 times the traffic it has already. Even the most relevant question today that is on the minds of a million programmers worldwide might have poor odds of bubbling to the top, since the high-volume question traffic would give it ill chance of receiving such wide attention. Meanwhile those 6-year old Q&As with epic votes tend to be repeatedly viewed for generations to come given the current state.

So I think beyond relevance vs. obsolescence, there is this issue where the site is inadvertently strongly biased to favor the oldest yet most popular Q&As, continually bubbling them up higher and higher to the top. Perhaps there should be something more to promote attention on the good questions within the past year, e.g., so that they end up having just as much or more chance of receiving the same wide exposure.

Perhaps we should have to dig a little more to even get to the most popular questions which are fairly dated by entering a zone where we can clearly be aware that the information may no longer be applicable today. If I'm looking for the most modern yet relevant questions, the "frequent" section at the moment of each mature tag wiki is pretty useless, as all the answers tend to be quite old (even if still relevant, it never shows me anything really new).

Comment: The answer is valid when the question is posted. Some part of the answer has become obsolete with launch of new features.  I prefer to revisit all protected questions by community. Community should take up responsibility to update latest developments.