# Can we do something about old/outdated/terrible highly upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) has 3 answers with >100 upvotes.

The 3rd answer (mine) is fine, but the 1st and 2nd answers are terrible by all accounts.

The first one relies on jQuery to do a loop (wut?), the 2nd one relies on **eval** to do a sum. Let that sink in. **eval** to do a sum.

What can we do about it? These answers create a bad (and even harmful) image for visitors from search engines.

Comment: Your answer is highest voted though - although I agree it is annoying that the one with the check mark sticks to the top. That should be done away with (but so far they've resisted the request.)

Comment: I left a comment for the OP in case he ever comes back. (Last seen February last year)

Comment: How the heck did the jQuery solution get that many votes? Faith in humanity: Gone.

Comment: I feel like the problem is more general. We can find other QA were expert programmers of the field would have not made the choice of OP. And often not the choice of voters.

Comment: @Cerbrus OP explicitly asked how to do it with $.each, so that answer was legitimate, even if it should have also explained how to correctly do that sum.

Comment: I feel that if the answers were incorrect, the community would have voted them down. Even if they suck, they're still answers - and it helps to show others how *not* to do it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: ah, I see. However, then the correct answer would be: _"Don't use `$.each`", use `x` instead"_, as I'm sure you'll agree :-)

Comment: @Jimbo: The answer should mention that it's how "not" to do it. If it doesn't, it's a perfectly valid reason to downvote the answer.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with bad answers. They're answers, and some people might find it useful for their *specific* use. If you don't agree with their approach, downvote and explain in comments - this might help future users to see its bad impact.

Comment: Vote totals depend on the number of views first, the quality of the Q+A is a distant second factor.  That one has had over a hundred thousand programmers looking at it.  No, we can't reasonably stop them from looking.  Or expect them to know the proper answer, they wouldn't have a reason to look.  Or expect them to know anything about Lisp :)  The accept mark is usually a good way to steer away from popularity, too bad it has the wrong one.  Your beef is with @amir.

Comment: "eval to do a sum." You what mate?

Comment: Downvoting seems like a possible way. May be slow but surely does the right thing in the end.

Comment: How about a feature that would allow the community to vote to change the accepted answer, that requires `max(10, acceptedAnser.score) + 1` votes to change the accept? Note that this would be separate from upvoting an answer, in order to cast a change-accept vote a user would have to upvote the answer *and* explicitly vote to change the accepted answer. Could be restricted to e.g. "established" (1K+) users.

Comment: I like the answer from amber too (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1230238/1536976). Without fancy stuff this sounds like the obvious approach at obtaining the sum of all elements of an array: just iterate over the array and sum.

Comment: @Trilarion That answer is also incorrect. `i` represents the array's keys, and not the values. So that will fail for any array that's not a consecutive list of numbers starting with 0.

Comment: I think that the question was originally rather clear: how to do so with `jquery`. The intent has been lost in continuous editing. The accepted answer is coherent with the initial question. Before asking to make your answer the accepted answer, you should consider the original question.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I honestly don't care at this point, as OP is long long gone. The question has an extremely high value for visitors from Google, and we want the best possible info to be at the top.

Comment: Well, if you don't care, why don't you continue not caring and move the accepted answer yourself, or ask the SO guys to do it directly?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: If someone asks you how to cross the Atlantic with a canoe, wouldn't you tell him to use a plane, instead? Just because the OP requests a certain method, doesn't mean that's the best method. Also, mods can't change what answer is accepted.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Because even moderators can't move the accepted mark. That's a power reserved only to OP. Were I able to do so, I would have done so in a heartbeat in this particular case.

Comment: It cannot be so difficult adding up some numbers in Javascript, can it? What about a single good answer that shows the three common approaches like plain iterating, using reduce or using jquery (if this gives any advantage at all) and comparing execution speed. That could then be an outstanding answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Then people shouldn't complain that the OP accepted the answer at the time he did so.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I don't think anyone's complaining about OP's decision to accept the answer. He asked and was answered.

Comment: Florian Margaine is complaining (since he posted this meta topic), Pekka 웃 is complaining as well (since he asked the OP to switch answer). So... yes, people are complaining.

Comment: "Can we do something" - Maybe remove or change the voting badges, increase rep threshold for upvoting rights. I don't know how willing the SE would be though; they have shown (in some of their other sites) that they like the increase in popularity and user happiness (even at the expense of quality).

Comment: The closure as _"This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community"_ is nonsense. There's plenty of dscussion going on here.

Comment: I agree the question's title is the question.

Comment: Then CV as dupe. Not as off-topic.

Comment: @Cerbrus I did. However 3 other guys didn't and so the system didn't mention it. But also the discussion is interesting. So while it is a duplicate, I'm happy with discussing it.

Comment: Btw. Someone gave a [very similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8878141/1536976) (using reduce) already a year before Florian Margaine come up with the idea. And it doesn't end there. One year later again [somebody came up with reduce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27456716/1536976) and [one year later again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28283756/1536976). This guy [measured the execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12995054/1536976) and arrived that reduce is even faster than a while loop (+1 for actually measuring it)!!

Comment: Maybe we should prove OP's point with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=13671297#resultSets). It tell us which answer anonymous users found the accepted answer more helpful... and unhelpful. But that's not everything, hot in its tail, the next more unhelpful was the eval solution, then the Q itself, and on the 4th position the for loop.

Comment: Way to farm rep...

Comment: @Cypher oh yes, I'm totally a rep whore. My history shows it. I'm also looking for badges!

Comment: Personally, I think that if you are an actual web developer (not a college student looking for the easy-way-out on homework/projects), then you are going to spend the time looking through every answer when you are Google searching and land on SO (or somewhere else). An experienced developer (should) know the consequence of copying and pasting the first answer they see, without reading further into it (comments, other answers, etc.). As such, I don't personally have an issue with the current setup. But then again, I'm nowhere near a power-user on SO.

Comment: Just to understand this (I don't know anything about javascript). Have the answers always been bad or are they just outdated?

Comment: Btw. another [evil eval](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15946541/1536976) of the same kind.

Comment: @MikeMB I think in this case the answers are rather bad, not really outdated because the first answer with the preferred (reduce) solution dates back to 2012. So already then or before the technology was there.

Comment: @Trilarion: The question, the accepted answer and the eval answer (which I believe is the only really problematic one) were posted in 2009, the preferred one in 2012, so I was wondering, if the accepted answer was the best one in 2009 (the eval version was probably already problematic back then)

Comment: Btw. the meta effect of today is about 80 downvotes on eval and 60 upvotes on reduce. Do we really need the deprecate thing?

Comment: @MikeMB I guess the while/for loop should have been one of the top voted answers of the time back then. The OP asked for jquery but of course normal javascript is part of jquery. There is this [duplicate from 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550183/sum-of-values-in-an-array-using-jquery) and the top voted answer is the for loop.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yes, actually I'd say this got a little out of hand, but considering the number of votes already on it that was probably necessary.

Comment: @Trilarion I think that the meta effect is nice, but then again that answer was there for *nearly seven years*

Comment: @PeteTNT And lots of people liked it and found it even a cool. Actually the syntax has a certain something. While it's dangerous to use, unfortunately it looks kind of elegant too. What is remarkable is the editing orgy yesterday. At least five major edits with big warning signs and at the end the answer is back at the initial state (of seven years before) and despite the warning people upvoted it. I personally believe this was an extreme outlier. Usually the voting is accurate with some noise. As long as there are not too many such cases we could probably solve them all just by meta effect.

Comment: "Terrible by all accounts"... *has 300 upvotes*

Answer (score 59):

So I'm just going to toss this out.

Let's say ..
*Five* people vote to *deprecate* an answer (let's say we gate this at 15k+ rep, gating it through tag participation is simply not possible from an engineering standpoint). Their combined signal says:

> This answer is probably actively harmful even if it was once correct, and needs to get the heck out of the way so the modern world can creep in

... would it matter if we took the accept mark away? We have gone through at least six possible implementations of this that attempted to preserve the accept mark without making the sort order even *more* confusing - it won't work.

For this to be able to work, folks would need to be behind the idea that as an answer loses relevance and usefulness - so does any accept mark it once had. Now:

- It wouldn't take rep away from anyone
- It would be a pretty silent ordeal. There wouldn't be notifications of this process - it would be very similar to deletion.
- A deprecated answer would still be visible, but marked as deprecated and at the bottom of the pile (above any negatively scored answers if they existed)
- The status could *possibly* be reversed if a substantial edit was made to the answer.

We'd need a feature request that aggressive in order to consider it again, folks really do need to be behind dropping the accept mark in order to make deprecation work. It's like the .. purgatory .. before deletion, so we need to treat it pretty much like deletion.

***I want to do this***, I've worked at lengths with Bluefeet and Shog in order to come up with a system that handles this (we were *always* supposed to have this in place, it was always Jeff's intent to close this gap).

Come up with a feature request that treats deprecation basically like deletion, but with some possible ways out of it for those that discover that something was deprecated *and still care enough about it despite knowing they won't lose any rep* to fix it, and we'll take another shot at it. We can't mess with the sort order, we can't make this process noisy and causing contention all over the place - but we do need something.

I'm open to any sane idea given the above constraints, with a decent amount of support shown for it.

***Here's a start on how to gate the feature:***

- Must be an answer (though, we want to know if many answers to a question are deprecated, because the question probably has some issues too)
- Must be at least 1 year old
- Must have received at *least* 5 down votes in the last 30 days *and still have a positive score of at least +5(? probably needs to be configurable so all sites can have it)* - otherwise just delete the darn thing
- Must not be community wiki - otherwise just *fix* the darn thing

... you can take it from here :)

Comment: With the gating mentioned at the end it might end up as a quite special thing to fix very special cases. There are alternatives however: Put the accepted answer even less often on top. Or: Decay votes with time (with a decay time inversely proportional to voting activity). Or as has happened here: Fix the darn thing and wait for the community scoring to eventually get a reasonable order again. If however you do this, deletion of answers, where will it end? Deleting posts against the score but still based on the content quality is still a dangerous thing to do I believe.

Comment: Tim, I'll type an idea up for this that I have. I'll post a link to the Feature Request here when im done. It could take a few hours though.

Comment: @Trilarion We've extensively discussed "unpinning" the accepted answer and that's not likely to happen - it's the signal that the OP found an answer that worked for them (good or bad) and we also assume it's a tested answer.  Whatever is put in place needs to be easily explainable to non-power users of the sites.  Decaying votes gets a bit difficult to explain to newish users, so that is also not likely to happen.

Comment: @bluefeet Why do you assume that newcomers are unlikely to understand decaying votes? Given that, for example 1/3 of the votes are negative? Won't this be a good indication that the post is controversial?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm not assuming they wouldn't understand it, I'm saying whatever is put in place needs to be be easily explained to non-power users. Don't forget that seeing the voting breakdown is a privilege earned 1k so a large portion of users wouldn't know 1/3 of the votes are negative.

Comment: @bluefeet Displaying the derivatives/trends of answers (maybe by nice little up or down pointing arrows) might be something worthwile to pursue. It also might be easiy to explain to newish users. This proposal here I don't like much. It looks like mistrust in voting and sets precedences. I hope it will not happen. I'm fine with additional symbols next to the post but deletion or putting at the end is too strong.

Comment: @bluefeet Well then please take a look at my [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314168/auto-expand-vote-count-warn-when-the-post-is-controversial), will be glad to hear your input.

Comment: @bluefeet Of course a "deprecation" warning can be added if X/Y of the votes are negative and happened recently.

Comment: @bluefeet I posted a feature request to "deprecate" old and inaccurate answers. Take a look: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314172/implement-a-way-to-deprecate-answers

Comment: Please also change this proposal to community wiki, it won't let me do that myself.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: If we have decaying vote, we probably also need a way to re-affirm votes... or otherwise a lackluster late answer will easily dominate a 2K+ answer if it just garners a few upvotes.

Comment: I like this idea very much. In addition, perhaps gray it out like with posts with -3 or less.

Comment: "preserve the accept mark without making the sort order even _more_ confusing"
And why is the sort order confusing in the first place? Why do we need to place the accepted answer at the top and not the highest voted one? What good does it do? Just get rid of that and simply sort by votes?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Well, if a post is both deprecated and heavily downvoted, wouldn't it make more sense to simply delete it automatically instead of adding yet another shade of gray?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, I mean if a question is marked as deprecated, color it gray even if it has 100 upvotes.

Comment: So the community would have the ability to revoke acceptance on poor answers for questions that have been abandoned by the OP? *Heck yes*.

Comment: I can see where this would be useful, but as someone who has sometimes had or seen posts where the highest voted answer was *not* correct for my question, I would be concerned about having this misapplied. It drives me crazy sometimes to people complaining about an accepted answer when the alternative highest voted answers do not actually answer the question, while the accepted one does. In my opinion, voting is already a way to mark a "community-accepted" answer, so we should leave the original asker's accepted answer alone. Comment on it or downvote it if it's bad.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is this really such a problem? Whenever I'm searching for information (be it on SO, Google, in books) I always try to find an up-to-date source anyway and weight it accordingly. Actually, one relatively minor change into that direction is to make the date of the last edit more prominent (e.g. at the top of the post). I know, that this would - by far - not have the same effect as what you are looking for, but it would also be very simple to implement.

Comment: @bluefeet: "This answer is useful only to the question asker in their specific situation" vs "This answer is useful to a broad audience, which may or may not include the question asker". Pick one. Pinning an answer sends the message that *the answer is vetted by the community at large*, not the OP alone (peer pressure notwithstanding). How are you going to try and explain your way out of that?

Comment: Just now seeing this (thanks to the recent deleted answer), but "gating it through tag participation is simply not possible from an engineering standpoint" that's simply not true. If it can be gated at 15k, it can be gated at X-tag-score.

Comment: @TylerH I'm sorry, but you're not qualified to make that judgement (having never seen the code, or having any knowledge of other potentially performance impacting things going on around January 2016). Saying something "is simply not true" is also, to me, an egregious mischaracterization of my intent in writing what I did.

Comment: @TimPost I think anyone who knows how programming works is qualified to make that judgment, especially considering we *already have* tag-gated functionality like tag synonym recommendations, unilateral duplicate closures, and the now-defunct SO Documentation bronze/silver tag-based abilities. Anything that is logic-based (e.g. "if this then that") is possible. I like to think the engineering team at SO is a pretty good one, to boot; I'm sure they could implement something like this. Also, please don't make this somehow about "doubting your intent"; you can be genuine *and* wrong.

Comment: There's a problem with "Must be at least 1 year old": Consider the "minecraft" tag on gamingSE. The current version of Minecraft is 1.15.1. Minecraft 1.9 was released in 2016, yet some people still play Minecraft 1.8.9 and sometimes even answer questions with e.g. commands that don't even exist anymore. Or, even if they don't play in those old versions anymore, they might still just answer from memory and do it based on those old versions. Maybe it's rare, but it's worth considering. I'm sure this happens in other areas as well, for example some companies still don't use Java 8 (2014) or newer

Comment: @FabianRöling I still sometimes play 1.6.4 (for purely nostalgia purposes!) so yes, I see what you mean. I didn't want to issue a comprehensive list in this answer, I was more giving examples of ways such a feature could be gated so it was still very useful, but not open to abuse (or just simple misuse). The "one year" was just an arbitrary characteristic that popped into my head, essentially just to get a more detailed / thought out discussion going :)

Answer (score 34):

> Can we do something about old/outdated/terrible highly upvoted answers?

## YES!!!

We can **downvote** them and **leave a comment** explaining that.
Bad answers are still *answers*, and they can teach us a lot on how "not to" do things - they might lead to very rich discussion and provide food for thought for all of us.

I do expect the minimum of minimum from users who came to the post. C'mon guys.. really.. let's not change the accepted answer just for the sake of the laziness of people who arrive here! What if the user is inactive forever? Do you really want to change the accepted answer? Do you want to delete it? Why? Just leave a comment... I really, really expect people to take comments into consideration, or to scroll down to see other answers.

When new users arrive to the post, they'll note the comments and see the "see other answers for the correct way of doing that". Maybe we can also have the vote count expanded by default with some "sum" near it - it might also give a good indication of the quality of the post.

If the accepted answer is misleading, you can also leave a comment for OP asking him to untick it and pick another one (although I really hate to do that, IMO it's enough to downvote and point at the problematic issues in the answer).

---

NOT To-Do list:

- Delete the bad answer
- Enforce changing the accepted answer
- Edit that deviates the answer from its original intent (even adding "Hey, take a look at other answers")

Comment: In practice, the vast majority of visitors from Google only ever look at the accepted answer (with the brightly colored V). That should be taken into consideration.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I think this is a naive belief that the power of intelligent downvotes can ever overcome that of robovoters just wanting to vote up the junk. Sadly...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I expect from us to comment on bad answers, and I expect users to read comments if they're there - not just copy and paste the snippet.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Users should have minimal responsibility before they just copy-paste a snippet. If the answer is bad, and they don't mind to read the comments, we can do nothing about it.

Comment: Also readers of StackOverflow should always at least read two answers if there are two because in a significant amount of cases the accepted answer is worse than the highest voted answer. And it's always good to know the alternatives.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: If a visitor from Google only reads the accepted answer and does not check the comments, well... it's its own fault? Of course it would be better to serve the best content first, but honestly if the searcher blindly copies/pastes rather than try to understand (and notably check if it really applies to her own situation) my conscience is clear.

Comment: @MatthieuM. We don't want to turn people into robots. Yes, I do expect the minimal of minimal from users who read an answer here.

Comment: @Trilarion Indeed. We can't enforce someone to scroll down, and we can't enforce OP to change the accepted answer just because others might be blindly copying pasting it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's a fair argument. And that holds true for "normal crap", but I think this is a rather special case, that little piece of code could literally end companies.

Comment: @MarounMaroun in this case, OP was last active in February of last year.

Comment: "We can downvote them and leave a comment" - In that case you would need another 100 downvotes to make it 0 score. Also, not everyone reads comments. Neither they should read them; an answer should contain any vital information within itself.

Comment: @Fermiparadox If they don't read comments and blindly copy-paste code, good luck for them.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I disagree with the downvote philosophy. In cases such as this, a more heavy handed approach is required.

Comment: A downvote is too insignificant here. Even now, it's at `-32`, yet still scoring over `100`.

Comment: @cerbrus A solution: if some equation, then auto expand votes.

Comment: That still says: "A lot of people disagreed with this answer, but even more thought it was a good answer". It doesn't indicate in any way that the answer is _dangerous_.

Comment: You have to also consider that requires less rep to upvote something than it does to downvote (you can see why this is the case) - however in cases like this it won't help. Weighting the votes might be a way around this but it's a lot of work - and even then people will no doubt complain about the power users.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. While downvotes and comments are valid options, this answer discourages edits to the disclamer, while I think some extra warning in there is __crucial__, and should be added.

Comment: @Maroun I totally agree with your comment and I always check answers even from multiple posts. But would still like a way to remove some of the junk around. Especially e.g. on Android tag there are so many answers I would love to get removed.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Wrong answers are still answers. We should delete only harmful, spam, irrelevant.. answers

Comment: @Cerbrus Nothing but a comment can indicate that it's *dangerous*. Displaying the vote counts (both) might give an indication that something is wrong.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The `eval` answer _is_ harmful. It's a nifty trick, sure, but one that should never be used in production. _At very least_, the disclaimer should be expanded. Users that have enough rep to see the vote counts aren't the users we're trying to protect here.

Comment: @Cerbrus Why is downvoting too insignificant. The 100 people who liked it won't all have been wrong, will they? At least they won't be in a statistical sense because in most cases it will be okay. That's how Stackoverflow works. You basically suggest to partially abolish the voting system?

Comment: The answer is _old_, and I'd wager that at least half of those upvotes are from people that visited the page from google, saw the answer, copy-pasted it, and upvoted it. On such high-traffic questions, individual votes are insignificant. Now, since the answers were posted, the scope of SO has slightly shifted, rules have changed, etc. What used to be a good answer, isn't necessarily one, today.

Comment: @Trilarion " The 100 people who liked it won't all have been wrong, will they?"  In this case, they objectively were. This answer is actively harmful for people attempting to use it. At least now the disclaimer properly states that.

Comment: @Cerbrus What what to do instead? Moderator intervention has been declined in this case here (see answer by Madara Uchiha here). Maybe vote decay with age? Like weighting them exponentially with age. That might be better but otherwise only the standard up and downvote mechanism is available and the meta effect. It's inbuilt into Stackoverflow that every vote counts the same for whatever reason it has been cast. Changing this would be a major operation.

Comment: @Trilarion I honestly believe in extraordinary scenarios like this it is in order to delete or heavily edit the answer.

Comment: @Magisch Yes it's wrong here but that is the exception to the rule. What to do instead? Editing the question is fully okay, but that doesn't change the votes. (Actually it changes the meaning of the votes which is somehow strange but...)

Comment: @Trilarion I ... don't know? Maybe the SE staff can use this case as a lynchpin to implement better ways of dealing with such old answers.

Comment: @Trilarion: The answer was modified, to expand on the disclaimer. Imo, this was the right course of action. (And a necessary one, at that)

Comment: As a side note, I work on a lot of legacy code and I often *need* older ways of solving a problem, as newer more efficient ones are not available to me. So I find outdated answers are often the answer to my question. And I find one location to find all solutions, with comments about each one, to be far more useful than a single potential solution which I'd have to judge myself with nothing to compare against.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If an answer is crap yet upvoted something has to be done.1) Crap is noise 2) Crap is a waste of time 3) especially for long answers, before you reach the comments you though it was ok : crap is tiring. 4) What weight will you give to a single comment, when the answer has 100+ score ? There's enough work in understanding how we can use a valid answer for our actual needs : we can avoid to turn a careful reading (that a rep'ed answer should deserve) into a scrutiny/enquiry/puzzle solving or like, so we should.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Comments are meant to be read. If the user doesn't mind reading it, we can do nothing about that, good luck for him.

Comment: @Rachel That wasn't a *once acceptable* answer though, but a *holy crap no, never* one. The first one, if the only thing *wrong* with it is not applying to the current version, just needs a note. The second kind needs a bold warning-sign and a deep negative score.

Comment: @canon It's a link to this thread, am I .missing something?

Comment: If this was Reddit I would gild this answer.

Comment: Wait, how did I end up looking at a meta question from 3 years ago?

Answer (score 18):

The scary thing is that it took a concerted effort from meta to do something about this answer. Even though that answer received 80 downvotes in short order, it still retains a positive score (41 at the time of this writing). Thankfully, the writer opted to delete his own answer. If he hadn't, that answer would still be out there steering people wrong. I mean, just look at that steady stream of upvotes...

[image]

It seems to take a lot of effort to oust an entrenched answer. All the energy we poured into that spike of activity seems to get steamrolled by the long trend of casual, thoughtless upvotes. Meta took its best shot and didn't manage to strip the post of a respectable score.

... nor did it detract overly much from the reputation gained from the answer:

[image]

That little drop in reputation is the meta effect. That was 80 or so downvotes in the span of a few days... which effectively changed the rep from 1300 to 1190. Is that enough to make most people care?

The answer *is* deleted. So, that's a win, right? Never mind how ineffective this particular process might be when applied broadly -and it's not; most of these answers never receive the kind of concerted scrutiny it would require to unseat them. Even if they did, the mighty meta effect might still fail.

Comment: Nice statistic for showing that Maroun Maroun's advice, though presenting a popular position, is completely useless. Unless and until the poster decides that *the damn thing should just have been deleted*.

Comment: If people ignore _"**WARNING**: This should not be used in production code, because `eval` invokes the JavaScript compiler"_ at the very top of the answer; they have bigger problems.

Comment: @jfs sadly, it's the world we live in. Plenty of people in our profession skim right over that stuff looking for a quick fix. Somewhere along the line, it tends to become _our_ problem.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1230461/5389107

This right here, is downright dangerous. Using eval() without any need to do so, I'm frankly shocked it got upvoted at all.

Maybe the explanation that already sits at the top of this answer, which reads

> WARNING: Some people insist this is not to be used in production code,
>   because eval invokes the JavaScript compiler.

Could be extended to

> WARNING: Some people insist this is not to be used in production code,
>   because eval invokes the JavaScript compiler. It also introduces various security concerns by tacitly treating potential user input as code.

Edit 2: The answer has since been further modified and improved, to add additional emphasis as to why not to use `eval()`.

Other users of the community feel free to rollback/modifiy the caveat when you feel I overstepped boundarys in doing that.

Comment: Go ahead. Do it. :)

Comment: @Trilarion Im uncomfortable with unilaterally editing the meaning of other people's answers, especially if they are highly upvoted.

Comment: Honestly, I'm genuinely considering to downright delete that answer if it enough people agree. There's a difference between "not helpful" or "not efficient" to "downright dangerous". We don't want downright dangerous answers, unless the question is "how do I not do this thing?"

Comment: @Magisch Editing to circumvent intent is frowned upon, but this is incorrect information. Their caveat about eval is insufficient and you're only adding useful information to their caveat to better inform users.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I don't think you'll get much opposition to the removal of that answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I was under the impression that moderators didn't police answer content or correctness, but im not a moderator, so I don't know for sure. Afaik, the rep will be preserved for the person if you delete it, correct? In that case, maybe thats the correct way.

Comment: @Magisch: To an extent, they don't. When it comes to "Downright dangerous", though...

Comment: @Magisch you're right, but this is a rather special case of "actively harmful answer" and "in the field of expertise of a particular moderator".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I would have no qualms with you deleting that provided it doesn't cause the user to outright loose 1300 some rep instantly.

Comment: @Magisch: He might gain some rep as it may get rid of recent downvotes. (Is the rep locked based on post age or vote age?)

Comment: See [suggestion of Rene](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314157/can-we-do-something-about-old-outdated-terrible-highly-upvoted-answers/314162?noredirect=1#comment291335_314163) in the other answer: The question should be edited to contain more explanation why eval is really bad. "While you could use eval for it in the following way... you really shouldn't because of ...".

Comment: I think that the **Some people insist** part is still down right offensive: the `eval` answer might be clever in a way, but it's still garbage way of doing what the OP wanted to achieve but not only that, it's raises various if not endless security concerns. My version would be something along "While this may seem like a clever way of achieving the sum of an array of numbers, it also introduces various security concerns by tacitly treating potential user input as code and should never be used in production code. See answer XXXXXX for a better solution" plus some reference why `eval` is awful.

Comment: @Magisch I think it may now be too long for something that must be read. Perhaps bold an entire sentence on don't do *and why*?

Comment: *"This right here, is downright dangerous."* **No, it isn't.** It's *wrong*, it's pointless, it's a really stupid way to solve the problem, but it's not *dangerous* to use `eval` on *content you control*. Not remotely. At all. The comments call out what's wrong with it. That's sufficient. @MadaraUchiha: Pinging you because you were considering deleting it.

Comment: I don't think it would be fair to delete that answer because of its harmfulness. SO is filled with upvoted answers that can be potentially dangerous. The answer is a solution that works for **some** people. It might be a terrible solution for most people, but it is still a solution for some. The best solutions are not always going to be checked. It is up to readers to determine that. The answer in question has plenty of comments explaining why is not a good solution. As a reader, I can learn from that.

Comment: I think it is really bad style to edit another persons answer with a comment esentailly saying *This answer is crap*, even if it is. Comment on it, downvote it, put it up on meta (all of which has been done), write your own answer pointing out the problems in the other answers, *maybe* make a short edit that states that there are caveats/problems (under which circumstances) and point to further information about that topic. I understand the desire to prevent bad information from spreading, but I really have the feeling, that this got a bit out of hand.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the answer makes no effort to explain that it's not dangerous to use `eval` on content that you control though. Next thing you know someone, somewhere, is using the answer to calculate the sum of an calculator output or something. I mostly agree on the sentiment that editing someone else's answer to call out it's bad is rude, but then again it's a trivial issue to fix that can pose tons of dangers, even if it can be *perfectly safe* but most likely will not be. Security is #1 and answers that are downright terrible should be flagged as such.

Comment: How about a new Flag -> This answer contains security implications which high rep users could review. With options being Look okay, Flag as dangerous and Delete?

Comment: @PeteTNT No need to flag IMHO. Just edit the post and add information about the security implication and if necessary downvote as not useful. Btw. I now believe the same should happen with deprecated answers/questions and most other issues with a post. Instead of flagging, just update information about the status in the post itself and vote. This is the most straight forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed many times already; and so have the below improvements; but I'll repeat them again:

1. The top post has a score of 61; but if you check the actual votes you see 93 upvotes and 32 downvotes! This is a good clue for anyone that something is up with this answer and should be handled with care. Showing the amount of up/downvotes by default for everyone would be useful.
2. There's also an answer with a lot more upvotes. I see no reason to pin the first answer to the top.

I would *not* be in favour of "deprecating" answers, what's "deprecated" for you may be very relevant to me. Examples:

- When is Python 2 deprecated?
- When are CentOS releases deprecated? 5, 6, and 7 are all still supported.
- Lets not even talk about Android versions!
- ...etc...

I forsee great discussions about when to deprecate what!

Answer (score -7):

The answers are community property as much as the questions and both are eligible for editing.

What is stopping you or anyone else from editing the offending answers with the caveats and warnings at the top of them?

If you do not have the rep or damage the answer in some way the community can roll it back or hopefully improve upon your edit.

Comment: That pivots on the question whether a legitimate warning is *damaging the OPs rep*, *misrepresenting his intentions*, *defacing his post* or the like. And many an OP will simply unilaterally roll it back anyway.

Comment: On years old answers where the answerer has not been active in months/years I do not see it as that big of a concern.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the only kind of posts needing it. And even without the OP, you easily get some spirited opposition.

Answer (score -15):

In my personal opinion, the `eval()` answer must die, and the sooner the better. I'm willing to delete it if no real resistance is raised.

As for the jQuery answer, given that the author is still active on Stack Overflow, I suggest pinging them and replacing (or adding) a better, non jQuery solution (like a simple `for` loop).

Comment: [Just do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0)

Comment: Oh man, this opens up so many requests to come. You don't know what you started...

Comment: @rene: requesting the deletion of answers that are actually _dangerous_?

Comment: @rene I consider the eval answer a special kind of dangerous. You could make a case thats its actively malicious code to some extend. I don't think the cavear is sufficient.

Comment: @rene If people open meta posts about posts which are actually actively dangerous for people to use, and there's a vast community support, and there's a mod that can properly assess whether or not deletion is a good solution, then bring on the requests.

Comment: Yes, I'm in favor of explaining in that answer why eval is bad and how it can be abused. Eval is still in the language and can be (ab)used, By deleting it you lose the opportunity to send out the correct warning. By deleting you deny its existence. Not a good tactic in my opinion. @Cerbrus

Comment: That will be sad for Stack Overflow.. The day we delete bad answers (that are actually answers - just in bad quality).

Comment: Those qualifications might just be enough to save you from being burried under the requests. Maybe...

Comment: I like that suggestion @rene.

Comment: @rene Explaining why eval is bad (maybe making it community along the way) - seems like a nice solution.

Comment: Also, worth noting, like I said, that's my personal opinion, and since I'm seeing the resistance being raised, the answer won't be deleted. I'm just probing for discussion here :)

Comment: @Trilarion: I would be astounded if there isn't already a canonical explanation about that, both restricted to jQuery and language-neutral.

Comment: @Deduplicator I believe that's the canonical. If you find a better one please let me know.

Comment: Adding a bold note is way way better like rene has suggested it. Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/QClec.png (One of my answers, still got a lot of dvs, but it is better)

Comment: Surely the real issue is that all votes are of equal value. Whether they come from Jon Skeet or Johnny McNewbie. A vote is a vote. So a small number of experts downvoting a dangerous answer can never outweigh armies of non-experts voting it up. Not sure what the best solution is, but force-deleting unpalatable answers seems a scary precedent to set. Though possibly drawing attention on meta alone could provide enough impetus to kill off terrible answers? We shall see... :)

Comment: I don't agree or disagree with your post but... [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers#comment100084_272570)  and [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers#comment100086_272570)indicate there is a different policy.

Comment: I completely agree with the deletion of the answer but I also agree there should be a policy behind it, which currently there doesn't seem to be unfortunately.

Comment: I do not agree on deleting an answer no matter how bad or how dangerous it is. It does not violate any of the SO rules. There is even a warning added to the answer. If moderators start deleting "bad" or "dangerous" answers, where does it end?

Comment: @KФ It ends with all demonstrably and provably false or dangerous answers deleted. That .... doesn't seem to bad?

Comment: I think there's plenty of warning about the dangers of `eval` in that answer to warrant leaving it alone. I think it's also worth mentioning that, despite the knee-jerk reaction in the comments, there's no actual security hole in the two lines of code in that answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard if the array is in any way filled with user input, there is.

Comment: @Magisch Is that array filled with use input? No, it's hard-coded with numeric values. Also, the warning about user input is *in the answer already*.

Comment: I strongly support immediately deleting dangerous answers with zero value. It's the moderator's job to keep the site clean in cases like this where the community can't or won't. This garbage is emitting toxic fumes, creating a public health hazard that needs to be removed. It's disingenuous for @BilltheLizard to pretend that this isn't a security hole because the example input is hard-coded when it's certain that the majority of potential users will not be in that situation.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You're spouting hyperbole like "toxic fumes" and "public health hazard," but I'm the one being disingenuous? The warnings about using `eval` are *already in the answer*. How many times do I have to say it?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I don't think the metaphor is very hyperbolic. Each year it becomes clearer the amount of software that is insecure, the number of users that are at risk. Each year, more people are impacted. Each year, the stakes get higher. It is extremely clear that most developers are going to remain security-ignorant for a long time. Those of us who are not have **a profound moral responsibility to society at large** to protect them from the negligence of our industry, as much as we can. No number of disclaimers is going to ensure that people won't copy highly-upvoted code. Deletion can.

Comment: Look, social responsibilities and example code makes for an interesting philosophical discussion... But let's stay focused here. If you really wanna make the case for purging unsafe code, better make some coffee first - we got a long night ahead. (In short: start a new discussion)

Comment: @BilltheLizard _"Is that array filled with use input? No [...]"_ But that's because questions and answers tend to use static values for demonstrative purposes. I wouldn't expect that future visitors searching for _"how do I sum an array of numbers?"_ would use the same static values in their own environment... nor would I be overly hopeful that the distinction between "numbers" and "strings" would save them if indeed _their_ environment was based on user input and there wasn't some parsing/sanitizing involved before processing.

Comment: @canon The answer was deleted 10 months ago. I think it's safe to find something else to worry about now.