# Answering an exact duplicate to make a new canonical?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just encountered a user who answered a very common question with popular canonical originals (one with two answers scoring above 1k). He stated that his reasoning for doing this was that - although the questions are identical - he wasn't satisfied with the other answers and intends to <s>self-promote</s> link the new question instead of the canonical originals in the future. He was the only one to post an answer to the new question, and I don't see any useful new information in it.

Is it okay to answer an exact duplicate question with no new information in an attempt to replace existing canonicals, or is this (as I suspect) detrimental to the site?

Comment: *"he wasn't satisfied with the other answers"* do they elaborate why? or why they couldn't just post in the duplicate?

Comment: For the most part, this all tends to be up to interpretation on a case by case basis. In general, one should not be answering exact duplicates, especially not canonical ones. However, I am afraid that the only answer to the question as written is "it depends" and without more context, there is no way to give a more detailed response.

Comment: Related (potentially duplicate): [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/1026459) I considered just closing using this, however, as you ask "is it okay to make a new canonical" I refrained as I found it fundamentally different.

Comment: Looks to me you are ready to take a break from SO and/or/any the [python] tag.

Comment: @Memor-X: Chances are their answer is going to go unseen if they post in the original because the canonical answers are front and center.

Comment: I added an answer to an original question (while closing the current question as a duplicate), and I got 2 upvotes on it after a few weeks. So playing by the rules can get you upvotes, provided that your answer is different than the other, older answers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Absolutely, and over time, that answer will rise in the answer list (assuming sorted by votes) as people find it useful. Voting doing its job.

Comment: You just have to trust the search engine for returning the Q&A you answered to :) sometimes it doesn't work as well as I described.

Comment: You've loaded your question with a presumption that the new answer contains no new information. Canonical dupe targets frequently suck! I have seen so damn many give-teh-codes canonical dupes that don't actually explain anything, or explain things wrong, or have security holes.

Comment: @user2357112 - It's not a presumption; I'm flatly stating that the new answer offered no new information over the existing canonical posts. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: By doing that, you're conflating the issue of making a new canonical dupe and the issue of posting an answer that adds nothing new. You should never post an answer that adds nothing new, regardless of what question you're posting it to. The way your question stands, it doesn't generalize well past whatever particular case you're looking at, and it's priming people to answer as if all attempts to create a new canonical dupe are bad.

Comment: @user2357112 - I would say it's a subcategory of duplicate answers (with unique motivations), and I was looking for discussion specific to such.

Comment: Does the discussion need to take into account that the original 'canonicals' applied more or less correctly to a version of the software that was current _N_ years ago, but the software has evolved since then so what was (and perhaps still is) useful to those using the old version is still valid _for the old version_, while a different answer may be appropriate for a newer version of the software (and the new answer may not be at all appropriate for the old version)?  It's pretty dangerous to assume no-one is using the old version — even for archaic code (I know of someone using DOS 6!).

Answer (score 44):

No, this isn't the right thing to do in the general case.

A user who thinks that the canonical question's answers are not adequate should:

- Post an answer to the canonical question that *is* adequate
- Vote to close the new question as a duplicate (perhaps with a comment linking to a self-written answer)
- Downvote any answers on the canonical that user considers "not useful"
- Upvote any answers on the canonical that user *does* consider useful (even if not — apparently — adequate)

There are probably exceptions to that rule, but they'd be rare exceptions.

The new answer, if more useful than the others, will get upvoted and climb in the list of answers (in the default sort order, by votes). If the question really is canonical and well-linked, that answer's going to get more attention than one posted on a duplicate anyway.

Comment: There's definitely cases where this doesn't seem to be enough to me though.  FOr example there's a question that was considered canonical at one time in Android on how to track GPS location.  The code in the accepted answer worked some of the time, but it had a lot of bugs.  It would literally take years to get that answer downvoted enough for a new one to replace it, in the meantime it was spawning secondary questions as people dealt with it not working.  In that case no longer using that as canonical seems like the best answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan: It's really tricky sometimes. There's an answer to a canonical JavaScript question which is simply wrong, but much-upvoted and accepted. The comments on it say clearly that it's wrong, and how, but the OP refuses to change it and doing so would be violating their intent. That's what I was thinking of when I suggested there were exceptions, but **rare** ones. But even in that case, I simply went ahead and followed the above, and my answer was swiftly linked via comment on the wrong answer by another user, that comment upvoted; and the answer has been steadily rising up the page.

Comment: @GabeSechan: In the case of your Android question, though, surely fixing bugs isn't violating the OP's intent? Esp. if you preserve the original code but highlight the issues, and then show code addressing those issues?

Comment: The bugs were conceptual in nature (he didn't understand the fact that just because a provider was enabled it didn't necessarily have a location, didn't understand that getLastKnownLocation could fail, etc).  It would have worked say 90% of the time, but getting the last 10% would require complete rearchitecting.

Comment: @canon: I'd feel bad meta-ing it. :-)

Comment: "The new answer, if more useful than the others, will get upvoted and climb in the list of answers" - yeah, right. You'll never get a new answer past an accepted, +400/-7 piece of crap from 2011.

Comment: @user2357112: There are always extreme cases; they don't disprove the general principle. I've had multiple answers rise up in situations like this, several of which were eventually accepted when the OP changed their mind.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Canonical dupes are exactly the kind of question that tend to have entrenched answers you'll never get past and an inactive OP who will never switch the accepted answer.

Comment: @user2357112: They also get a lot of inspection, and tend not to have completely rubbish +400/-7 answers in the first place. The ones that do are rare exceptions.

Comment: Is it really such a big problem when the best answer is not on top of the list? Can't we expect reasonable readers to read more than one answer, and the comments that point out the flaws of the highest-voted answer? Blind copy-pasting does usually not work that well anyway.

Comment: I mostly agree. The problem with this is that canonical-type questions tend to be old, and they frequently have several answers, several with lots of upvotes. In those cases, a new answer might not receive the attention it might deserve. I can't think of a specific example, but I'm pretty sure I've come across Java questions from years ago where the top 2-4 answers say "here's this awkward way to do it" from the Java 6 days, with 20-30 votes each... followed by a "here's a nice way to do it in Java 8" with a small handful of votes.

Comment: @canon, yes, some users will use the wrong solution, but to me the alternative seems even worse: A casual user that lands on the old duplicate will not have a chance to even see the better answer. As long as the old duplicate has more votes, it will probably rank higher on google and SO search.

Answer (score 7):

*As it usually happens*, there are two questions in one.

**In general**, as long as the new canonical is indeed better, it should be created.

In the PHP tag, for example, old canonicals are bloated with outdated and misleading garbage, so the new answer will be just lost there. Besides, it's better not to distract a reader with outdated or plainly wrong solutions.

As of the T.J. Crowder's dreams, they are about anything but real Stack Overflow. It's good for him to *wish* that everyone would vote like he said but in reality any garbage gets upvoted. Against one knowledgeable chap occasionally stumbling upon this question, there are hordes of noobs ready to upvote any rubbish they are impressed with.

**While in this particular case** you described here, as long as there is nothing better, the new answer obviously shouldn't be created.

Answer (score 1):

I have no objection to it.  Their question and answer should be marked as duplicates of the more popular one, so long as the more popular actually answers the question and doesn't have a huge flaw in it.

It can accumulate upvotes, and he can use it as a duplicate target/reference in the future.

If others agree, they may direct their duplicate effort towards his better one.  At one point, it may exceed the original one in popularity, and an argument may be made that the duplicate arrow should be reversed.

However, this effort is likely to fail, and that is acceptable.

People should only upvote this alternative Q&A if they find it generates added value to justify it.

Generally, it will be a waste of time.  It won't even generate more upvotes; the eyeballs directed at a popular "canonical" question, in my experience, do result in the "lower level" answers accumulating upvotes faster than a general question.  Very rarely the OP even comes back, notices that your answer points out flaws in the current top answer, and switches the checkmark.

You can link to a later answer in a canonical question just as easily as you can link to your own "private duplicate", so promoting it is just as possible.

The plan is harmless.  The gaming potential is small.  Unless the person is actually right that the existing canonical Q&A is a bad one, they are unlikely to succeed at their goal of surpassing it this way.

And there are cases where it is actually a good idea, and one should help; when the existing canonical Q&A are poorly worded and it is difficult to edit them to get the essence out; when the existing answer is outdated, or contains a fundamental misunderstanding/error that cannot be fixed without throwing the answer out and rewriting it, or other fundamental flaws.  It still probably wouldn't *work* (surpassing that canonical question and answer), but in these cases it is probably worth trying.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea for practical reasons. The canonical dupe will have lots of questions closed as duplicate pointing at it. If the would-be canonical post would become canonical in the future and the duplicate "arrow" should be reversed, then I believe we'd have to go through all questions closed-as-dupe pointing at the old canonical, before we could close it. Because I think there's a restriction that you can't close a question while there are duplicates pointing at it. Overall, the duplicate system implementation is quite crude.

Comment: @Lundin I don't know when it is and when it isn't allowed, but I've definitely seen questions closed as duplicates of other questions which themselves are closed as duplicates.

Comment: you can always comment negatively on the "most popular but crap" answer (I admit that downvoting won't help if there's 400 upvotes...).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It will *eventually*, if 400 people do it. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, the snowball effect can happen. I'd comment & downvote if the answer isn't salvageable. You can also edit it so it's correct if it's just slightly outdated. What would be cool is that people follow the duplicate link when a question is closed, and upvote/downvote/comment on the original questions instead of staring at them :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In the ideal world, sure? More realistically, the expert's downvote is lost amidst the sea of casual, uninformed upvotes. To unseat an entrenched answer, you must await the celestial alignment, marshal the meta armies under a single banner, perform a blood sacrifice, and _hope_ that the answer's author is still around and motivated enough by your downvotes to throw away the overwhelming rep he's earning in spite of the meta effect. Remember [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314426/621962)? Hey, sometimes the stars _do_ align.

Comment: @canon: :-) I'm a man of faith.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, you're just a romantic. :P