# Rename [openlayers] to [openlayers-2]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I just ran into a bunch of [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12112958) removing the [openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag from questions where the OP is using Open Layers 3, and the question was tagged [openlayers-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3).

According to the tag wiki, [openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) is supposed to be used for Open Layers 2 and is not compatible with Open Layers 3:

> OpenLayers 2.x is an open source Javascript web mapping library for creating web map applications. It is not compatible with the newer OpenLayers 3.x (see openlayers-3 tag).

Since versions 2/3 are not compatible with each other, I think the tag should be renamed to [openlayers-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) instead of keeping the generic [openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag.

Comment: I was just about to post this question, I ran into the edits too (and maxed review queue)! Also, currently there are [260 Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers+openlayers-3) with both tags. I start re-tagging them now to help. However, **I totally agree that it should be renamed**. I think most users do not actually read the tag description when posting, and from the name it is not clear enough that it should not be used for Open Layers 3

Comment: I was about to post the same question, to avoid the confusion that this tag is causing.

Comment: Instead of just numbering, why don't you create, dunno, [tag:javascript-openlayers] or [tag:openlayers-library]?

Comment: openlayers 3 has an API completely different than that of openlayers 2. So, it would be closer to comparing, say, Java and C++.

Comment: @Braiam But you could say the same about [tag:twitter-bootstrap] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3]. You would still need to number to see the difference in versions. Version 3 is apparently *vastly* different to Version 2. So, naming it [tag:openlayers-library] will still mean you need [tag:openlayers-library-3], and all you have done is created a longer tag name.

Comment: @Druzion please note that both tags simultaneously can be relevant to a few questions (mostly the ones related to migration from 2 to 3)

Comment: For context, checking GIS SE (http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/should-openlayers-2-and-openlayers-be-synonyms), I see that they have both openlayers and openlayers-2 tags, and they have decided to set the openlayers tag as a synonym of openlayers-2 (which has not stopped creating confusion).

Comment: Ok, I have gone through all the posts with both tags and retagged the ones I thought should not contain the "openlayers" tag (i.e. the ones specific to v3). However, some edits are being rejected. Is there a way I can tell why? Maybe I should have linked to this thread in the description of the edit?

Comment: And I just realised that in stackoverflow there is a "openlayers-2" tag, which is very rarely used.

Comment: @JoseGómez I didn't even see that before. I guess I should update the question to make this a merge request?

Answer (score -7):

No. Prevent confusion now! Use a single tag for everything. Merge  [openlayers-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3) and [openlayers-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) into [openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers). At the end of the day openlayers(2|3) *is* openlayers. If someone has a problem specific to the older version, they can perfectly state so in the body of the question, like [this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36816134/792066). BTW, **the creators of OpenLayers are pushing forward the version 3 quite hard**. I had to poke around to get the previous version, so there's no need for separated tags.

On the plus side, openlayer has only 4 and 16 questions in the last 7 and 30 days, while openlayer-2 has only 2 and 5 in the same period. [openlayer-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayer-3) is more popular than both having 15 and 80 questions asked. I say that since the velocity of new questions asked about the 2 version is slow, you could get away assuming every new question being version 3 unless the body shows the contrary.

Comment: Your reasoning could apply to all versioned tags. Why merge openlayers but not others?

Comment: @Oriol Patience you must have my young padawan. We will go there, in time.

Comment: I suspect the community is opposed to merging all versioned tags. So unless you provide a convincing reasoning that openlayers should particularly be merged, there might be no merge. If that reasoning is the last sentence, consider moving it to the top instead of being a BTW addendum.

Comment: @Oriol most powerful than "the creators of OpenLayers are pushing forward the version 3 quite hard"? They make no mention of that version, so you expect that given 1-2 years there will be no new implementation of openlayers 2, and the already implemented will shrink in number. Like the [tag:jquery-1.*] that never took off.

Comment: The question would be, would a question (and answers) for one version be useful for people using the other version? In this case, I don't think it is for the most part (at least not for me), since version 2 and 3 change a lot.

Comment: @JoseGómez if you want to "foo the bar with openlayers" would you ask two questions or one? That's the real question.

Comment: I would ask once, indicating which version I am using (in the title or the tag, if available). But other people may not indicate it as clearly.

Comment: @JoseGómez no, you will have to ask it *twice* (or more), one for each "new" version. That is pure madness. Questions should be *timeless*, and answers should either be edited to adapt to the ["natural evolution of the software"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066) or new answers if the existents can't be trivially updated. Having tags to differentiate between arbitrary points of time just balkanize the community, confuse the askers and makes less likely to get questions answered.

Comment: Well, I would have to ask twice if I were to implement it for both versions. If I am only using one version, I would ask it just once.

It's not about time or version numbers; there is a major API breakage between versions 2 and 3 of OL, which make all the code of one version incompatible for the other. Would you have the same tag for both C++ and C#?

If version 3 and a future version 4 do not differ as much as 2 vs 3, I would agree on keeping using the -3 tag for v4 questions as well.

I guess the OL guys should have named v3 "NG" instead.

Comment: @JoseGómez and why that should matter if you are trying to foo the bar? What you are proposing is the equivalent to having separated questions to "how to check if X condition is true, then do Y?" for each version of the software. THAT DOESN'T WORK. SE is a library of canonical questions with all possible answers, having to shift through several questions just the find the "right" one is inefficient and defeats the *raison d'être* of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, you used caps. Caps make you right. Thanks, it's all clear now.

Comment: With the upcoming OpenLayers release v4.0.0, the OpenLayers team no longer recommends using the openlayers-3 tag, but the openlayers tag. I created another retag request (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340754/please-update-openlayers-and-openlayers-3-tags).