# Is it OK to edit references to obsolete RFC with links to the new one?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, editing-help

[RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (HTTP/1.1) has been obsoleted by a set of new [HTTPbis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/documents/) RFCs 723x that contain hundreds of bug fixes and clarifications of the old RFC.

HTTP WG considers the new RFC to be a [complete, strictly superior replacement for the old one](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead).

There are plenty of answers that refer to the 17-year-old RFC 2616. The new RFCs are still relatively obscure.

Is it OK if I search for questions on SO that refer to RFC 2616 and use my mod powers to make them link to the relevant current [RFC 723x](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html) instead?

Comment: How about *also* rather than *instead*?

Comment: @JohnHascall Because RFC 2616 is obsolete and [head of HTTP WG says "Don’t use RFC2616. Delete it from your hard drives, bookmarks, and burn (or responsibly recycle) any copies that are printed out."](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead). The way I see it having both links would be providing both correct and incorrect information.

Comment: I assume you would only change it when the question is not specifically related to RFC 2616.

Comment: To my mind, if the RFC in question was in effect at the time the question was asked, it should be preserved. This feels kind of like when people want to go back and update references to older versions of documentation, to the newest version. If the question is about the old version of the language/library/standard, then the link to the older version should be preserved.

Comment: Can you petition for RFC 2616 to be given "Historic" status? Or have its headers modified to include "Obsoleted by"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: The old RFC itself will never be modified, but depending on which of its many URLs you're using to view it, there may already be an "Obsoleted by" header: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: @Kornel -- my thought was that by just silently changing the reference you might make the original answer "look stupid" if it was depending on context from the original RFC (as has been better explained by several others in the meanwhile)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066

Answer (score 13):

No, don't just edit the links en masse. Good answers linking to an RFC are likely quoting from it to support some claim. If you modify just the links, then:

- The quotes are unlikely to still be present at the new link
- The overall claim being supported may not even be true any more per the wording of the new RFC

Also, it's non-ideal to eliminate mentions of old RFCs from answers entirely, since those mentions provide extra information - that the behaviour the answer is describing was specced even back when the older RFC was written. Edits that remove significant information from answers are *usually* bad.

When answers reference obsolete RFCs and you want to do something about it, I'd suggest following a process roughly like this:

- Before anything else, determine whether the overall point the answer is making remains valid for the newer version of the RFC. e.g. if the answer says that frobnicating the widget is not allowed because RFC 231231 says *"implementations MUST NOT frobnicate the widget"*, check whether the newer RFC 645313 makes the same claim (perhaps in different words), or whether it says that *"implementations MAY frobincate the widget"*.
- If the whole answer is wrong in the context of the newer RFC, your best recourse is probably to comment on it and add a new answer of your own referencing the newer RFC and noting that the spec has changed between RFCs.
- If the overall point that the answer was making is still valid, then:

  - Update the link to the latest version
  - Update any quotes in the answer to whatever the equivalent passages in the newer version of the RFC say
  - Add in a parenthetical mention of the old RFC, noting the date at which it was published and that it specified the same behaviour (probably no need to quote from it in detail)

Alternatively, if taking the steps above would mean totally rewriting somebody's answer, feel free to post your own.

This is a lot of work, but taking half-measures like *just* editing links to obsolete RFCs risks leaving answers in a confusing and self-contradictory state. If you don't want to take on all the work above, that's fine - just comment on the answer noting that the RFC is obsolete and linking to the newer version, instead.

On a side note, whenever you link to RFCs on the IETF website, please, *please* link to the HTML versions like https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 instead of the plain text versions like https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616. Not only are the HTML versions prettier, easier to navigate, and easier to link to subsections of, but they contain headers at the top that note if the RFC has been obsoleted or updated by another RFC. These are *enormously useful* to readers a few years in the future who want to know whether the RFC they're reading still represents current spec or not, and favouring them over the txt versions religiously helps prevent the irritating phenomenon of RFCs that were obsoleted years ago still being cited as if they were present spec all over Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, please, *please*, **please** link to the HTML versions. If you do that then the obsolescence problem becomes largely moot.

Comment: `frobnicating` - I love this word.

Comment: "The overall claim being supported may not even be true any more per the wording of the new RFC" — isn't that an argument for editing or even deleting the answer? If the answer claims something that the HTTP WG found to be false, then the answer is now incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @Kornel it's an argument for editing the answer (extensively, to describe the behaviour per the new spec, or lightly, to note that what is being described is per the obsolete RFC XXXX - perhaps then posting a competing answer of your own). I think it's usually *not* an argument for deletion; information about old, changed specs can be useful, at the very least for understanding why different sources are contradicting each other, but sometimes directly - e.g. if HTTP now says servers MUST accept frobnicated widgets, but used to say they MAY, that matters to clients hitting old servers.

Answer (score -11):

Lets change the question a bit:

> Is it OK to edit obsolete information with new one?

The answer is a rotund **"Hell yeah!"**. So long as your changes are updating the content and not just the link, ie. the answer is obsolete by itself.

As I said in another answer:

> The actual issue here, and that I would like that we refocus, is that **we shouldn't keep outdated information sticking into the top**, specially if the "outdating" comes from a natural evolution of the software.

This was a natural evolution of the RFC standard which, among other things, resolved some ambiguities of the specification.

Comment: Changes that substantially alter an answer (possibly contrary to what it originally stated) but still attribute authorship to the original answering user are always inappropriate. Let me demonstrate.

Comment: @R.. that's absurd upon absurdness. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066

Comment: @R.. Fuck that off the ship. You want to truly own your posts, then write them on your blog. Posts are here for the community, and if the community can benefit from them being improved then your authorship is essentially irrelevant (given the right to be disassociated).

Comment: This has been discussed many times before and my comment simply reflects existing consensus. If you think the content of an answer is wrong, you write your own better answer. Editing is for *fixing mistakes* (typos, grammar, link without relevant text quoted in the answer, mistakes in code where it's obvious what the author intended, etc.) not for *changing the answer* to say something different than what it said.

Comment: @R.. "consensus" of whom? You are categorically mistaken about [why we allow edits and the bounds of how much you can edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066): All you can do is **treat the 'OP' with respect** and do your **best to be helpful with your edits**. That's all I need to know that any edit that improves the quality, clarity, freshness are good edits and should be [encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575).

Comment: @Braiam: I'd have to dig back up the relevant questions and answers on meta.