# Is there a norm that old accepted answers should not be downvoted or criticized?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes, answer-quality

I recently ran across an accepted answer that, while correct for the specific details of the problem given by the OP, was somewhat misleading without those details. (That is, if you only read the title of the question, and didn't pay close attention to what the OP was doing, the accepted answer would introduce an additional wrinkle to the problem that you might not be expecting.)

I downvoted the answer and added a comment, with a counterexample (different from the OP's). Instead of, say, editing the answer, the author commented:

> Thanks for the down vote on an accepted and correct answer that's over a year old. Good on you. Maybe I should take some time out to criticize some of your work.

It seems to me that the age of the answer and whether it's accepted or even (debatably) correct should have no bearing on downvotes or comments, but I could be wrong. Should I avoid downvoting or commenting on “old” answers?

Comment: @yellowantphil Possibly I shouldn't have downvoted while commenting. :) I would have thought someone with several thousand rep wouldn't take it personally, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: ["if you look at old stuff and still think it's perfect then that means you've learned nothing in the meantime "](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=33780138#33780138)

Comment: The age of the answer is completely irrelevant. That the OP accepted the answer does not determine whether *I* find the answer useful. And if the OP did not accept it or commented that the answer was not useful, that does not constrain my evaluation either. (Some OPs manage to reject excellent answers. Go figure!) When people get downvotes on their posts, some of them are quite good at coming up with imaginary "rules" that somehow make downvoting their post incorrect.

Comment: This smells like a veiled attempt to drown that guy in the meta effect.  But it doesn't link to the answer.  So now I'm in withdrawal.  Thanks.

Comment: @Will Linking to the answer seemed unnecessarily cruel. I'll settle for the satisfaction of having the community confirm I was right. :)

Comment: The OP is typically the worst judge of whether an answer is correct. If he knew the right answer he wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Hopefully the author in question *will* take the time to review your answers for you so that you are given the opportunity to correct any errors - if there are any.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I suggested in comments that he do just that.

Comment: @DavidMoles That information was not available to me.

Comment: @Will: tracking down the post in question is relatively simple. That said, the snarky comment quoted above is no longer present, so depending on what you're experiencing withdrawal from, spending the extra few clicks to get there might not solve anything. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Nah, it's okay, I just started shooting heroin.  Seems like a better choice, anyhow.

Comment: @EJP "Worst" seems like a severe overstatement (at a minimum, for a valid question, OP has everything set up to *test* the provided answers). And by the logic of your second sentence, P = NP.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ...so it's a good thing DavidMoles mentioned it, no?

Comment: There are two issues here. The big one is whether or not to downvote when the answer to the question (as posed in the post, not the title) is correct but maybe is wrong or adds a tricky wrinkle if one does not read the details of the post. That is completely separate from the time frame issue, which is irrelevant for downvoting.

Comment: You should have edited the question.

Comment: I think voter intimidation should be punishable like other minor offenses. It is an attempt at undermining the intended and agreed foundations of the site. Can we flag such malicious comments?

Comment: @DanielDarabos: you can flag it as _"Not Constructive"_ Those _"Maybe I should <...> criticize some of your work."_ comments don't add anything to SO, and will surely be removed.

Comment: Sometimes answers become incorrect years later, through no fault of their author, because for example a library is no longer available. I'd argue that if the aim is to encourage improvement, antagonizing the author with a downvote (which implies a criticism of their answer) is not constructive.

Comment: @neilfws I think the aim (my aim, in any case) is to provide useful and accurate information to those searching for it, and whether the original respondent improves is really neither here nor there. That said, I don't even remember this particular case any more, but I suspect that these days, with more moderation tools (and privileges) I would just edit either the question or the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

No, comments and downvotes are precisely for this purpose. Even old answers can have flaws, and it's OK to point them out.

The fact that they are accepted, possibly even highly upvoted, does not give it a privileged status. If you find a flaw in an answer, and can support that it really is a flaw, it is a good thing to point it out—it makes the site better for all of us.

As [@Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) points out in [their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341417/is-there-a-norm-that-old-accepted-answers-should-not-be-downvoted-or-criticized#comment431702_341419), this is even more important for answers that have a high score than for answers with a low score—if an answer has a high score, it is more likely to be considered a good answer—and visitors are more likely to unknowingly copy the problem into their own projects.

The courteous thing to do, is to keep an eye on the answer for a while. If the answerer takes the criticism to heart and edits the answer accordingly, reverting the downvote is appropriate.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's irrelevant.  In fact, I'd say that it's much *more* important to downvote/comment on an accepted and/or highly upvoted answer when it has problems.  An answer like that is one that would lead readers to actually think it's correct, so if it has subtle (or not so subtle) problems, it's all the *more* important that readers know about them.

Comment: @Servy I think Barth is trying to say that those doesn't confer a privileged status, on the other hand, I agree. The top post should be treated if not with the same, even deeper scrutiny. It's the first thing people see when they arrive from a search engine!

Comment: @Servy, Braiam - you are right. I've edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I wasn't too happy when an answer of mine from seven years ago was down voted because the source wasn't authoritative enough I'd used, admit it was Wikipedia but that was the best and most readable source I could find at the time, did seem unfair to punish me after the fact though!

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid I understand. It happens; we get both upvotes and downvotes on old posts. Nobody likes to be told that something was wrong, certainly not years later. I do believe that, if one finds flaw with an answer and downvotes it, one should also revert the downvote if the (supposed) flaw is addressed properly.

Comment: That's a good point, may be good to clean up old answers as when in time I've improved the way questions are asked and answered it's a good idea to see if can go through old stuff and improve it, that should be what I took away from it, hardly ever get negative rep so guess took it wrong way!

Comment: they're plenty of accepted answer that finally get less votes that another because it didn't work for other people than the op

Comment: "it's OK to point them out" -> "it is good and virtuous, and potentially beneficial to the community (and even the answerer!), to point them out". Especially if the flaws in the answer are severe.

Comment: @Walfrat yet they are the first one everyone sees because they are stuck in the top.

Comment: The tricky part is to downvote a high score comment...

Comment: Not important at all, but if you're trying not to use gendered language in your last paragraph you could say "The courteous thing to do ..."

Comment: Indeed, an accepted answer simply means "this answer helped OP/solved OP's problem". It doesn't mean it's *correct* or the best answer.

Comment: @BenBolker That was the word I was looking for when I wrote the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

Let me first say that I understand the frustration of the person whose answer you commented on. I've been in this situation several times, where an answer that I posted *many* years ago has been considered useful and helpful by the community at large, yet someone else comes along later and points out some flaw. Usually, these seem pretty nitpicky to me, which only makes them more frustrating. But even when they are absolutely valid objections, I don't like being forced to revisit and support every answer that I've ever posted to this site since the beginning of time. I have *a lot* of answers, and when taken to its logical end, this gets to be a truly massive support burden—not one that I am capable of or willing to sustain. Moreover, some of my earlier answers are for technologies that I *used* to know well, but that I haven't worked on in years and have therefore forgotten much of what I used to know. In order to fix the answer now, in many cases, I would have to go back and relearn (or at least refresh my memory on) what I used to know, which entails an awful lot of effort just to understand the nature of the problem, before I can even contemplate a fix.

But at the same time, I agree with everyone else that the age of the answer doesn't matter. The focus should be exclusively on the *content* of posts, not their author or their age or anything else. I also agree that old, high-scoring answers with flaws are *particularly* problematic, because these are the ones that people see and are most likely to assume correct. Therefore, downvoting and commenting are both perfectly acceptable courses of action when you see something that is wrong.

But I think there is an even better solution: **when you see a flaw in an old yet well-received answer** (whether through upvotes or acceptance), **consider using your edit powers to fix that flaw**. If you're competent enough to see the problem and comment about it, then you should be competent enough to just go ahead and fix the problem yourself. This prevents the frustration I described, because now all I get is a notification that my post has been edited, rather than another item added to my to-do list. It doesn't impose a burden on me. I don't have to make the hard decision of whether to fix it myself (if I even can), or delete it (despite the fact that many people have clearly found it useful). If, for whatever reason, I *disagree* with your changes, I have the power to roll them back. But the vast majority of the time, I'll appreciate that you took the time to improve my answer and the site as a whole. Even if I could have immediately made the change myself, you saved me some time. Otherwise, if I wasn't able, for whatever reason, to make the change myself, then I learned something from your improvement. Either way, everyone wins.

This is just another example of the rule that, when you see a problem you can fix, *you should fix it*, rather than trying to put the monkey on someone else's back. If you spotted the problem, you are in the best position to edit the answer to address it. The site is, in fact, based upon this premise: it is a *collaboratively maintained* repository of high-quality answers to programming problems.

If you see an old answer that was *never well-received* and/or contains *irredeemable flaws*, then just downvote it and consider voting to delete it. Comment if you want, but there probably isn't any reason to waste your time. Unless it's almost right and can be easily fixed, it doesn't *need* to be fixed. Either the other answers on the page are sufficient, or you should post a new answer of your own that addresses the problems. Blissfully ignore any whining you receive in such cases. Wrong answers not valuable, and unlike fine wine, do not become more valuable over time. (If you don't have delete-vote powers, then downvoting and/or commenting is often sufficient to get the person who originally posted the answer to revisit it and delete it themselves.)

Comment: There's also the fact that, short of raising a moderator flag (assuming they weren't already aware of that option), if the old answer in question is accepted (as seems to be pertinent in this question) then a user is basically *forced* to either keep their answer correct/up-to-date or suffer the downvotes, particularly if the question asker no longer uses the site.

Comment: @BoltClock I think it's better to have a collaborative minds to maintain the answers. Giving downvotes where you can contribute is like suing a poor person for his poverty: you may win the case, but nobody gets anything. It's better to just fix what you can fix instead of bother to giving downvote in the first place.

Comment: As a fun fact, I also had the opposite: upvotes on old answers that I don’t consider my best from today’s perspective, causing the same pressure to improve these old answers so I can consider them to be in line with their high rank.

Comment: "It doesn't impose a burden on me. I don't have to make the hard decision of whether to fix it myself". I disagree, it could be a completely wrong edit, and since it's your answer it would seem your fault. It should be reviewed to prevent this, so you would still need to refresh your memory.

Comment: @Oriol if it's wrong, he has the option to roll it back... which is a pretty painless process versus drafting the edit himself.

Comment: @canon Yes, but you need to check whether it's a good or a bad edit. So you still need to make an effort and refresh your memory about that technology you could have forgotten.

Comment: @Oriol well, the question also becomes active, in which case anyone can correct the wrong edit and/or comment about why it's wrong. Not necessarily the OP.

Comment: I agree with this answer but it's probably only usable by people whose edits don't have to be reviewed unfortunately.

Comment: @Chen Li Yong: Why are you replying to me? What does your comment have to do with what I was saying?

Comment: @BoltClock I was saying, instead of a user is basically forced to either keep their answer correct/up-to-date or suffer the downvotes, it's better to form a collaborative spirit where people with knowledge that knows what's wrong with the old accepted answer, can just edit the answer directly. That can solve the problem.

Comment: @Chen Li Yong: Oh, yeah I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 10):

It is perfectly fine to comment/vote on any question/answer irrespective of age.

Flag comment as "rude" and move on.

Comment: I wouldn't flag such a comment as rude / abusive. That is reserved for offensive content, and—if I recall correctly—it has a negative impact on the account. I can't remember whether this is just a counter for mods of how many comments a user has posted which were deleted with an active rude / abusive flag or not, but it does negatively affect the account. I would use "not constructive" in this case because that is precisely what this is.

Comment: ^ +1 for suggesting _"not constructive"_.

Answer (score 8):

We evaluate *the content* of the answers (or questions, or edits), nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: In other words: Votes, "accepted" status, user name or answer age are all irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

One factor which should be taken into account is the changing nature of the technology industry.

An answer which was excellent 5 years ago can often be defunct, obsolete or even wrong now. However, even if it's defunct by modern standards, it may be entirely correct for supporting legacy systems.

I don't know if that's the case here – the answer isn't very old – but in future, consider pausing for a moment to see if it has value in an older context before commenting/downvoting. It is especially true with new technologies that have reached maturity in a short space of time.

Comment: Not the case with this answer, but in that situation what I would generally do is add a comment along the lines of "this is valid up through X 3.6, but note that in X 4 and later you can do Y instead".

Comment: @DavidMoles An answer that is state of the art at the time and correct for them deserves to have the *question* edited to make the version of the language/toolset clear, not downvoted, if they don't update it.

Comment: @Yakk I think it's debatable (and maybe varies case by case) whether the question or the answer should be edited. If the question is general and already has a lot of Google juice, I think it's probably more helpful to later readers just to cover both versions in the answer.

Comment: (@Yakk but by all means open that as a discussion on meta! or point me to one if it already exists.)

Comment: @DavidMoles we already had [that discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066)

Comment: @Braiam I'd like that ffmpeg answer better if it was more specific about version numbers, but sure.

Comment: @DavidMoles what? That would be actually pretty counter-productive. Doing stuff isn't a "version" specific thing, and in the specific case of ffmpeg is a fricking [mine field you don't want](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3611/Ffmpeg.html). SO aims to be a library of canonical answers to programming questions, and to be canonical it means that you have to stay on top of things.

Comment: @Braiam I've often been in environments where I'm forced to use a less-than-current version of one thing or another. "Canonical" shouldn't mean "correct for the latest version at the time of posting, whatever that was, cross your fingers that it's been kept up to date, and if you're stuck on something earlier you're out of luck."

Comment: @DavidMoles but I'm sure as heck it doesn't mean "we should keep obsolete stuff for the 0.001% that it's stuck in the old version". Canonical means it works for 100% of the people, everywhere, anytime, and stays that way.

Answer (score -3):

Seems much of what OP is reffereing to, has happened here: only reading the title of the question without full details.  Note this quote

> That is, if you only read the title of the question, and didn't pay
>   close attention to what the OP was doing, the accepted answer would
>   introduce an additional wrinkle to the problem that you might not be
>   expecting

That is completely fine, and should *not* be downvoted. This has nothing to do with age. Someone had a specific problem, got a specific answer. This does not sound like case of being correct at some point, but becoming incorrect as time passes.

How does a specific answer to a problem becomes bad, if it cannot be applied to the rest 99% of population? Conversely, why should the answer deliberately not answer the question asked in precise manner, not accurately solving problem leaving OP hanging, just so it can be applied more generically? What about others finding the answer to that specific nuance helpful; maybe several people need that particular version instead of generic?

Comment: In this case, I think the OP genuinely thought they had a general
problem, and phrased and titled the question as such. (If not, the title 
[should have been more specific](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).) However, the accepted answer depended on a quirk of the detailed use case. I'm not suggesting the answer shouldn't solve the OP's problem. I'm suggesting that the answer should take into account its own long-term
future audience. (Especially when the general question is a good one.)