# Can we delete "When to Redis? When to MongoDB?"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400163/792066) already outlived it usefulness. There are already many results answering either of the questions, from [MongoDB vs relational](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/54373/104338), to [MongoDB vs MySQL](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql), to [what redis is useful for](https://redis.io/topics/introduction).

Basically, all information about either of them is available elsewhere, and some are maintained by the vendors themselves, which kind of assure us that is not going stale. I remember an image that basically summarized every database-like application in reliability, performance and something else... what I want to get at is that the topic has been beaten to a point where that question doesn't make a developer easier to decide whenever they need one or the other.

Can we let the internet do its job and delete that question for good?

Comment: I don't that question should be deleted, it has many upvotes, viewed many times and looks very helpful for many people.

Comment: @MarounMaroun who cares about drive by votes? ["We evaluate the content of the answers (or questions, or edits), nothing less, nothing more."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341439/792066) Why should this one be "special"? ["The fact that they are ... highly upvoted, does not give it a privileged status."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341419/792066)

Comment: #views and #votes are (very) strong indication on some post's importance or usefulness.

Comment: @MarounMaroun They are a strong indication of popularity.

Comment: @Louis Popular is important, not necessarily good or bad.

Comment: @MarounMaroun but it's not *the only one*. If you stop thinking about content and take into consideration just votes/views, then you are doing it wrong... very wrong.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't use the word "only" anywhere.

Comment: @MarounMaroun if you want to keep popular questions, that's ok, but at least ["make sure that questions and answers are popular for the right reasons"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

Comment: "Mongo vs. relational", "Mongo vs. MySQL" and "pros of redis" are certainly not the same angle as "Mongo vs. redis"…?

Comment: @deceze what is A vs B, but "what A is (not) useful for" and "what B is (not) useful for" separated questions?

Comment: While I agree that it's *too broad* etc., I disagree that the information is necessarily redundant, and that popularity is one of the dimensions that strongly needs to be taken into account. We don't need to delete every single thing on the site, there is much more important garbage to be cleaned up.

Comment: @Braiam How's that different from "how to compare strings in Java" questions? [The](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) [internet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html) has [many](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/string_compare.htm) answers.

Comment: @MarounMaroun because in that you are asking how to do *one single thing*. In this one is: what are the characteristic of MongoDB + what are the characteristics of Redis + when would you use them. Three things in a single question

Comment: @deceze do you remember that the broken window is real? If anything a post with that kind of votes/views has to have higher standards than drivel that will be eventually deleted by the system.

Comment: These kind of situations make me really conflicted. Its a poor question to ask, the top answer already confirms this in the first sentence as it depends on too many factors and thus is terribly broad. But of course the answers contain a wealth of information. IMO it being closed and locked is enough.

Comment: @Gimby what if I tell you that the wealth of information is better presented elsewhere?

Comment: I think the *historical note* Bhargav tacked onto it is sufficient enough to handle broken windows. If you disagree with that, we'll have to have a discussion on whether "historical significance" is a thing or not.

Comment: @Braiam We all know SO is not a replacement for the web, but we don't have a close reason or method of review for this case :) I'd be interesting to be able to close questions as being irrelevant based on an external source.

Comment: @deceze You know how to tell good jokes, you know? /sarcasm [Read this for all the gory details about how misguided are those notions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280826/792066)

Comment: @Gimby we already do, see this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478916/what-should-i-choose-mongodb-cassandra-redis-couchdb

Comment: @deceze It's been shown time and time again that historical locks are still broken windows.  People post meta questions, or angry comments in response to closure *all the time* saying that their opinion survey question should be allowed because there's another locked one like it, completely disregarding the lock notice.  It's why there's been a notable push over time to use historical locks less and less, and to only use them for *extremely* valuable content, rather than stuff that's just kinda sorta okay.

Comment: @Servy you know, the funny / sad thing is [it is really technically easy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285985/165773 "as discussed in more details here") to make these less of a 15-million-views broken windows. I sometimes wonder what so important do SE developers have on their plates that they can't fit just a few hours for such a simple and proven change into their schedule

Answer (score 5):

My answer to this is basically the same [as I gave you back in August](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332216/660921):

> Consider what deleting this question would mean: someone asks a question on Stack Overflow, which at the time was considered on-topic for the site. Some people spend their free time writing constructive and meaningful answers hoping to help the OP and other people in the future.
>
> Several years later Stack Overflow's policies have changed, and this question is no longer considered on-topic, but do we really want to delete the questions and all answers? That would basically mean chucking constructive content in the rubbish bin. Wouldn't that be disrepectful to the people who spent time writing answers?
>
> This is why a lock is a better choice. It effectively "archives" the question. It preserves the content but also prevents people from adding new content.

In short, it doesn't strike useful to delete content that people spent time creating unless it's obviously *terrible* for some reason. I don't see how this question fits the bill.

---

In addition,  I'm not even sure this question should even be closed, much less locked. "What is the difference between A and B?" can be a perfectly valid on-topic question and doesn't have to be a "Gorilla vs. Shark" type of opinionated question. I don't think that this question fits in the Gorilla vs. Shark category.

It *is* a pretty *broad* question, and that *might* be a good reason to close it. It could perhaps be made a bit less broad with an edit – not sure. Perhaps more importantly, I tend to be a bit more relaxed about casting *too broad* close votes if it's a reasonable question and is getting good answers, which seems to be the case here. Following rules *to the letter* for the sake of it is rarely useful.

I'm not sure why we need a lock though. It's not *that* wildly off-topic. IMHO just closing it should be enough.

---

All of your arguments in favour of deleting this seem to be rephrasings of "I don't like it". You are – of course – fully entitled to not like things, but that hardly seems like a very good reason to delete anything.

> all information about either of them is available elsewhere, and some are maintained by the vendors themselves

This seems pretty irrelevant to me. This has never been a criteria for deleting *anything*. Should we now judge new answers with a Google search and see if it's "good enough" compared to "what is available elsewhere"?

Besides, I would hardly call vendor-provided information reliable (especially in the case of MongoDB if you ask me).

> already outlived it usefulness.

I don't know if it has. Why? How? It seems to me that at least a few of the answers are fairly accurate. You may not *like* them, but that is an entirely different thing.

> the topic has been beaten to a point where that question doesn't make a developer easier to decide whenever they need one or the other.

That's your opinion. Others may disagree. It's a good reason for *downvoting* a question and/or answer. Not for *deleting* it. You can't just go "I mega-disagree with it, therefore it should be deleted!". That's not how it works (or at least, not how it *should* work).

---

Lifted from the question's comments:

> I'd be interesting to be able to close questions as being irrelevant based on
> an external source.  – Gimby 47 mins ago
>
> @Gimby we already do, see this
> meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066 – Braiam 44 mins ago

I've seen you use the fact that that question was deleted as an "argument" for
deleting more stuff several times already.
As I have argued before, it is **not** a good comparison. At all.

Look over the answers in that question, most are just "I'm using foo! It's
really great!". Hell, those answer are just *barely* even eligible for
copyright, as they contain so little creative effort.
If we remove all the "it's really great"-type of cruft then all we're left with
is a list of links. I don't see a single objective "this JSON parser is
different from others because [...]"-argument *anywhere* in that entire
question.

The answers on the MongoDB and Redis question are very different. They're the
result of creative effort, and contain some good reasoning on actual expertise.
I would call it a "[good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)".

In other words, it is a *very* different question with *very* different answers.
*Perhaps* it should be closed – as mentioned I haven't made up my mind about
that – but it most certainly shouldn't be deleted just because some other very
different question was.

Comment: _"You can't just go "I mega-disagree with it, therefore it should be deleted!". That's not how it works"_ - heh, you must be new to Meta.

Comment: "that people spent time creating unless it's obviously terrible" it's terrible man I tell you. They see this question in their search result and think "this is what SO should be for!"....

Comment: @Braiam What? A useful and answerable question about programming? Yeah, that's not at all what Stack Overflow is for!

Comment: This question *wasn't* on topic when it was first posted.  It's been off topic since the day it was posted.

Comment: Also, your argument that the usefulness of a post has no bearing in whether or not it merits deletion is just wrong.  Whether or not a post is useful is *enormously* relevant to determining whether or not it merits deletion.  Just saying, "it doesn't matter" to a bunch of points explaining why the post isn't useful is simply wrong.

Comment: "In short, Stack Overflow doesn't delete content that people spent time creating unless it's obviously terrible, which this question isn't." That's not really true. SO deletes all kinds of content that people spend time on. The threshold for keeping *this* question is not because people spent lots of time on it, but primarily because it has so many votes and views. Its popularity is likely why Braiam had to come to Meta in the first place.

Comment: If I'm reading this answer correctly is basically: we know that the status quo sucks, but you have to suck it, we don't want to change it.... which is totally uncalled for. You don't even have a strong argument in favor of keeping this question that isn't directly linked to it's popularity, and make no assessment about the quality of the content (measured in other than votes), nor the availability of the content elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: @Braiam I never even mentioned "popularity" or anything like it. I think this is a useful question with useful answers which shouldn't be deleted and possibly even be re-opened. I'm fairly certain that many – including you – will disagree with me on that – which is perfectly fine – but your summary is pretty off-base, and it seems you have missed the point entirely. To be honest, I'm somewhat baffled how anyone could summarize my answer like that...

Comment: So, if that's not your argument, what is? Because, other than that seems that you don't have other.

Comment: @Braiam My argument is in the answer. But let me repeat it: 1) I don't like deleting useful content people spent time writing. Yes, you think it's useless and worth chucking in the rubbish bin. I don't. 2) I think this is a useful, albeit somewhat broad, question which could *possibly* be edited to be on-topic. I certainly think we should *try*.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Your response to all of the points explaining why the answer isn't useful was "That's irrelivant".  So you're responding to several different notable pieces of evidence demonstrating that it's not useful with "I don't care" and then just *stating* that it's useful without actually support that position in any way?  That's not exactly how that works.  Briaiam's whole point here is that the post *isn't* useful.  And unlike you, he's supported his position by doing more than just stating it.

Comment: @Servy I see no such "support", other than various rephrasings of "I don't like it". Well, that's fine. I *do* like it. Do I now need to write an essay on what exactly I like about it? What I learned from reading that question and how someone else might learn something from it? How it compares to other information found on the internet?   Besides, a lot of the things said about this question apply to a significant portion of the questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Considering that you quoted the points in your answer, I don't see a reason to re-state them.  Since you took the time to quote them, I'll assume you did in fact see them.