# How to handle flags on very old posts

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Periodically I'll see old, highly-upvoted questions show up in the Close queues.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224154/find-unused-images-css-rules-js-script-blocks) is from February 2010 and, as of today (January 26, 2017) it has 32 upvotes and has been viewed 25,000 times. It also has 4 answers with positive scores, and the accepted answer has 40 upvotes and was awarded a bounty.

Recently someone voted to close it for being a request for an off-site resource. My thinking is that it's a bit late to be closing it now and that even if it actually *is* technically off topic the facts I mentioned above (32 upvotes for the question, 40 upvotes and a bounty for the accepted answer, almost 25,000 views) implies that this question is useful to a lot of people.

How should we handle cases like this in review queues?

Comment: It is not too late to close it, and upvotes do not make a question on-topic. Cf. [this very recent effort to clean up resource request questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/2751851). Also note that resource request questions tend to get more problematic over time due to link rot and other such facts of nature.

Comment: @duplode Should we necessarily get rid of upvoted questions with high-quality answers though? The mere fact that lots of people find the information useful would, in my mind, make it on topic.

Comment: "The mere fact that lots of people find the information useful would, in my mind, make it on topic" -- It doesn't. There is plenty of useful content about programming that is off-topic or otherwise not a good fit for the Stack Overflow format, and which is best maintained elsewhere. Stack Overflow is not all-encompassing.

Comment: PS: 32 upvotes is definitely decent, but its not necessarily to be considered a lot given the life span of 7 years. be careful what foundation you build your personal barriers on top of ;)

Comment: Related but not really a dupe: [Is there a norm that old accepted answers should not be downvoted or criticized?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341417/424903)