# What's the point of closing old questions that are unlikely to be deleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Related: [How to Handle Flags on Very Old Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342348/how-to-handle-flags-on-very-old-posts)

Consider as an example a positive-score question with an accepted, positive-score answer, and several other upvoted answers. Now suppose that the question is later closed. (This isn't theoretical, I've seen it happen before). My understanding is that this question wouldn't be automatically deleted, and questions like that aren't necessarily manually deleted either.

If a question already has multiple high-quality answers (including one that fixed the OP's problem) and is unlikely to be deleted, what's the point of closing it?

One major reason for putting questions on hold is to give the OP an incentive to improve the post and to remove low-quality questions that distract from better questions; however, this really doesn't apply in this case, so why would the OP have any incentive to improve the question now (given that they already got their information and the question's unlikely to be deleted anyway)?

Comment: What's the point of clearing that old wardrobe with tons of stuff you don't use anymore?

Comment: @Braiam That would assume that you're actually removing it from the wardrobe (in this case, the whole point is that you're actually not).

Comment: Well, you need to actually identify them before trowing them out. That you seem to be marking more than throwing out is just that the people that can do the later are prohibitively less than the former.

Comment: FWIW I only close vote old questions when they attract new, low quality answers.  I don't protect because they should be closed and it removes it from being used in the classic *well this question is open so why can't mine?* arguments.

Comment: @NathanOliver Those seem like reasonable reasons (could probably be an answer).

Comment: These questions also serve as a broken window, making people think that asking quesitons like these is okay.  It's a fallacious argument, but it's one that people are going to make anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is a reason to close a question it should be done no matter how old it is or whether or not it has an upvoted accepted answer.

One reason can be that old questions that once used to be on topic but now aren't anymore every once in a while attract new (mostly low quality) answers from users who are maybe not too familiar with the site yet.

The best way of dealing with this is to just close the question so that nobody can add any more answers. If you close an old question you don't necessarily want it to be deleted, you just don't want more people answering it.

Comment: Agreed, but I've been grilled a few times because of it. I'm a pretty good juggler in real life, but I don't particularly enjoy having to deal with double-edged swords.