# Edited incorrect answer, but my edit was rolled back

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, rollbacks, wrong-answers

I stumbled upon [this highly upvoted and accepted, but not really correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537649).

While the comments to the answer clearly stated the error, this did not lead the author to edit his answer or other users not to upvote it.

I consulted [this previous meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255470) and followed its approach. 
(Its question has no accepted answer.)

> Just my opinion, but I think the correct approach is to first write a comment to the author of the answer, and if (only if) they don't respond in some reasonable time, edit the answer [..]

The comment under [the wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537649) is from years ago, and people posted new answers, but those were rather short and probably didn't catch much attention. The accepted answer, on the other side, prominently presents its wrong contents.

So I decided - following the suggestion from the quoted meta answer - to [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5537649/2) and back my answer with links to the official specification.

This was immediately [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5537649/3) with the explanation that I should have just posted it as my own answer. I think this is ridiculous. At the time of writing (2018), my answer is at the very bottom, and most readers will still regard the accepted answer as totally correct. 
After all, *it's accepted, so it must be right.*

I think this should be handled differently. What should I do?

---

I didn't follow the advice of the most upvoted answer from the referenced meta question, since sole comments to the author obviously showed no effect.

---

I edited the answer again (just added a note) because it seems to still get upvoted. 
Does no one care that it's utterly wrong?

Comment: The editor actually lurks 'round these parts.  Tag them in that question and you'll get a justification as to why they did it.

Comment: I already explained why I did it in the revision notes.

Comment: Just need 53 more downvotes and than possible to delete the answer... (And author of the post not seen for more than year anyway)

Comment: @Servy I clearly stated in my post that I read your explanation... and my opinion on that

Comment: Hence why I didn't see the need to repeat it here.

Comment: @Servy I'm not asking you to repeat anything....

Comment: @Adrian I know.  Makoto was the one who asked for me to explain myself.  I was replying to that comment, not to you.

Comment: @Servy sorry I assumed you meant me since you didn't "@"tag him

Comment: @Servy:  Yes, I read that too...but it doesn't quite gel with the existing Meta question on what precisely to do in those scenarios.  I get that you're applying the "let the answerer be wrong lest the answer be invalidated"-methodology (and if I'm paraphrasing I apologize), but there have been cases in which edits which do correct older answers have been accepted under certain circumstances.  I'd be interested in hearing an opinion keeping that mentality in mind.

Comment: If the user hasn't been on the site for over a year, what's the point of keeping a highly upvoted wrong answer? I don't see the reason for that

Comment: The fact that your edit separated the answer clearly into "your part" and "wrong part" likely contributed to the rejection.

Comment: @user2357112 I was just trying to follow the advice from the quoted meta answer

Comment: This has been solved before, it is fine https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066 Servy should just back down.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure if you remember, but ^ it happened before. Shog said it was fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't follow the advice of the most-upvoted answer on the meta question?

Comment: I'm amused that no one has problems with some people reading misguiding information, with "high" reputability (look at the score!) and say "it is fine, we don't care about clueless users reading rubbish tutorials". Calling the kettle back?

Comment: Okay, it might just be me, but erm ... I don't actually see how that answer is wrong in the first place :/

Comment: @Just a student it is not immediately apparent why it's wrong. But the specification is clear. There is nothing against `&` just bc it's a bitwise operator. It just isn't when applied to booleans. That's why this answer is so dangerous. It seems to be right at first glance.

Comment: The answer doesn't say there is anything wrong with using it, as far as I can see, @Adrian. I'm not a C# expert, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686348) leads me to believe that `&` *will* perform a bitwise operation even on booleans (or, more precisely, the integers that represent the booleans).

Comment: @Just a student it is a bug that cannot be exploited using normal C# language features. What is relevant is the c# language reference. And that is clear. Just look at the syntax definitions. Internally, bitwise AND is also performed for the `&&` Operator anyway, since booleans are just abstractions from integers.

Comment: Sure, @Adrian, we agree there. So, maybe for my understanding, which part of the answer specifically is wrong?

Comment: @Just a student it is wrong to say that the one is 'bitwise' and the other is 'logical'. Apart from the fact that bitwise AND is also 'logical', the answer suggests it's wrong to use it with Booleans. This is not the case. Both operators are intended for booleans. Else they would not even compile (c# is very strict about such things)

Comment: But those are simply the names of `&` and `&&`, @Adrian. It stems from [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). I agree that the result of a bitwise AND on two booleans yields the same result as a logical AND would, but I wouldn't want to say that it is wrong to call one a bitwise operator and the other a logical one. Anyway, I see your viewpoint and the value of your answer. I just don't see how the other answer is wrong, and why it deserves to have a note edited into it. Thank you for all your responses and clarification so far, I'll leave it at this :-)

Comment: @Adrian The answer in no way says that `&` cannot be performed on a boolean value, or that you should not use it on a boolean value.  It just says that it treats the boolean values as if they were bits, and acts on them accordingly, which is exactly what it *does* do.  Nothing about that is incorrect.  You may not like that description of it, but it's not wrong.

Comment: @Braiam The answer wasn't edited to update it with changes that have happened since the answer was written, it was merely someone that didn't like the answer editing it into a different answer because they didn't like what it was.  The site has systems in place to judge answers, and subverting all of the unilaterally to decide on your own is not appropriate.

Comment: @Servy come on, is that an excuse to keep misguiding information? The *qi* of my post is here "keeps Stack Overflow being one of the **authoritative sources of verifiable, trustworthy**, practical, uptodate answers for specific programming questions" Right now it isn't verifiable nor trustworthy.

Comment: @Servy at no point do I say the answer says it cannot be performed. But it sounds like `&` is a weird operation and that it is a operation meant for binary manipulation. By the c# specification it is neither in the context of booleans

Comment: @Braiam And you think having one uninformed person who isn't particularly familiar with the material completely re-writing an answer that over fifty people thought was a good answer to edit in incorrect information is a way to improve verifiability and trustworthiness?

Comment: @Servy so you're saying reading the c# specs means I'm "not familiar"? What an utter joke.

Comment: @Adrian You said that it implied it, and used that as your justification for saying that it's wrong.

Comment: @Servy where did I edit in incorrect information? So the specs are incorrect? This is just ridiculous. Show me the part in my answer that is wrong **and** where the specs are wrong.

Comment: @Adrian Your statement that the answer is incorrect was incorrect.

Comment: @Servy just read the answer. It says `&` works on bits and `&&` works on Booleans. By the c# spec, both work on Boolean values (if applied to bools). That `&`  is a bitwise operator if applied to integers should not matter at this place. Neither how `&` and `&&` are actually implemented

Comment: @Adrian That you think the information doesn't matter is your opinion, an opinion that you're more than welcome to hold, and reflect in your vote on the answer.  But it doesn't mean you can replace the answer with your own answer just because you don't think the information it provides is relevant.  The answer correctly states that both operators can be used on booleans, and correctly states the exact semantics of each.

Comment: @Servy You even write *yourself* in one of your answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683266/1447296)  that `&` **isnt** a bitwise operator in C# , how can you claim that the accepted answer is factually correct then? It is sad to see that even after 3 years the wrong answer is still the accepted one

Comment: @adjan `&` can be *either* a bitwise or logical AND, depending on the type of the arguments.  My answer says that it isn't a bitwise AND *when the arguments are booleans*, which is true.  It *is* a bitwise AND when the arguments are integers.  So you saying that I said `&` isn't a bitwise AND is just a misquote of what I said.  The qualifications matter.  If you think an answer is wrong (or otherwise unhelpful), *you use your votes to reflect that.  Editing an answer into a different answer is not the appropriate course of action, regardless of how correct your or I think it is.

Comment: @Servy the question was in regard to booleans. I supposed you just dont wanna admit youre wrong (except for pointing out that editing the answer was the wrong approach)

Comment: The talljoe answer says that `&` is a bitwise operator on bools. That is, as you say yourself, absolutely wrong. I dont understand why you argued that the answer was "good" or "correct". And even now, its the most upvoted answer. Vote counts dont matter at all when judging correctness.

Comment: @adjan "The talljoe answer says that & is a bitwise operator on bools." No, it says, to *accurately* quote it, "`&` is a bitwise AND".  That's an accurate statement.  It's arguably a *misleading* statement, because it's *also* a logical AND when the arguments are booleans.  As I've said, if you think an answer is not of high quality, there exists several mechanisms specifically for you to convey that, and it's not for you to edit the answer. I didn't say that I thought it was a good answer, I said that your assertion that it's factually wrong is itself, wrong.

Comment: In the context of the question that is clearly talking about bools, this is indeed factually wrong. Look at the sample code. Look at the question. If it was not about bools asking for the difference between `&` and `&&` would not make any sense at all. Its not just a bad answer. You can't answer "the fruit has no seeds" if youre being asked whether apples have them just because bananas dont.

Answer (score 5):

You only "edited" the answer in the technical sense. You actually wrote a completely new answer, because nothing in the old answer is relevant after your added text, and should have been removed. If you *had* removed it, it would have been obvious that you completely rewrote everything.

Nothing in your linked answers supports a *complete rewrite*. I think the rollback was justified.

<sub>*I see that you have already made a much better edit since your question was posted, which solves the problem.*</sub>