# The Community vs. The Domain Expert

Tags: discussion, review-queues

So, I have a concern regarding reviews and I'm just probing the community for feedback.

The idea is that with enough eyeballs on a review, the community will arrive at a reasonable consensus. Now, that only works out if reviewers will reliably:

1. Recognize immediate, obvious problems like spelling, formatting, vandalism, i.e.: normal stuff
2. Judge the edit on its technical merit and compatibility with the original material
3. **Refrain from voting when #1 passes and they don't have the expertise to perform #2**

I don't know that **#3** is happening enough. It seems like the community is okay voting on content they don't understand. I don't want to see quality edits rejected because they *"changed too much"* when the reviewer didn't have the domain knowledge to judge whether the edit was an improvement.

Do you guys believe this is a real problem? I can cite examples if necessary but I'm more concerned with your current opinion, given your personal experience up to this point.

Comment: This is exactly why edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, and not to add or change the underlying content of the post.  Such changes generally shouldn't require domain expertise.  If you're trying to use edits to make factual changes to a post, you're using the wrong site feature.

Comment: Your proposal of encouraging edits to make factual changes, but asking reviewers to simply not judge edits that make factual changes they don't feel qualified to judge, will result in (if it were actually successful) the queue simply filling up with really niche topics that none of the reviewers are qualified to judge, effectively removing the suggested edit feature entirely.  The system only works when domain expertise isn't required.

Comment: If you don't have domain knowledge of the subject you shouldn't be reviewing something that requires said knowledge. Saying these edits shouldn't happen and reality are two very different things.

Comment: Ideally these edits should be done by users who can bypass this queue to avoid the problem entirely, but how do we deal with cases where something does need to be improved, but the person who notices it doesnt have said rep? do they instead ask someone else to do it, or do they put it into the review queue. neither option seems ideal, though asking the answerer or asker to do it is likely the lesser of two evils. At least then maybe a passerby with the rep could do it too.

Comment: @KevinB `If you don't have domain knowledge of the subject you shouldn't be reviewing something that requires said knowledge.` But that's just it; suggested edits were specifically set up *to not require domain knowledge to evaluate*.

Comment: @Servy and yet, here we are.

Comment: Are you suggesting it's working as intended, and all edits that aren't fixing formatting/grammatical problems should be rejected? i mean, that's a valid option, it isn't too damaging when it comes to suggested edits to answers/questions. Certainly wouldn't work for documentation, but that's another topic.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, with a largely functional editing and reviewing system, that works on the premise that anyone can review just about any edit, and so edits are able to be reviewed promptly, regardless of domain.  It simply means that suggested edits cannot be used to change the content of another user's post; if you want to add your own original ideas to a question, you need to do so with your own answer, an entirely workable solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm more inline with your stance on it that these edits shouldn't happen, but, it does create a bit of a double standard. these edits will still happen for those with 2k or more rep, simply because we can't stop it without also sending all of those edits into the queue. but... should we even care in that case. problematic cases in that area get flagged (auto in the case of edit wars)

Comment: @KevinB well, that line of thought goes against SE own guidance with edits: If you see something that needs improvement, click edit! For me, content curation is critically important for SO right now, and its importance will just continue to rise over the time.

Comment: @Braiam Right, but, the reviewers aren't capable of reviewing these things appropriately. Those of us with 2k+ rep can edit away freely so we aren't affected, only those that haven't earned trust within the network are barred from making those kinds of edits.

Comment: Just to be clear, this question is only asking about reviews in Q/A, not documentation, right? because documentation is a whole nother ballgame.

Comment: @KevinB documentation terrifies me. I've actively avoided it.

Comment: @KevinB the obvious solution is to promote sensible reviewing, how exactly? Maybe imitate MDN model? Or cpp reference one? These site seems to have figured out how to do it (they are collaborative editing wikis and good quality at that).

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a limit to the number of posts that can exist in the suggested edits queue, and they don't age out. So if these edits pile up and there is never a domain expert to review the edits, then the edit queue will eventually be closed entirely. The edit queue is designed from the ground up to be reviewable by users who don't have domain knowledge, and edits that require domain knowledge should be discussed with users who have the ability to apply the edit without it being reviewed.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've responded this elsewhere, but here it goes: the queue limit is totally arbitrary, in fact [we have never reached it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422783#graph). That's non an issue. Basically, you are using a problem we never had to prevent solutions we actually need.

Comment: See [Should people who've never asked or answered a question fo C be allowed to review C documentation changes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/) for a similar problem, and that has a link to the problem with wiki edits, …. There's an element of "it's an endemic problem around here".  Granted, not all edits and reviews always need domain expertise, but I think there are (lots of) times when people don't skip when they should.

Comment: This problem, is real, but IMO applies more to close votes.  People often vote to close a question because they don't have the expertise to understand what the questioner is trying to ask, when in fact the question could be easily improved. The questions never get opened again.

Comment: @SList No, they don't "often" do this. In fact, in the tags I follow, they *rarely* do this. Rather, this is the assumption that the asker often erroneously makes, out of frustration that their question got closed and the reality that the person asking the question thinks that it is sufficiently clear because it is clear in their head. If the question being asked is insufficiently clear or obvious that 5 *reasonably* experienced answerers think it should be closed, then it absolutely should be closed until it can be improved. You don't wait for the improvement to happen before voting to close.

Comment: @CodyGray "You don't wait for the improvement to happen before voting to close." That's maybe a bit of a problem. I wait with my close vote if I have the feeling the question has the certain something that gives me confidence it might be salvaged (difficult to define better). As for "are close decisions always right" - well if they would we wouldn't have reopen votes. My experience is that there is a bit of herd instinct going on with close votes but not very strong. Basically some people trust that the guys before them got it right. It's not a big issue though.

Comment: @tril Strong community consensus that you should not wait to close (see, *e.g.*, [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022)). Obviously not everyone follows this rule, but it creates problems when you don't, like questions that *could* be improved by editing *not* getting improved by editing and then *not* being closed. If you think the question is salvageable and don't want to close, then you should salvage it. Also, I didn't mean to imply "always right"; rather, that closure isn't for lack of expertise.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I'm not the asker in this situation, I've seen it happen on less frequented tags, where there are fewer experts.  People make judgements that they are not qualified to make.

Comment: @Braiam "Maybe imitate MDN model? Or cpp reference one? These site seems to have figured out how to do it (they are collaborative editing wikis and good quality at that)." Actually, out of curiosity: how are they doing it? What is the biggest difference between their quality control and our review systems?

Comment: I could be wrong about this but it seems that when I "skip" stuff in the review queue (be it close votes, edits or whatever) I get more test reviews. This is kind of irritating and feels like skipping is being discouraged, which IMO it shouldn't be

Comment: @canon *when the reviewer didn't have the domain knowledge to judge* -- Aside from merely disagreeing with a particular edit rejection, how do you know how much domain knowledge a given reviewer has? You say that you can cite examples, and I think that doing so would help us all to understand specifically what you think the problem is. Can you also cite evidence that this is a widespread problem?

Comment: @Trilarion MDN seems to use a flag where you can ask for a technical or editorial review (your changes are applied immediately, but reviewed post-facto)

Comment: @Braiam reviewed by whom, I wonder?

Comment: @Trilarion I think the biggest difference is that they don't give out fake Internet points, so editors only edit if they want to improve it.  cppreference doesn't seem to have any formal quality control process, which probably only works because there are few contributors.

Comment: @Trilarion: The quality and reliability of MDN has been declining as of late. It's still the definitive JavaScript manual for obvious reasons, but when it comes to other web technologies like HTML and CSS, I can no longer recommend it except for general reference.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The very idea that fake internet points can make any difference seems so fanciful until the moment you see grown people fight about them. It has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Braiam A post-facto review is probably okay unless you attract vandalism or many lowly skilled editors. But still, this seems to be a viable alternative to our reviewing process delivering good quality. Kind of: as long as there is a review at some point... approach.

Comment: @Trilarion well, for the MDN you have to clear the hurdle of having a Github account before editing anything, which works with the assumption that most developers has a GH account.

Comment: No, @KevinB is not that "reviewers aren't capable of reviewing these things appropriately", is that we do the impossible to prevent the right reviewers to do their job. I've filled a FR [that addresses this problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575). Basically, it aims to put review tasks in from of those that are able to do a sensible evaluation.

Answer (score 37):

[It takes *no* domain expertise to edit for grammar or spelling.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251928/1079354)  I won't deny that it's helpful to have the domain knowledge, but it absolutely isn't required.

You have to understand the difference between editing for presentation and editing to improve its factual accuracy.  The vast majority of editors are equipped enough to tackle the former, but not necessarily equipped to tackle the latter.  The key misunderstanding with many is that they believe that these two edit types are the same, which isn't the case at all.  In fact, some editors may attempt to conflate the two edits together, which leads to someone rejecting it for changing too much.

My genuine belief is thus:

- If a user wants to make grammar changes, then they should *exclusively* make grammar changes.
- If a user wants to make changes to improve the accuracy of the post, then there's two cases to consider:

  - Do they have knowledge of the OP's situation, gleaned from comments?  In that case, it's fine; just include, "The OP said this in comments" or something analogous in your edit summary.
  - Do they *only* have domain knowledge of the problem and believe it to be an issue with how the problem is presented?  **Do not edit!  Answer instead!**  Editing the question in this scenario hides the fact that the OP didn't know any better, and could lead to answers which the OP has no means to apply to their problem.

Comment: @canon You shouldn't be editing something like that into someone else's answer.  If you want to add your own original explanation to an answer, post your own answer.

Comment: @canon: A new answer is still preferable in that situation.  If the answerer is wrong, then vote and comment accordingly.

Comment: @canon: If you're talking about an answer being plagiarized, then it should be deleted.  Using a custom flag on the answer would be best rather than a ham fisted attempt at an edit.

Comment: @canon Because posting your own answer is what you do when you have your own answer.  You don't just edit your answer into someone else's answer.  That's how answering works.  Different people post different answers when they each feel that they have something to contribute.

Comment: there is a gray area, believe it or not, where an answer may have a typo or minor inaccuracy that you as an editor can fix. These very often get rejected by people who blindly reject anything that touches code. (fortunately i have the rep to bypass this queue)

Comment: @canon That's not what edits are for.  Edits are there to improve the existing answer's content, not to add your own original content.  To do that, post your own answer, even if it happens to also include a citation for another answer in it.

Comment: Whatever happened to the logic that, in an ideal world, a question would have a single, highly-upvoted, community-audited, well-maintained, canonical answer that would be easy to find? If every time someone wants to add something non-trivial, they must post a new answer, then we've become indistinguishable from a traditional web forum, which we all roundly agree sucks. And in practice, no one will actually do this. The best you can hope for is they'll post a comment to the existing mostly-good answer, which is also strongly discouraged. This answer selfishness is destroying the site.

Comment: @CodyGray That was never the premise of the site in the first place.  You seem to be confusing the site with Wikipedia.  The premise of the site is different people each post what they feel is the best answer, and the best answer rises to the top through voting, not through different people editing someone else's answer into what they think the best answer is.  The primary way the site was designed to distinguish itself from more traditional forums was through the voting pushing the best answer(s) to the top and separating out *answers* from clarifying questions and other meta information.

Comment: @CodyGray If the premise of the site was always having one answer that was community edited into "the answer" then there wouldn't be any need to have multiple answers in the first place, answers wouldn't be attributed to a particular user, ever answer would effectively what Community Wiki answers are, etc.  But *that's not the way the site was designed*.

Comment: A second answer should be posted if you have something substantially different to say. You know, a *completely different answer*. But if you just want to expand on an existing answer that is otherwise perfectly adequate, you don't fork it and put your own name on it. Your recollection of the purpose of the site is rather different than mine. Stack Overflow didn't innovate the idea of voting on stuff on the web. There are plenty of other online forums that had that even before 2008.

Comment: I think that both Cody Grays's argument that adding another answer for every content update is bad as well as Servy's argument that editing one arbitrary chosen answer with updates is bad are both justified. That leaves me with the conclusion that a trade-off is required somehow, but I fail to imagine what it could be.

Comment: @Servy What about making answers community wiki. Wasn't this thought as the way to enable others changing the content of a contribution?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes; if you're posting a contribution that is not your own work, but rather was created as a collaboration of many people, you can indicate as much by posting it as CW.  It's also a way of saying that, for that particular answer, the underlying content itself can be edited by the community because that particular answer was specifically designed with that in mind.  Pretty much everything I've said throughout this question doesn't apply to CW posts, but it's just not practical tacking, "except if the post is CW" to the end of every sentence.

Comment: @CodyGray You should be posting your answer if you want to contribute your own original content.  You should be editing to improve the presentation of someone else's content.  That's is what edits were there to do.  I never said SO was the first site to ever have voting, of course it wasn't.  Other programming Q/A sites tended to not use them though; they applied the practice taken from Reddit (and other less technical sites) to the technical Q/A  sites.

Comment: @Servy "You should be posting your answer if you want to contribute your own original content." That's very nice and clear, but it also means that potentially the number of answers can be be very large with lots of redundancy between them because everytime somebody wants to add even a tiny bit of content he would have to post a new answer. I could easily spam the whole site by taking all the top voted answers and publish another answer combining them and the best of their comments. Probably half (or a significant amount) of the knowledge on SO Q&A is contained in the comments. Intended?

Comment: @Trilarion And yet, even with the site working this way for the past 8 years, that hasn't been shown to be a significant problem.  Clearly your fears that it would happen are false, because it *doesn't* happen (at least not often enough to be a problem).  Note of course that if you went around doing that you'd need to be citing the content that was not your own, of course.

Comment: @Servy In general I agree, although for some questions there is a large number of answers and there is some redundancy between and there is also important information mostly contained in the comments. It's good as it is, no doubt. It may be better with a different approach, who knows. We may never find out. Doesn't make our system perfect.

Comment: @canon Except that they don't, generally.  They realize that other people's answer are their answers, and feel that if they have their own significant contributions to add to the topic they can post their own answer, and do, when they feel it's merited.  When they have small clarifications most people content themselves with commenting, and allowing the author to correct their post as they see fit.  But hey, apparently virtually everyone else here on this site is insane.  It's just you that's sane.

Comment: @Trilarion Questions like that tend to be questions that are very broad, or questions that are opinion based.  That's why those types of questions are supposed to be closed, rather than answered, because SO's model of answering simply doesn't work for questions like that.  There are rare exceptions, but by and large when you see questions with huge numbers of answers it's *probably* a question that should have been closed for one of those two reasons and just wasn't (or wasn't closed quickly enough).

Comment: @canon Indeed.  (Of course, that's not how they're actually used, but yes, that's the design.)  The intent is that the author incorporate the content into the answer, if they feel it's merited.  Additionally, if the user feels that the content is significant, rather than a minor point, or if the author disagrees that the content in question is appropriate, the user can post their own competing answer.  Oftentimes one of those two things happens, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The real success metric is probably how many top voted answers (total length of them) does one have to read on average to get a kind of complete picture and how much redundancy is there in between these answers. This is difficult to estimate and even more difficult would be to predict how this would change with somewhat changed rules. However the discussion here convinced me that in practice we are quite good without changing the content of answers. The only thing left might be to compare the average quality of a community wiki answer with a normal answer.

Comment: @canon If someone has a code-only answer and you want it to be improved, comment on the answer requesting some more information, even if you personally know enough to write that information yourself. If the OP responds or adds more info via a comment, *then* you can edit that content into the question or answer (**while being sure to mention in the edit description that you're just copying OP's own words from the comment to the post**).

Comment: @CodyGray re: one answer per question; one of the criteria for a beta site being healthy is that it has an average of 2.5 answers per question. It is baked into the whole engine that there should usually be more than one answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant yes, 2.5 answer each with their own point of view. Not the same answer vomited, re-vomited and regurgitated a bit more answers (btw, since some years now, CM don't rely too much on quantitative metrics)

Comment: @Braiam there are thousands of questions (if not more) that have multiple answers containing basically the same code (possibly presented in a slightly different manner) but different explanations. Realistically, the explanation is what is worth anything. Sure having some copy-pastable code is a plus, but it is the explanation that makes the answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've flagged to delete answers that do nothing but rehashed previous answers, you know? And they have been deleted, leaving only the oldest one which is normally of higher quality. (BTW, I mean verbatim or diluted answers, which don't even reach the same quality as previous answers).

Comment: @Braiam and that is not what I'm talking about, and the obvious choice in that situation.

Comment: @TinyGiant You said "there are thousands of questions that have multiple answers containing basically the same code", and I said "I've flagged to delete answers that do nothing but rehashed previous answers". How is that not related? You acknowledge that there is content duplication, and I fight to remove it.

Comment: Because if it has a different explanation then it is a different answer. If the explanation is the same, then it is a duplicate answer and should be deleted. @Braiam

Comment: @TinyGiant what? How about no explanation at all? How about semantically the same explanation (different words, same thing)? How about just a single extra sentence?

Answer (score 16):

This appears to refer to suggested edit reviews. I don't believe people doing reviews without technical expertise is much of a problem, for the following reasons:

Stack Overflow is not Wikipedia. A post should not be edited to radically change the technical content (with a few exceptions listed further below).

If a *question* is missing a lot of important details, then it should obviously be edited by the OP. There is no way anyone but the OP can fix it. Close vote such questions as off topic -> lack details to reproduce. In case the OP left a lot of code in comments, then it is fine to edit the question and include this, though make a comment to the edit reviewers "pasted from comments by OP" or similar.

If an *answer* is missing a lot of important details or is simply incorrect, it is not a good answer. It should not be "fixed", it should possibly be down-voted with a comment explaining why it is not a good answer. Then the radical changes needed to correctly answer the question should be posted as a new, separate answer.

The only time an answer should be edited to change the technical content is either when the OP of the answer made some simple mistakes that can be fixed without changing their intent or drastically change the answer. Typos, simple syntax errors, formatting etc.

Note that minor syntax errors should never get fixed in a *question*, as they may be the actual cause of the problem described!

---

Given the above, suggested edit reviews therefore rarely require domain knowledge. Most such edits are actually invalid and should be rejected. Apart from the following exceptions:

- Minor technical edits to an answer as described above.
- Edits that change tags of the question. This often requires review by a domain expert.
- The post is a community wiki.
- The post is a tag wiki.

I suppose tag wiki edit reviews by people without technical expertise might be a valid concern. But most often such reviews is only about ensuring that the text isn't some copy-pasta from wikipedia or other sources.

---

A much greater concern is the "robo-reviews", which is a persistent problem on the site, and has been discussed on plenty of other meta threads.

Answer (score -3):

> I don't want to see quality edits rejected because they "changed too much" when the reviewer didn't have the domain knowledge to judge whether the edit was an improvement.

Users get access to the suggested edit review queue as part of the [**edit questions and answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege. You seem to be worried that people who don't have sufficient domain knowledge are judging other people's edits, but these very same people have reached a reputation level that lets them edit any question or answer in the system without having their own edits reviewed at all!

It seems to me that if the community trusts someone enough to give them unconstrained edit privileges, there's little reason to be concerned about their ability to judge the quality of less trusted users' edits. Furthermore, rejecting or accepting a suggested change requires consensus among several reviewers, all of whom have edit privileges, making it even less likely that a good edit will be rejected or a bad one will be accepted.

> Do you guys believe this is a real problem?

**No.** You say that you can cite examples, and it would be surprising if there weren't *some* examples of edits being judged badly. But a handful of examples aren't sufficient to show that this is a problem that happens often enough to worry about. There are many thousands of posts and at least hundreds of suggested edits on any given day, and I think we'd see a lot more complaining in meta if good edits were frequently being rejected. There are also measures in place, such as test questions, that are designed to improve the quality of reviews.

If you have some data that shows that there's a substantial problem with the review process please post it. *Then* we can have an informed discussion about the size of the problem and what to do about it. Absent that data, your concern seems more like well-intentioned speculation.

Comment: "making it even less likely that a good edit will be rejected" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338986/792066 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340745/792066 "or a bad one will be accepted" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338914/792066 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332552/792066 not as unlikely anymore.

Answer (score -5):

> I don't know that #3 is happening enough.

I don't know either. Therefore, is the community as a whole really okay voting on content they don't understand? For example, couldn't it be also a side effect of robo-reviewing?

We first need to find out if this is a problem (not just believe in it or not believing in it). How to find that out?

Review the reviews

If that turns out to be a problem you have the choice of:

- more controls (audits) with potentially harder sanctions
- require more votes before a decision is made
- more warning signs (example: Are you sure, you understand the topic?)
- stronger limiting reviewers by rep
- limiting reviewers by topic (you need to have at least XX badge in at least YY of the tags to be able to review)

As it is currently, it's the job of the audits to wed out any wrong review activities including this. Audits may not work good enough. Maybe they can be improved.

General remark:
The better the content is already the higher the chance that an edit of a human which can err is lowering the quality. Therefore being more and more critical is probably  desirable. On the other hand you still want to be able to update content and improve it, so there is a trade-off. In the end, a certain amount of newly introduced noise is unavoidable. You can improve the situation by doing one or more of the above mentioned actions.

Btw. my guess is that even the un-supervised edits for >2k rep users introduce new errors from time to time.

My personal experience: ~80% of edits improve the content and ~20% make it worse (numbers are just gut feeling)

Comment: You have made the assumption, along with the OP, that edits that are making changes to the actual underlying technical content of the answer are okay in the first place.  They are not.  Pretty much any edit that is changing the technical content of the answer *merits rejection* because that's not what edits are there for, so to assume that people are rejecting edits that change the author's consent giving a rejection reason that they're changing the author's content *are reviewing correctly*.  It's people that are approving edits that change someone else's post that are the incorrect reviews.

Comment: @Servy I see. Interestingly the proposed actions (more audits, more required votes, more warnings) mostly stay the same. What drops is the requirement for the reviewers to actually know anything about the topic.

Comment: I don't see how more audits are going to help.  Either the audits are catching people actually reviewing improperly, or they're not.  More of them would mean it would take maybe 2 days instead of 3 for them to get banned, not out of the question, but if there really were a major underlying problem that wouldn't fix it.  Same with more reviewers.  If the common consensus was simply wrong, requiring more reviewers wouldn't change the outcome.  There's also not much correlation between rep and reviewer quality past a certain point, so increasing it is unlikely to help a ton.

Comment: But again, before implementing any of those you'd need to demonstrate a problem that they'd be there to solve in the first place.  As of yet, that hasn't been done here.

Comment: @Servy "If the common consensus was simply wrong, requiring more reviewers wouldn't change the outcome." That depends. If for example only a minority gets it wrong, you get more decision power the more votes you have. But I fully agree that we would have to first demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score -13):

There are no easy things in this life: working, studying, sports, programming, designing, etc. Therefore *reviewing is, also, hard* (or not easy). Even the most obvious problems require domain knowledge of *something*: the language (in this particular case, English), the markdown syntax, the concepts you are reading about, etc.

Considering this, reviewers are required (in theory) to know about whatever they are reviewing. Since they are *reviewing*, we expect that they are able to critically evaluate if the actions being taken [conforms with guidance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIK5s.png).

Expecting a reviewer that is basically a monkey with a <s>keyboard</s> mouse to give a sensible evaluation of what is being reviewed is as likely as the same said monkey writing something similar to Shakespeare.

I prefer having a sensible review by an expert, even if that means having the queue to grow infinitely. I doubt this will be a problem since there is at least one user, the very author, that is notified of any edits on their own post. If they aren't available in a sensible amount of time, we can simply invalidate the edit and hope for the best.

Comment: I agree, but, i think we may disagree on how we decide whether or not a reviewer has said knowledge (or if we even should.) I'm more included to say this should be a guidance, rather than a hard enforced rule via badges/rep/whatever

Comment: The queue has a max size of 200 items.  When there are 200 items in it edits are not allowed to be made at all.  Additionally, there are *lots* of posts out there where the author isn't actively monitoring the site, and either won't ever be able to review the edit, or won't be able to do so in anything resembling a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @KevinB of course there's no perfect solution, I doubt we will reach it. But something sane enough that strikes balance between the ugly and the good should be workable.

Comment: @Servy do you know that that limit is totally arbitrary and can be modified by SE (remember, only triage and suggested edit queue has any sort of limit)? If we can build a good case to allow the queue grow, SE is likely to comply, since [they are worried about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/). If we solve both problems, do you believe that SE won't be flexible about it?

Comment: @Braiam Then you end up with many, many posts out there locked for editing, because there's a pending change that there aren't qualified reviewers for, and you end up with a review queue that becomes functionally unusable.  When someone needs to skip through hundreds of posts to find a single edit that they can actually review (because there's a backlog of thousands of edits in niche topics) then people will either stop reviewing edits, or make decisions that they don't have the expertise for (I guarantee most will do the latter).  You just create more and more problems.

Comment: @Braiam You *haven't* found a way to solve *any* of the problems, you've just suggested ignoring all of the problems.

Comment: @Servy Care to share your own solution instead? I'm saying what should be the *ideal*, or you could say say "if-this-was-Canada-and-not-real-life" solution. For me, the problem to solve is: how to allow sensible edits on the system. I don't know what problem you think I am solving?

Comment: @Braiam The current implementation is far superior to your suggestion, which is functionally equivalent to just removing suggested edits entirely.  Of course, if we want to talk about entirely unrealistic ideals, ideally no post would ever have problems meriting editing; they'd all just be perfect right from the start.  Of course, discussing entirely impractical idealistic situations isn't really productive.

Comment: @canon ewww..... one of the reasons I invested time on SE is that ["the content is clean, neat, and professional looking."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251937/792066) You know how painful is consuming content that is not like that?

Comment: @Servy ideally, there shouldn't be hunger in the world, it's impractical to reach that goal? Maybe. It's worth to pursue it? Absolutely. Ideals are to be pursued, otherwise we wouldn't have the industrial revolution, reached the moon, had computers. How many times the ideal that everyone said to be impractical or impossible hasn't been reached, albeit not perfectly?

Comment: @canon you think that stale or unexplained content is presented correctly? A book that can't be understood by its reader, nobody will want to read it.

Comment: @Braiam: "*ideally, there shouldn't be hunger in the world, it's impractical to reach that goal? Maybe. It's worth to pursue it? Absolutely.*" But you can't solve world hunger by denying people food. If you come up with a solution that makes the problem worse, that's less effective than doing nothing.

Comment: @Braiam If you think a post is a bad post, because it lack an explanation in entirety, then there are *lots* of tools for dealing with a bad post.  You can downvote, you can comment, to explain what's wrong with it, and *you can post an answer that's *not* bad.  The solution isn't to say that anytime you don't like an answer you should edit what you would have posted into that answer instead.  If you want to post your own answer *you can always post your own answer*.  If I think your answer here is a bad answer should I edit it to correct it and explain how edits should actually be reviewed?

Comment: @Servy yeah, right, that [worked on this case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338392/792066)? But lest go towards a more serious topic: **what is to you collaborative editing?**

Comment: @canon Making edits that require domain expertise to judge is fine, but when the user has <2k those edits should be discussed with other users who have domain knowledge as well as the editing privilege. In a perfect world (which it isn't), the suggested edit queue would not just be a bandaid (which it is). With the tooling that we have in the edit queue, it is just not possible to ensure that domain experts will ever see the edits that require their expertise to review. If you want to make a request to change the tooling to support the reviewing you would like, I wish you luck.

Comment: Let alone if, as mentioned before, reviewers have to wade through 30+ technical edits to posts in niche technologies in order to find an edit that they can review, they will probably stop reviewing. So you end up with more edits in the queue, staying there for longer, while discouraging reviewers, causing less review items to be reviewed, resulting in an ever growing queue that becomes harder and harder to manage.