# Why is a specific edit request rejected?

Tags: support, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14622673) fixes a genuine bug in my opinion, but it was rejected. I am the author of the original answer, and the commenter (xoolive) picked a bug in the code. I suggested to him in a comment to the answer that his comment is correct and that he should edit the answer to fix it.

Later I see that the edit was rejected with the comment "deviates from the original intent". I can't see why using the `inspect` module in a couple of lines would deviate from the original intent.

Can you please reconsider?

---

Specifically, in Python code when more than one parameter has the same type there are no guarantees that the dictionary `__annotations__` will be able to distinguish between the parameters given that the order is not preserved and the keys of the dict in the original code are lost.

Comment: Unfortunately many people will just reject edits that touch code on sight instead of evaluating the edit or skipping if unable to evaluate it. If you want it approved you always have the option of single handedly approving edits to your own posts if you happen to be online whilst it is pending.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I wasn't online at the time.

Comment: For the rest, can you help me understand why this question is downvoted so much? At least comment so I can know the error of my ways..

Comment: Because it's Meta, and people downvote questions where they fundamentally disagree with the premise. (And where they think you have done insufficient research, especially on a topic that's been covered a lot elsewhere on Meta.) Don't worry about it; the community is *very* divided on this, as evidenced by the current even split in votes. And downvotes don't cost you any rep on Meta, so it's simply a gauge of the community consensus.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/792066

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In suggesting to someone else, a low rep person, that they edit your answer your are implicitly relying on the edit reviewers to understand enough about the issue to approve the edit. Much of Stack Overflow's review system relies on people who are not domain experts using their judgement about topics in other domains. An edit that changes code, an edit that seems more than just a typo, is likely to be viewed by many as changing the original author's intent.

For this issue it might have been better to change the answer yourself and say a "thank you" to the person who reported the issue.

Comment: So we in StackOverflow are supposed to reject any suggested edit we cannot understand rather than skip it?

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri I am not sure what you are asking or suggesting with your comment. I have read several Q&As here on meta that emphasise the recommendation that people should skip when they are not sure. We all know that there are too many robo-reviewers who do not skip when they should.

Comment: That was my understanding, and that is why I am limit my review to what I know. But the interpretation of "people who are not domain experts using their judgement about topics in other domains" coupled with the fact in this particular edit that it was rejected by three none of which had any real participation related to Python on the site, while accepted by two people one of which contributes largely to Python, give that perception. I would say there is something wrong with our incentive system for reviewing.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri if you disagree with current review system - make new proposal as separate post. Make sure to come up with decent criteria on who should review edits (obviously filtering by tag score does not work as you've seen in many similar requests on SO - so come up with something better...)

Comment: Fair enough. I will look into that, reviewing the relevant discussions we already have first. My guess, it will take time to come up with something reasonable.

Comment: TBH this is why SO needs a weighting system for domain experts, so those who do know have a higher dong than those who don't

Comment: @Sammaye or best of all: [show you something you can do a sensible review instead of whatever](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575)

Comment: Don't say "thank you" anywhere of your answer. It's pure noise.

Comment: People still could be domain experts, but don't have enough rep to be recognized as such here on SO. So yes, a good solution is hard, and the current best workaround to make your voice heard is to comment on bugs.

Comment: It seems from what Braiam linked in the question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339101/the-community-vs-the-domain-expert it seems edits are actually discouraged if they are not presentation only fixes

Comment: @Sven actually, the author of whatever you are editing is, at least, knowledgeable enough to evaluate any edit on their answers. If /review instead of allow anyone to review, only allows those that can do a sensible review, the author can, in case that there isn't other experts reviewing, evaluate the edit critically. The author in this case wasn't online, otherwise he would be approved the edit. The system should wait for them.