# Why was this edit rejected with a seeming unrelated generic response?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have a feeling this is a duplicate but each edit is unique so here goes.

So for the first time I proposed an edit to [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625164/object-createfunction-prototype-create-function-which-inherits-properties/37625347#37625347), the edit was designed to act apon a comment made on the answer by another user and to add sample usage through the snippets feature.

However [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17240596) was quickly rejected by two users with the comment

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Whilst I understand that there will be many occasions that this generic response is appropriate I'm confused as to how its relevant to my edit.

Comment: So why exactly did the `f.__proto__ = obj;` need to go? What is the confusion?

Comment: I would have rejected the edit too, but I think I would have chosen the "clearly conflicts with author's intent" reason instead. (I'd welcome any comments if that seems inappropriate.)

Comment: The `f.__proto__ = obj` was irrelevant as `setPrototypeOf` was decided to be the better choice in a previous edit, the `__proto__` mention only serves to muddy the water as it's other mentions have already been removed

Comment: Recommended read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/792066

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not disagreeing with the actions taken there.

The thing is, we have an issue with users editing just wantonly editing the code of another person's answer.  While there are competing schools of thought on the matter (and some would think your edits are fine), there are *other* schools of thought that believe that if an answer is wrong, it should *stay* wrong and *you* should answer correctly instead of editing the existing answer (and yes, I subscribe to *this* thinking).

You essentially put words in the OP's mouth by adding that extra snippet, which is what likely set up some alarms for people. That's *typically* frowned upon.  Based on my school of thought, you should provide your own answer instead in this scenario.

Comment: The user isn't even asserting that the answer is wrong, just that they're not doing it the way they'd prefer it be done.

Comment: @Servy:  I mechanically translate "not done the way I want it" as "wrong".  I had a strict upbringing, I suppose.  But it really washes out in the end.

Comment: They also removed `f.__proto__ = obj;` from the answer. So it is not just adding a code snippet ...

Comment: Previous edits from the answers author had removed mentions of `__proto__` in favour of the standards compliant `setPrototypeOf `

Comment: Based on these discussions I would post an alternative answer however I am unable to as the question has been marked as a duplicate even though it's question / answer is debatably of higher value than that of its supposed duplicate. Anyway thanks all for clearing this up for me

Comment: @AlexB:  Does your new answer conflict with the duplicate answers in any way?  If it doesn't, add your answer to the duplicate question instead.

Comment: "we have an issue with" reviewers reviewing stuff they are not qualified to review. I don't care people editing other people code, so long as a) they know what they are doing b) improve the post as result. cc @AlexB

Comment: I subscribe to your school of thought, but I have also become weary of new answers on old questions which just pile up and generally stay under the radar. When there are already enough existing answers, maybe it's not so bad to improve an existing one.

Answer (score 3):

It's relevant because what you provided shouldn't have been an edit, it should have been either a comment or another answer, just as the rejection reason says.  Edits aren't there for you to change an answer from what someone else decided it should be into what you'd rather it have been.  If you have your own alternate answer, you can post yours as a new answer, since apparently the author choose not to make the change that was already proposed as a comment.