# How does pointing to an English MDN page instead of its Spanish counterpart deviate from the original intent of the post?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Today I made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21751351) to an answer that simply took an existing reference link to a Spanish entry on the MDN web docs site to the corresponding English entry.

Seeing as SO is an English language site and the answer itself was posted in English, I'm at a loss as to see how two out of three of the review editors rejected the edit with the reason that the "edit deviates from the original intent of the post".  I verified the link in my edit was not broken.  To claim my edit deviates from the intent of the post is nonsensical.

Comment: Surely you did not really expect a useful answer?  The editors wanting to demonstrate the advantage of you earning 401 more rep is an explanation, but not a very plausible one :)  Fixed.  Go for the rep.

Comment: @HansPassant I find it cathartic to vent once in a while, given the lack of recourse on SO for this sort of bad refereeing.  Reputation points are a non-sequitur here.

Comment: Just a guess but it is often said that we shouldn't translate posts. It could be that these reviewers didn't understand the reasoning for that and thought that meant you can't change the language for links. Or maybe they felt since they couldn't verify that the content was the same they ought to reject it. They don't have review numbers that suggest robo-reviewing so I'm assuming it was some kind of mistake.

Comment: The answer below looks fine, it's plenty reasonable to assume it was a mistake or misunderstanding. It might have helped to avoid such a misunderstanding by making the review comment more explicit. "The current linked documentation is in another language. My edit updates the link to the same documentation, but in English."

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes reviewers make mistakes.

They may have just seen the URL was changed, and didn't realize the page contains the same content in another language.

In some cases though, changing the URL to another language may not be a good thing, because often times the same page topic in a different language will actually contain different content. That doesn't seem to be the case here, but that would be a good reason to reject similar edits.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Alexander. I would hesitate to change a link if it were in the question itself, or if any specific content of the target page were cited, for the reason you stated.  However, I would add that we have edit descriptions for a reason, and if reviewers are ignoring them then they are not going about the review process correctly.  Another reason to edit an URL would be if the original link were broken and there were a suitable replacement, e.g. documentation reorganized its site structure.

Comment: *"Sometimes reviewers make mistakes."* - Too many reviewers make too many mistakes and don't take the time to read at all. This has been problematic for way too long, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner hold your horses. Are you asking for critical thinking reviewers instead of button smashing monkeys? [Preposterous!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339127/792066)

Comment: @Braiam In general. Seen too many hit the button too fast; no news around here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yet, we know that [when you have some knowledge in the thing you are reviewing, you take your time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288121/213575). For some reason, meta general population rejects the very notion of being a *reviewer*.

Comment: @Braiam The ones that don't mess up, are the ones who take the time to review and not "jump the gun" as it were. It's the lower rep members that'll just hit anything in thinking they'll make some type of rep out of it. I've seen too many of those guys mess up and it'll be an ongoing battle that nobody will ever win, sadly enough. I hardly do reviewing anymore, I rate the questions as they come, be it good or bad.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner did you know that /review has filters? Have you used them?

Comment: @Braiam Don't believe that I have but can't say I'd ever use them also though.

Comment: There’s a reason why people get the robocop hat for doing reviews...

Answer (score 8):

You are correct.

The edit was appropriate and the rejection reasons are outlandish.

Unfortunately this is not uncommon; reviewers have a wide variety of opinions as well as varying levels of concentration/competence.

Remember, democracy is not the best form of government, it's just better than everything else we've tried.