# Outdated Q&A: new solutions, new&updated packages

Tags: discussion

Just have asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050484/extract-date-using-month-names-in-danish-language?noredirect=1#comment71274313_42050484) regarding parsing a date using non-English language. It was (rightfully) flagged as duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na/42051060#42051060).

Now when I tried to reproduce this question, I can see that first attempt made by person who asked question using base function

```
 var <- "Thu Nov 8 15:41:45 2012"
strptime(var, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] NA #his (older) output
[1] "2012-11-08 15:41:45 CET" #my output five years later
```

Also, the solution offered and accepted is very informative, but a newer package and functionality offers a simple way that does not include unnecessary steps, as in my answer on the same question.
  Now my questions is weather there should be an **outdated** flag? Or, something like package updated to deal with... and so on.
I am just a newbie, using a lot of answers from this site, and can see that this happens quite often with older questions.

Similar: [how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers)

Answer (score 8):

No, there doesn't need to be a flag. What is someone else going to do about this problem?

If there is a newer, better solution, then that should be posted as a new answer to the question.
It appears that is what you did, and that is good. Nothing else needs to be done. If your answer is useful and accurate, voting will push it up to the top.

Comment: I'm afraid, that most people looking for a solution pick the first they find, the accept answer, the highest rated answer - but not a much better answer, which is somewhere on the second page... I tend to answer question which could be closed as duplicates, if I find absolutely outdated answers... I'm afraid that your approach helps to keep bad and outdated solutions alive...