# Is anything being done to reduce check the ego/reduce gatekeeping?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Regarding [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/96in6i/machine_learning/?st=jkqaf9mw&sh=8ad292f8) amongst many others.  It seems like outside of stackoverflow the general consensus is that stackoverflow is hostile to new contributors.  As someone who's lurked on this site for 7+ years, I've definitely noticed that there is a hostility within the site.

While, I'd like to keep this question objective I'd also like to provide a provide a real scenario to discuss what can be improved: My most recent question was regarding a stack that I'm very unfamiliar with and I needed help being pointed in the correct direction, fortunately my question wasn't marked as a duplicate and I was able to receive an answer describing what to do but no example.  With the new information I googled for and found what I needed.  I also wanted to provide the contributor feedback (flagging the answer as correct) while still providing anyone else stumbling onto the question more information so they can avoid the additional googling.  As such I added the appropriate `code` snippets and citations.  This was considered "[...] intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer".  A response that makes no sense as providing code by itself as answer is unhelpful.  Citations by themself are also not an answer.  This response was almost enough to make me refrain from updating, however, fortunately the original author approved my change (when I resubmitted it with minor alterations and copied the bullets from the right side of the screen as my changelog notice).

The linked thread has many such stories and anecdotes describing similar frustrations and has ultimately been upvoted 17k times at the time of this question, suggesting that the majority of the adjacent community also feels this extreme hostility towards new editors.  To reiterate, what if anything is being done to reduce the hostility?

Comment: What would you propose be done?  Keeping in mind the reddit thread you linked to is really, really long.  Do you want to always be forced to read through a lot of stuff to find the meat, or would you prefer the meat to be readily available?

Comment: @StephenRauch Which just highlights the difference between SE and Reddit.  SE is all about the answers.  Nothing else.  Reddit, and most of the rest of the internet, you have to dig to get any nuggets of information.  The laser focus of SE is it's strength.  Many people don't like that.

Comment: If we use my biased but specific case as an example, the edit could have remained in the moderation queue longer.  This would have allowed the person who originally answered the question to review the post and decide for themself if they'd like the modification incorporated into the answer or not.

Comment: And for cases like that, you suggest the alteration in a comment.  When you actually suggest an edit, you open it up to all reviewers, who are *supposed* to reject such changes.

Comment: @Colton, yeah but...  How do you do that?  The suggested edit queue is already frequently wanting for people to spend time processing the requests.  Subtleties like what you are asking for are going to be very hard to implement given the desire to focus on the answer.

Comment: The two main concerns I saw posted repeatedly on reddit was that old posts are closed and new posts related to the same post are marked duplicate.  This is even the case when the old post has deprecated information and is otherwise no longer useful.  The other big one is that posts are closed as duplicate despite being unrelated.

Comment: @fbueckert you're incorrect from the edit page, edits are to "add related resources or links"  resources could be code examples and links/citations are pretty self explanatory.  Under what criteria should adding citations be rejected?  If you don't want to see that it the moderation queue, don't review the moderation queue.

Comment: Edits are meant to clarify content, and fix spelling and grammar mistakes.  I don't believe they're meant to be used to add additional content; can you point to where you believe that to be said?  There's a very specific reason to use, as you saw, when it looks like the edit looks like a reply to the post, not an edit.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm not sure I understand your point.  I've never seen the moderation queue, but as mentioned to flueckert, adding links/citation is exactly what edits are for.  The diff of my change was nearly all green as all I did was add specific details which weren't included in the original answer?

Comment: @fbueckert https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51306089/edit right hand side under the heading "how to edit" also adding code or examples falls clearly under "clarify meaning without changing it"

Comment: Adding code that isn't part of the question is not what editing is for; how do you know what the question or answer is trying to say?  Code is something you leave alone.  Examples, ditto; you're not the poster, so you don't know how they meant to use it.  Both of those are assuming intent.  If that's what your edit did, I believe that's rightly rejected.  Related resources might be okay, but if they were rolled in with the code changes, well, there's no way to accept only part of a suggested edit.

Comment: @fbueckert, you've clearly not reviewed the edits.  It's very clear that I know what the question was supposed to be as I am the person asking the question.  Further the answer was clear enough to assist in googling but not clear enough to suite a "Q&A" type forum.  As such providing a clear, concise example (which was accepted by the author but not the moderators) only serves to benefit the community

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20302919) is the edit you're referencing, I'm going to say that was rightly rejected.  I think that goes beyond what editing is meant for.  But how does that relate to your semi-rant about ego and gatekeeping?  You're going off on a tangent.

Comment: So your lack of knowledge of the intricacies of reviewing suggested edits is part of the confusion here.  You have been a member for almost 8 years, and have not done one suggested edit review.  I have been here for 20 months and have done 5842 suggested edits reviews. Please allow me to say that I do not think that what  you are asking is likely to be practical...

Comment: The question is: why are things like rejected edits, downvotes, flags and close votes percieved as _hostility_ instead of what they are - moderation tools that are meant to keep the quality up and can be acted upon? In your case, you could have suggested the alterations in a comment or post another answer. As long as moderation is seen as hostile, we can be as welcoming and friendly as we like, it won't change a thing. Maybe we need to communicate better what SO is (how it works, what users should expect) in addition to the CoC.

Comment: @ModusTollens that's a very fair point.  I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @StephenRauch you're correct, I lack perspective from the other side of the fence.  That doesn't prevent me feeling concerned as a user,  posts are stagnating due to "closed as duplicate" referring to posts which are no longer relevant.  That's why I'm posing this as a question,  I don't have a solution but I'd like know if there is anyone on the inner circle even thinking about the question.  Ultimately, the answer will likely be the same as it was the last time... Something new will come along and displace the current system.

Comment: I feel like this discussion has been valuable so I'm going to go ahead and leave the thread open despite the fact that it's clearly not a popular question.  I do hope to see more responses and at least one answer regarding how the community can foster better quality answers than what is currently happening as the information here ages and updates are rejected.

Comment: One more thing, please feel free to suggest exactly how I could've better handled that update to guarantee that the additional information is available to whomever stumbles across that post.  Should I just have added an additional answer ignoring the fact that it would ultimately be the same answer as what Ripi provided?

Comment: From a night of discovery and reading more meta posts than I care to think about, it seems like a lot of this has been rehashed elsewhere in a more positive way.  I'm looking forward to seeing a formal way to handle the aged answers.  Thanks everyone for your insightful feedback.

Comment: Oh look - another 'anti-hostility' post with an abusive, hostile title that asserts that the ego of SO curators requires checking.  No surprise there, then:(

Answer (score 16):

Anymore, the hostility comes from people who not only don't understand the policies we have on the site, but lash out at us when all we're trying to do is keep the site clean.

Going to be blunt:  this is going to sound ranty since I'm **over** the whole mentality of Stack Overflow being a bully/having an ego/having an agenda against new people/having an agenda *at all*.  It's been a running theme this entire summer and the totality of the smear I've seen is infuriating.

---

So here's the deal - Stack Overflow gets [**on the order of 7,000 questions a day**](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday).  While I more than recognize that searching for questions and information on the site is definitely wanting, we definitely have a *lot* of duplicate content here, some of which we're lucky enough to identify and close.  I get it - not everyone's problem is the same, but if the root cause is the fact that they're dereferencing `null`, then they should look to fix *that* first, and we have several dupes to show them how.

I do feel I need to stress this since it's being implied.

## Closing a question as a dupe is *not* impolite.

There is no ego attached, there's no bias, there's *nothing* except for the desire to not have to answer the same `NullPointerException` or `NullReferenceException` again for the umpteenth time.

Just the action of linking to a related question is fairly polite since it means that the OP has a chance at finding an answer over yonder, since someone has covered similar ground before.

---

To your example, I'm quite happy to see that you were able to find a solution to your problem.  However, we have some [expectations laid out when editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/175248).  This includes not doing what you had done - editing an answer to include new information as a response to the answerer.  Your motive was noble - you wanted to add more information - but adding it to someone else's answer was *inappropriate*.  If you wanted to do that, you should have posted an answer to your own question.

---

Can you do a favor next time?   Could you engage Meta and ask if there's a better way to go about doing what you intended to do?  Immediately assuming that we're out to ostracize people doesn't improve morale or give us a neutral ground to work with; immediately we're on the defensive, and it's not a comfortable position to work from.

---

Oh, also - there's this new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) which was recently revamped.  Feel encouraged to peruse it.

Comment: "Closing a question as a dupe is not impolite." agreed.  It's not impolite when done in a way that is constructive.  Closing as a duplicate and linking to something that has aged out or is unrelated feels very frustrating.

Comment: from your link "Adding additional information only found in comments, so that new visitors don't have to read everything", from the edit page "clarify meaning without changing it" & "add related resources or links", what about adding citations or example code is incorrect?

Comment: I work in software developement, and the majority of my team (about 30 of 40) uses Stack Overflow regularly, yet they almost never ask any questions; basically everything we need is already on the site if we know how to look. I'm the only one active and vocal on Meta among us, but all of them understand that "Closing a question as a dupe is not impolite," because they understand that what really is impolite is to ask people to waste their time reading, understanding and answering your question, when you could spend that same amount of time (or less) finding the duplicate yourself.

Comment: @Colton:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272570/1079354

Comment: @Makoto, I'd like to mark this as the answer but your link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/175248 contradicts your statement, could you make that a bit more clear?

Comment: @Colton I've read through that post and don't see contradictions, but I may be missing something. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: @Colton, do you think that Makoto's answer is some how dependent/hoping that the answer will be the "accepted" answer?  With over 1200 answers on SO Meta, it seems unlikely that the motivation for the answer has anything to do with your acceptance of the answer.

Comment: Well I had a fun evening trying to better understand your guys' point of view.  Though it appears that the the majority of posters here disagree with the accepted answers for what edits are for: The comments of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314064/157297 have quite a few examples of similar discussions which contradict what Makoto is trying to say regarding the edits.  The jist I got is get to 2000 rep and then you can just do it

Comment: @Colton But again what about what Makoto says are you actually disagreeing with? Or are you flat out saying that everything from his post from start to finish is one big contradiction? And if so, still explain why please, because I see them as being in line one with another.