# How to deal with outdated framing and statements in a question?

Tags: discussion

How to deal with a question stating something which is outdated? I'm particularly talking about this question [Why is Go so slow (compared to Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704417/why-is-go-so-slow-compared-to-java) which states Go is so slow compared to Java. The question was asked in 8 years ago in 2010.

I have read:
[How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers)
saying I can downvote, comment and provide a better answer.

Would it be ok to change the 'is' to 'was' in the question? This would preserve the great discussion about what contributes to performance while immediately pointing out the times have changed.

Currently I added the 'in 2010' to the question body.

Comment: No, the date of that question is sufficient.  If you want to add a new answer that explains why it is not slower anymore today then be sure to do so.  It is *very* important to quote verifiable facts and not just arbitrary benchmarks designed to take advantage of a specific Go feature.  Only then can "is" be changed to "was".

Comment: The question isn't really suited to SO in the first place.  It's way too broad; you can't really compare performance of an entire language against another.  There are too many systems involved, too many different ways to test them allowing you to create whatever result you want.  The question is inherently unanswerable.