# Should I accept an answer if I don't understand it?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

If I ask a question and get one or more answers but I don't understand some (or any) of them, can I and should I accept any of them? I can assume they're correct (especially if they get a lot of upvotes) but if I don't understand them myself I can't be 100% sure they answer my question (or that they're the best answer). What should I do in such a situation?

To clarify my question - my dilemma is: if my questions receives a correct answer then I might not be able to say if it's correct but that doesn't change the fact that the author of the answer deserves his answer being accepted.

Comment: I've often seen what I call _'panic accepts'_ for answers given on downvoted questions with low rep users. No you shouldn't accept an answer that you don't understand, or that doesn't finally solve your problem (supposed you manage to clearly state it).

Comment: I'd suggest taking the time to try to understand the answer, try to use it in your program (assuming you're asking for some specific thing you're trying to do and not just a general question), and then come back and accept it if it ends up helping you. You're not obligated to accept an answer immediately (or ever!)

Comment: When you say "my question receives a correct answer" you are saying that the answer *is* correct, are you not? If you then say that you are not "able to say if it is correct" then either your earlier pronouncement that the answer is correct cannot be taken at face value, since you are in fact not able to say, or your later pronouncement that you are not able to say is untrue.

Comment: No, the fact that I can't determine the correctness of the answer is independent of its correctness itself. In other words, I might not be able to determine its correctness but it **still might be** correct.

Comment: You should not accept an answer that is not correct or does not solve your problem.  If you cannot understand an answer sufficient to evaluate its correctness you should ask for clarification.  Note that you do not have to understand it *perfectly* (I can imagine, eg, some esoteric answers in the Physics SO forum), but you should be able to grasp the gist of it.  You do not *have* to accept any answer (even though folks will often try to bully you to do so).

Comment: I might compare this to scientific SE-network sites (math.SE, physics.SE and the kinds): given the nature of research-level question, some of users there only accept answers that are understandable by themselves while also upvote other more-detailed answers (given *some* usefulness from the answers)

Comment: @HotLicks There are subjects where people naturally ask a question, even though they don't have the necessary knowledge to understand the answer. For example Haskell question often bring up huge insights using category theory or type theory. Even a somehow naive question asked by a newbie haskeller may require significant knowledge in this area to provide a complete and satisfying answer. Since questions and answers should be helpful to everybody you cannot simply provide an incorrect or significantly incomplete answer just to let the OP understand, leaving everybody else with a bad answer.

Comment: Sure, the answerer should try to summarize the intuition behind all the actual answer, but this may not be sufficient to satisfy the OP expectations. In such situations the best option is: let the OP learn what he needs to and, eventually, he'll be able to understand the answer and accept it. In the mean time upvotes are enough to determine the goodness of the answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Closer to (my) home, there might be a question about, say, compiler optimization, where the OP lacks the background to completely understand a technical answer that involves code hoisting or data flow analysis.  A proper *answer* should make an effort to address the issue in Opie's terms and at his level, in addition to (if the responder feels like it) giving a more technical answer.  Something that is incomprehensible is not a valid answer.

Comment: If you don't understand an answer, and can't say that it's correct, you cannot accept it as correct. *If you don't know it's correct, don't accept it as correct.* I've no idea why this is difficult for you to understand. "I can't tell if it's right or wrong, so I'll just accept it as right" simply isn't logical. The person who posted the answer will be rewarded by others upvoting their answer if they are correct; you should only accept answers that you can say are *correct in that they answered the question you asked so that your problem is resolved*.

Comment: This could well be related to my question [Is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272546/is-it-reasonable-to-upvote-an-answer-if-you-dont-know-if-it-works)

Comment: Upvote 'useful'. Accept the one that helped you solve your problem. If you didn't understand it, then that doesn't apply.

Comment: This question is completely incomprehensible to me... why would you ever accept an answer that you don't understand? That's like getting a Chinese character tattoo that you didn't verify is the word "love" so instead you have "seriously, i am an idiot"

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You do not have to accept any answer. If I received an answer that I could not understand, I would not accept it. Chances are you're not the only person who does not understand it. Asking for clarification would benefit everyone, and *then* if the answer is clear and helpful, I'd accept it.

Comment: If a question receives a **correct** answer is it completely fine if it's not accepted?

Comment: How do *you* know it is *correct* if you do not understand it?

Comment: I agree that only if it helps you should you accept it. If it helps *other* people, they will upvote it, and it will be visible anyway.

Comment: @NPS For an answer to be a quality helpful answer it needs to be more than just correct.  It also needs to be understandable for its target audience.  A correct answer that cannot be understood isn't much different than no answer at all.

Comment: @Servy True but what if I'm a moron and I don't understand the answer even if it's phrased in a very simple way and everyone but me understands it? :P

Comment: @NPS Then those other people can upvote the answer.  In the event that most everyone finds an answer useful, the score will reflect that.  Your vote should reflect whether its useful to you, not whether it's useful to everyone else.

Comment: @NPS Are you *sure* you understood this answer before accepting it?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Very funny. :P

Comment: Could you explain that??

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Nice understanding of American humor :)

Comment: @Louis very simple: you copy the code and it gives the output you wished for. So you know the answer is correct. Now that doesn't mean you **understand** why or how it works.

Comment: @nico The OP gives me this code to perform the addition of any two numbers: `function add(a, b) { return 4; }` and gives the following code to show that it works `add(2, 2); add(0, 4); add(1, 3);`. I copy it and... my God! It works! Upvote and acceptance FTW! Someone who does not understand the answer can't be reasonably sure that they are not overlooking something which would appear as obvious to someone who does understand the answer.

Comment: @Louis Exactly my point. Say the answer is: I want to have a div in the middle of the page that has to bounce around when the user scrolls the page. Answer is a complex mix of JS, ugly CSS hacks and prayers to unholy HTML gods. I copy it and it works. Do I need to understand the code to see whether it does what I want to do? No. The two things do not imply each other. I can still use the code, and I would upvote the answer because, hey, it does the job. Depending on how much I do not understand of the code, however, I may not accept it.

Comment: Damn. I still instinctively look for accept rates for new users. Guess I didnt keep up.

Comment: @nico I don't think you got *my* point.

Comment: @Louis care to explain? My point is: you can know that an answer works without understanding it, just like you can drive a car without knowing how the engine works. What is your point?

Comment: @nico: It only works on an extremely limited set of inputs...

Comment: If you say so...  I think it is widely applicable.

Comment: @nico I tested it with numerous number ranges and it worked, it even works when parsing in multilingual strings (eg. `add(-4,"ocho")` returns `4` as expected), and its much faster than other solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @Lego you completely missed my point. If I did want to sum numbers and letters by ignoring the letters, that answer works as expected. And even understanding the answer does not protect me from bugs. My point was just that it is **possible** (not right) to say the answer works **for me**, because it gives the output that I want. I don't necessarily advocate this behaviour, I'm just stating a fact.

Answer (score 80):

Not accepting a good answer does very little harm.

Accepting a bad answer causes that answer to appear first in the list, above any better answers that people come along and post later. It overrules the voting of the community. And only you can change which answer is accepted. If you ever cease to be active on the site - perhaps because you move out of programming, or, gods forbid, get hit by a bus as you're crossing the road tomorrow morning - then there will be absolutely nothing anybody can ever do to stop that bad answer from being pinned to the top forever more.

This harms everybody who ever views your question for the whole of time. There are lots of questions out there with incomplete, misleading, or outright incorrect answers with low score sitting at the most visible spot on the page, pushing better answers out of sight of impatient readers and wasting the time of patient readers who need to wade through nonsense before getting to the good answers. This causes real harm; on popular questions, many man-hours will be wasted through people being misled by bad answers that were given undue visibility.

So you should err strongly in favour of *not* accepting an answer at all when you don't understand the answers you've received.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... I've come across that situation a couple of times, and the first time I didn't really look beyond the accepted answer. I came back when I noticed it didn't work very well, and there was a gem of an answer sitting underneath. Now I always evaluate the top 3 answers at least.

Comment: Maybe some moderator level should allow moderators with very high rep (so, usually (but not always :( ) able to judge the completeness and correctness of the various answers) to change which answer is the accepted one? (And add a flag "better answer" ?)

Comment: @OlivierDulac That's been suggested in various forms, but it's been declined every time. (I personally would like something like that too sometimes, but I understand why they always decline)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Partly yes, but sometimes the OP is rather clueless and accepts a non-sense, which was as "helpful" as anything else, since the question came out of curiosity. What's worse, the wrong answer comes to the top and gets even more votes from other clueless guys. No way to get it down.

Comment: @OlivierDulac It doesn't even require much reputation;  someone who understands the problem just needs to leave a comment.  And then anyone who can vote on comments can upvote that comment.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to make the following distinction:

- If an answer **works** when applied to my code I will accept it even if I don't quite understand it; and
- if the answer also makes clear to me what the problem was and how the fix solves that problem, I will upvote it.

To quote from the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

**[EDIT - seeing as the above seems to have been misunderstood; I'm referring here to a single working answer. In the case of multiple working answers of course the clearest one, which did most to aid my understanding, is the one to accept.]**

Comment: So, a quick and dirty hack which seems to work gets accepted and a thorough explanation which details what the problem is and how to avoid it might only, with luck, get upvoted later on (and not so much as the quick fix)? That's quite common... and annoying.

Comment: More a problem with how I've worded my answer than anything else in this case. I've seldom been blessed with multiple answers but, in the case that I am, of course the more thorough and usable gets accepted. Notice how the second bullet point refers to *the* answer - I'm meaning the same one.

Comment: Good of you, though it does not change my observation. Too often answers get accepted which let the OP move on, even if they open the door to all kinds of misery. The OP not understanding the answer is a prime reason for that, though certainly not the only one.

Comment: I still wouldn't accept in this case, unless (a) after re-reading my question, it looks like the answerer was right to expect I'd understand, and (b) he's given me enough information that I could learn what he's doing and why, and (c) I'm too lazy to actually learn. This should be a pretty rare constellation of occurrences.

Answer (score 6):

Explanation is an important part of the answer. If the answer is working but its explanation, for you, is insufficient then you should not accept it.

Answer (score 2):

We have reputation to provide incentive for the kind of behaviour we want to see. Voting is most of that, and encourages answerers to give the kinds of answers the community values, in aggregate.

The bonus reputation for accepting an answer is an extra bit of "signal" given to the asker of a question, to more specifically encourage answers that *help the asker resolve their problem*.

So I wouldn't worry about whether the answerer **deserves** to have their answer accepted, and instead just think about whether it's the kind of answer you want to your question. If it's the kind of one-off problem you're not likely to see again and the answer resolved your problem, maybe you don't need to understand the answer for it to have helped you resolve your problem, in which case accept away. But if your question is an example of a general class of problem, and you *need* to understand the answer in order to be able to apply it to different instances of the problem in future, then I wouldn't regard an answer that you can't understand as an answer to accept - *yet*. Hopefully it can be edited with a bit more explanation.

People with the same problem as you and a similar level of understanding are (hopefully) likely to use similar language to search for their problem, and find your question. So it's not unreasonable to specifically ask for an answer to be improved to suit your current knowledge; future readers of your question are likely to need this too!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i understand it completely. You can get from zero up to a LOT of answers. You flag it as a "solution" if it solves your problem. (Or at least you believe it does.)
IF your problem is "help me make it work" then you might be totally fine with some code or advice that you don't understand. (lets ignore the question if that is a good policy) So if the code works or the advice let you do what you wanted, flag it as the solution to your problem/question.
IF your problem is "help me understand" then OF COURSE you should NEVER flag an answer as a solution, if you do not understand it. That would be totally turning things upside down. Just because some lines of text contain an understandable explanation of something to people with different experience than you, does NOT make this text a solution to your problem.
That is actually one of the tricky parts of teaching. Writing an answer that can be acknowledged by anybody who already has knowledge and understanding is one thing. Writing an answer that helps someone to GAIN that understanding is something different.
Yes, the text might be correct. Yes, people with different experience might be able to verify and trace back to something they already understand. Yes, other people might be able to learn to understand from that text. But as long as you don't, it is not the solution to "help me understand"
Imagine two answers, both with completely correct text and explanations. You only understand one. (Maybe just because of choice of words) Its obvious which one you should flag as the solution. Now imagine that understandable answer was not given. Why would you suddenly decide to flag the other answer, which you don't understand?

Answer (score -1):

If I cannot understand the answer I get the poster to clarify it in a language I would understand and only then would i accept the answer. Stack overflow is a community where we all help each other learn, how can we learn if we do not understand?

Comment: Some people don't want to learn, they just want a solution to their problem. May not be a good way of thinking, but it is the reality...