# Should I upvote a complex question if I don't understand it?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes, etiquette

There are many questions out there that are above my comprehension level with regards to code complexity. If warranted, should I upvote these questions even if I cannot fully understand the code in them?

Please note, I don't mean questions that have bad English, poor formatting, off-topic, etc. I mean the questions that are not low quality, but are simply above my level of expertise.

*Addendum*
This question is not addressing how to vote based on solutions to a problem, as suggested by the proposed duplicate [Is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272546/is-it-reasonable-to-upvote-an-answer-if-you-dont-know-if-it-works) . This question is specifically addressing voting on how a problem is presented.

Comment: The tooltip says, "*This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.". If you feel that is the case, upvote. If you don't comprehend the question, it is less likely that you know whether it shows research effort, or whether it is useful or clear. On that basis alone, it would seem illogical to upvote. However, votes are yours to use as you see fit.

Comment: If I see a well-asked question with everything one requires (clear problem statement, what the user had tried, what happened, why it wasn't what was needed) that is formatted correctly and clean, and appears to be "hard" (relative most questions on SO), I will be more likely to upvote it just to give the question more exposure, less so because it's well written.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the complexity of the code provided, or the complexity of the question overall?

Comment: This question is complex and I don't understand it, but I've downvoted anyway.

Comment: @Will How exactly does upvoting give a question more exposure?

Comment: @torazaburo - You are reading too much into one word, the title was edited.

Comment: @torazaburo personal experience.  It's what I go by.  I cannot say it is the same for everyone.  Well, everyone who isn't super cool like me.

Comment: @TravisJ The OP said "complex". What is wrong with reading into that word the meaning "complex"? You have mangled this question beyond recognition with your edits. You have inexplicably changed "complex" to "good" in the title, and made many other changes which essentially amount to making this into an entirely different question. In the process of doing that, you have invalidated many of the existing answers. You even invalidated the part of your own answer which referred to "complex questions", which no longer even appears in the post as you edited it. Those changes ought to be rolled back.

Comment: @torazaburo - Complex questions was introduced in an edit I made and I removed it because it clearly didn't line up with the original intent of this post (which you can see in the revision history). Note that there is no existence of "complex questions" in there. The post is not mangled, it just no longer contains what apparently amounted to a "trigger word".

Comment: I see now, thanks for explaining. So you added "complex", then removed it. That's confusing. I think most people answered it during the period the "complex" was still there. Perhaps the question should just have been left alone.

Comment: @torazaburo - It is unfortunate that it was made to be confusing, that wasn't the intention. I was just trying to salvage what was in my opinion a discussion worth having. In its original state, it may have had its issues, but it was incorrectly closed as the wrong duplicate and I tried to do my best to salvage it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't understand the question, you can't reasonably determine:

- if the question is high quality
- if the question is well-asked with respect to the technology being used
- if the question has been well-researched
- if the question *might* be useful (and to be fair, this is more of a hunch than anything else)

With that, I'd prefer if you didn't just upvote any complex-looking question you happened by.  Vote on questions (and answers) that you *genuinely* believe to be good and well-researched.

Of course, you can vote however you wish, but my preference would be to abstain voting on a subject you don't fully understand.

Comment: I don't agree with some of the points raised. First, just to point this out, the statement "abstain voting on a subject you don't fully understand" could apply to downvotes too. The major problem with outlook from meta is that downvoting is seen as duty and has all sorts of guidance, whereas upvoting is just some dirty metric to avoid. This question was originally closed probably for containing the word "upvote".

Comment: Furhermore, just because a topic is complex does not inherently mean that it is hard to tell if it is high quality or not - especially when the OP states that they at least partially grasp the scenario. Quality in general is rather easy to determine, and users are constantly making these decisions in topics where they have absolutely no expertise with regards to downvoting or closing. Well-asked was never defined here and probably means something different to you than to others, but I believe it boils down to overall quality and has the same relation.

Comment: Well researched is not hard to determine, as the research is either present or not. While we do expect users to provide a decent amount of research to show what they tried, it does not need to be all encompassing. I don't think users are voting based on what *might* be useful.

Comment: I think the part of this that is accurate is that users should be upvoting questions that they believe are well researched and "good".

Comment: @TravisJ:  There are a lot of good questions out there that I can quantify, and a lot of questions which I can't quantify.  There are a lot of questions which, as the years and experience has built up, I've become more equipped to qualify.  Had I elected to vote on a question without any qualifications whatsoever, I run a huge risk in sending a false positive message to the system-at-large and to others that this question is "good".  I see voting in both directions as important, but I also feel like it's *perfectly fine* not to vote if you're uncomfortable or unsure.

Comment: Well I upvoted, with the assumption that "don't fully understand" semantically means the same as "fully don't understand". I mean when do you really **fully** understand anything in this life ;)

Answer (score -1):

I am glad you asked this question, because there is not enough guidance for upvoting in general. Most of it focuses on downvoting, and yet both are important in order to maintain the design of the site, namely that good content will bubble up. Without upvotes, nothing can bubble.

Yes, you should be upvoting complex questions, even if you cannot fully comprehend the code presented provided that it follows the guidelines of the site.

- It should have an MCVE if it is asking a question regarding code issues
- Both the title and prose should reflect the actual problem being presented
- There should be proper indentation, sentence structure, and paragraph use
- The tags should be appropriately scoped to the problem
- The OP should be responsive to a comment if an issue is raised with the post

A significant problem that Stack Overflow has is with complex questions. Often they languish as a result of either no one wanting to take the time, put in the effort, or even possess the capability of providing a solution. Sometimes these questions end up with bounties that provide, at times, a good solution to the overall problem of bringing attention to complex questions. However, this isn't a silver bullet.

These questions are the types of questions that everyone always states they cannot find. "Where have all of the high quality questions gone" is a common theme in meta posts from time to time, and it only makes sense to upvote these questions when you find them in order to not only get more solutions to problems but also to help others find these types of posts when they are interested in solving something more complex than how to style a grid, move an element, instantiate an object, or connect to a database.

Comment: I can't follow this train of thought. The OP did use the term "code complexity", but my assumption was he was referring to the complexity of the problem overall. If you disagree, ignore the below. But if we are referring to problem complexity, the five bullets you mention (with the exception of formatting) are going to be hard to him to adjudicate without a reasonable understanding of the question. And I was not under the impression that upvotes were a mechanism to get questions more attention, as you seem to indicate. Nor that upvotes were a reward for responsiveness.

Comment: @torazaburo - I disagree. I believe the OP was referring to the complexity of the code and not to the problem overall. Upvotes are definitely a mechanism to get questions more attention, upvoted questions are far more likely to receive attention. With regards to responsiveness, that was more a nod towards the question asker being attentive, and at least acknowledging that sometimes it can take a minute for the OP to respond. If the post needs clarification and is getting it, then that shouldn't immediately be written off.

Comment: @torazaburo - Voting in general is often used as a knee jerk reaction, and as there is more guidance for downvoting, that tends to be the direction people understand the most. We need upvoting as well, otherwise there is no balance to this system. If someone is looking at complex situations where they understand the problem, but do not fully gr0k the code, it would be nice if they left a signal for someone else in the form of an upvote to look at the question. Far too often questions with complex code sit at 0.

Comment: The title of the question says "complex question" that he "doesn't understand". It's beyond me how he would propose to vote on such a question one way or the other, or why he would even think that maybe he should.